# Detect if parameter passed is an array? Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, arguments, parameter-passing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to detect if a variable is an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058427/how-to-detect-if-a-variable-is-an-array)

I have a simple question:

How do I detect if a parameter passed to my javascript function is an array? I don't believe that I can test:

```
if (typeof paramThatCouldBeArray == 'array')
```

So is it possible?

How would I do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hmm...that makes me think. Maybe my function design is bad if it could possibly be passed anything else. But I was more asking this because of `console.log()`. It intrigues me because if you pass it an array, it iterates over the whole array and prints it out. While if you just pass it a single string, it just logs that. How does it do this?

Comment: Sorry, for continuity, deleted comment was "What other types could the parameter be?"

Comment: @Alex: in which browser? It could be relying on `Array.toString`.

Comment: They seem to be using a lot of browser-dependent checks -- inspect line 1992 at http://getfirebug.com/releases/lite/1.2/firebug-lite.js

Comment: @Alex: note that in Chrome, `console.log` is a native function, and thus has access to info not accessible to a JS script.

Comment: ... Firebug uses things it calls "representations" (http://code.google.com/p/fbug/source/browse/branches/firebug1.6/content/firebug/console.js#sl_svn6639_455, http://code.google.com/p/fbug/source/browse/branches/firebug1.6/content/firebug/reps.js) to convert objects, each of which has a `supportsObject` method, which mostly use `instanceof` (e.g. http://code.google.com/p/fbug/source/browse/branches/firebug1.6/content/firebug/reps.js#sl_svn6588_550). Firebug Lite (http://code.google.com/p/fbug/source/browse/branches/firebug1.6/lite/firebug.js) indirectly uses `toString` (it calls `obj + ''`).

Answer (score 72, accepted):

```
if (param instanceof Array)
    ...
```

**Edit.** As of 2016, there is a ready-built method that catches more corner cases, [`Array.isArray`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray), used as follows:

```
if (Array.isArray(param))
    ...
```

Comment: Good for most cases, but it wont work on cross-frame environments, give a look to this [article](http://perfectionkills.com/instanceof-considered-harmful-or-how-to-write-a-robust-isarray/).

Comment: `!!param.shift` would be faster in terms of execution speed. http://jsperf.com/instanceof-vs-method-detect

Comment: Is it safe to assume this will work properly under nodejs (as there is only one frame i guess ) ?

Comment: If you know for sure you won't be operating across frames (as is generally the case), then use the constructor method. Performance comparison: http://jsperf.com/detecting-arrays-new

Comment: As of 2016, this is still a generally performant and reliable solution.

Answer (score 19):

This is the approach jQuery 1.4.2 uses:

```
var toString = param.prototype.toString;
var isArray = function(obj) {
        return toString.call(obj) === "[object Array]";
    }
```

Comment: This `toString` comparison may seem strange but it is the accepted way to deal with cross-frame environments.

Comment: I don't quite understand: I define `toString` based on `param`, and then I call `isArray()`? What do I pass as `obj`? Where is the bottom line of this answer?

Comment: Tom, basically every object has a toString function which is 'overridden' for an array and per the spec returns [object Array]. This is uniform across all js implementations. The prototype is just so that one function is referenced.

Comment: What if param is the string "[object Array]" ? I think calling toString on a string returns the string itself

Answer (score 5):

I found this [here](http://www.bram.us/2008/02/01/javascript-isarray-check-if-an-elementobject-is-an-array/):

```
function isArray(obj) {
    return obj.constructor == Array; 
}
```

also this one

```
function isArray(obj) {
    return (obj.constructor.toString().indexOf(”Array”) != -1);
}
```

Comment: Testing with JScript `obj.constructor.toString()` returns `function Array() { [native code] }`, making this solution work for that environment.

Answer (score 1):

You can test the `constructor` property:

```
if (param.constructor == Array) {
    ...
}
```

Though this will include objects that have an array prototype,

```
function Stack() {
}
Stack.prototype = [];
```

unless they also define constructor:

```
Stack.prototype.constructor = Stack;
```

or:

```
function Stack() {
    this.constructor = Stack;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Some [days ago](http://gist.github.com/369052) I was building a simple *type detection* function, maybe its useful for you:

Usage:

```
//...
if (typeString(obj) == 'array') {
  //..
}
```

Implementation:

```
function typeString(o) {
  if (typeof o != 'object')
    return typeof o;

  if (o === null)
      return "null";
  //object, array, function, date, regexp, string, number, boolean, error
  var internalClass = Object.prototype.toString.call(o)
                                               .match(/\[object\s(\w+)\]/)[1];
  return internalClass.toLowerCase();
}
```

The [second variant](http://gist.github.com/369052#file_type_string_no_host_types.js) of this function is more strict, because it returns only object types described in the ECMAScript specification (possible output values: `"object"`, `"undefined"`, `"null"`, and `"function"`, `"array"`, `"date"`, `"regexp"`, `"string"`, `"number"`, `"boolean"` `"error"`, using the [`[[Class]]`](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-8.6.2) internal property).

Comment: CMS, both of your links to Gist are dead. Do you still have that code?

Answer (score -1):

#### Duck Typying

Actually, you don't necessarily want to check that an object is an array. You should [duck type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) it and the only thing you want that object to implement is the `length` property. After this you can transform it into an array:

```
var arrayLike = {
    length : 3,

    0: "foo"
};

// transform object to array
var array = Array.prototype.slice.call(arrayLike);

JSON.stringify(array); // ["foo", null, null]
```

`Array.prototype.slice.call(object)` will transform into an array every object that exposes a `length` property. In the case of strings for example:

```
var array = Array.prototype.slice.call("123");
JSON.stringify(array); // ["1", "2", "3"]
```

Well, this technique it's not quite working on IE6 (I don't know about later versions), but it's easy to create a small utility function to transform objects in arrays.