# get the mongodb data type in js script

Tags: javascript, shell, mongodb

```
db.foo.find();


_id    | type
-------------
10001     1
10002    'a'
10003    [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

As you know, the **$type** will match the type code in mongo query, like this:

```
db.foo.find({type: {$type: 4}});
```

**_id | type**

*----------*

**10003, [1, 2, 3, 4]**

and then, I write a javascript shell script called **test.js**

```
var curs = db.foo.find();
curs.forEach(showTypeCode);
function showTypeCode(cur) {
  print(cur.type + '-' + typeof(cur.type));
};
```

**results:**

```
1-number
a-string
1,2,3,4-object (this is an array, it's 4 in mongo)
```

here is my question, how can I get the array type code in the mongo shell

Comment: This is a known bug, whereby MongoDB actually reads an array as an object.

Comment: Here is the JIRA for it: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1475

Comment: @Sammaye,I should not use this demo,in javascript [] and {} are all object type.I want get the mongo data type 4.Is there any method for cur which can show this type code?:)

Comment: I believe I read your question wrong originally, I have added a link to another question that should help, basically you have to test for a class of `array`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first query of:

```
db.foo.find({type: {$type: 4}});
```

Will not actually work due to a bug. This is a known bug within MongoDB whereby it reads an array as an object when using the `$type` operator. You can vote and put your support to this JIRA: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1475

As for solving the issue with the JS, this question might be of help to you: [Detect if parameter passed is an array? Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763024/detect-if-parameter-passed-is-an-array-javascript)

Arrays are Objects of the class Array so that is why you are getting object back. If you test for an instance of `Array` then it should work.