# How to check that value is an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is there a good built-in way that I can find whether value is a array or not?

One simple check I can think of is as follows, but I don't like it:

```
if(ele.push){ /* its array it has push method */ }
```

I mean i would like know if something like pseudo-code below exists. `typeof` doesn't seems to be applicable, as it only returns "object" (though that makes sense).

```
function x(ele){ if(isArray(ele)){ /* dosomething() */ } }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to detect if a variable is an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058427/how-to-detect-if-a-variable-is-an-array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.andrewpeace.com/javascript-is-array.html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function is_array(input){
    return typeof(input)=='object'&&(input instanceof Array);
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
element.constructor == Array
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the cleanest but...

```
function isArray(obj) {
    return obj.constructor == Array;
}
```