# How to flatten array in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, flatten

How to simply flatten array in jQuery? I have:

```
[1, 2, [3, 4], [5, 6], 7]
```

And I want:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You can use [jQuery.map](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/), which is the way to go if you have the jQuery Library already loaded.

```
$.map( [1, 2, [3, 4], [5, 6], 7], function(n){
   return n;
});
```

Returns

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Comment: Granted, that is the way it was phrased in the question, but, this too will only flatten one level.

Comment: For those wondering how this works: unlike `Array.prototype.map` jQuery's `map` has special handling for arrays returned from the callback function: _The [callback] function can return any value. A returned array will be flattened into the resulting array_

Answer (score 35):

Use the power of JavaScript:

```
var a = [[1, 2], 3, [4, 5]];

console.log( Array.prototype.concat.apply([], a) );
//will output [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: That works if you only have arrays nested one level deep.  If you have an array in an array in an array, it won't be flattened.

Comment: @dnuttle Sure, but this condition wasn't stated in the question.

Comment: Could you explain the `apply([], a)` bit please? :)

Answer (score 25):

Here's how you could use jquery to flatten deeply nested arrays:

```
$.map([1, 2, [3, 4], [5, [6, [7, 8]]]], function recurs(n) {
    return ($.isArray(n) ? $.map(n, recurs): n);
});
```

Returns:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Takes advantage of [jQuery.map](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) as well as [jQuery.isArray](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isArray/).

Answer (score 11):

```
var a = [1, 2, [3, 4], [5, [6, [7, 8]]]];
var b = [];

function flatten(e,b){
    if(typeof e.length != "undefined")
    {
        for (var i=0;i<e.length;i++)
        {
            flatten(e[i],b);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        b.push(e);
    }
}
flatten(a,b);
console.log(b);
```

The flatten function should do it, and this doesn't require jQuery.  Just copy all of this into Firebug and run it.

Comment: I should add that this will flatten not only arrays, but anything that has a "length" method.  It is not really possible to be sure in Javascript that something is a true array unless it was declared as new Array().

Comment: dnuttle: Actually, I think using `obj instanceof Array` is pretty much granted to work. (Unless if there's another variable named Array, then you can use `obj instanceof [].constructor`)

Comment: Hmm.  You're right.  I could have sworn I'd tried that before and it didn't work.

Comment: dnuttle: This answer discusses it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058427/how-to-detect-if-a-variable-is-an-array/1058753#1058753 It seems there are problems with my method :(

Comment: You could always use `$.isArray`.  Pure js is great, but libraries are nice too =].

Comment: Upvote as your solution is clear as to what is going on. Other answers using $.map or Array.prototype.concat.apply([], arr) are very clever, but if anyone else views the code may have no idea what is going on.

Answer (score 5):

To recursively flatten an array you can use the native [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) function. The is no need to use jQuery for that.

```
function flatten(arr) {
    return arr.reduce(function flatten(res, a) { 
        Array.isArray(a) ? a.reduce(flatten, res) : res.push(a);
        return res;
    }, []);
}
```

Executing

```
flatten([1, 2, [3, 4, [5, 6]]])
```

returns

```
[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ]
```

Comment: Good to note that it works, but for modern browsers only (unless shimmed)

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`jQuery.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/):

> callback( value, indexOrKey )The function to process each item
>   against. The first argument to the function is the value; the second
>   argument is the index or key of the array or object property. The
>   function can return any value to add to the array. **A returned array
>   will be flattened into the resulting array**. Within the function, this
>   refers to the global (window) object.

Answer (score 1):

Use recursion if you have multiple levels:

```
flaten = function(flatened, arr) {
    for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
        if (typeof arr[i]!="object") {
            flatened.push(arr[i]);
        }
        else {
            flaten(flatened,arr[i]);
        }
    }
    return;
}

a=[1,[4,2],[2,7,[6,4]],3];
b=[];
flaten(b,a);
console.log(b);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.prototype.reduce` which is technically not jQuery, but valid ES5:

```
var multidimensionArray = [1, 2, [3, 4], [5, 6], 7];
var initialValue = [];

var flattened = multidimensionArray.reduce(function(accumulator, current) {
    return accumulator.concat(current);
}, initialValue);

console.log(flattened);
```

Answer (score 0):

Old question, I know, but...

I found this works, and is fast:

```
function flatten (arr) {
  b = Array.prototype.concat.apply([], arr);
  if (b.length != arr.length) {
    b = flatten(b);
  };

  return b;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need [`arr.flat([depth])`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)

```
var arr1 = [1, 2, [3, 4]];
arr1.flat(); 
// [1, 2, 3, 4]

var arr2 = [1, 2, [3, 4, [5, 6]]];
arr2.flat();
// [1, 2, 3, 4, [5, 6]]

var arr3 = [1, 2, [3, 4, [5, 6]]];
arr3.flat(2);
// [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```