# Combining 2 arrays in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 arrays in javascript.

```
            var A = ['c++', 'java', 'c', 'c#', ...];
            var B = [12, 3, 4, 25, ...];
```

Now from these 2 arrays i want to create another array like :

```
  [['c++',12], ['java',3], ['c',4], ['c#', 25] ...];
```

Both `A` and `B` arrays are variable length in my case so how can i do this?

Comment: It is a good idea to put your code that you have tried so far.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to flatten array in jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7875070/how-to-flatten-array-in-jquery)

Comment: Are those your actual arrays?  You might want to add commas between the elements!

Comment: @LinusKleen `flatten` != `zip`

Comment: possible duplicate 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584370/how-to-merge-two-arrays-in-javascript

Comment: Your question is tagged jquery so I assume that's the framework you're using... http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.merge/

Comment: nbrooks, Kyo: this is not what the asker is looking for.

Answer (score 3):

[Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/#zip) is good at that:

> `_.zip(*arrays)`
>
> Merges together the values of each of the arrays with the values at
>   the corresponding position. Useful when you have separate data sources
>   that are coordinated through matching array indexes. If you're working
>   with a matrix of nested arrays, zip.apply can transpose the matrix in
>   a similar fashion.
>
> ```
> _.zip(['moe', 'larry', 'curly'], [30, 40, 50], [true, false, false]);
> => [["moe", 30, true], ["larry", 40, false], ["curly", 50, false]]
> ```

Answer (score 3):

You can use this snippet if you don't to use any third party library:

```
var i = 0
  , n = A.length
  , C = [];

for (; i < n; i++) {
    C.push([A[i], B[i]]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function Merge(A,B){
    var length = Math.min(A.length,B.length);
    var result = [];
    for(var i=0;i<length;i++){
     result.push([ A[i], B[i] ]) 
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that using a hashMap instead of 2 arrays could be a good solution for you.

In example, you could do something like the following:

```
var h = new Object(); // or just {}
h['c++'] = 12;
h['java'] = 3;
h['c'] = 4;
```

Take a look at:

http://www.mojavelinux.com/articles/javascript_hashes.html