# Concatenate JSON arrays in a JSON objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a JSON response like this:

```
{"result":[["abc","de"],["fgh"],["ij","kl"]]}
```

I want the response to be in the form:

```
{"result":["abc","de","fgh","ij","kl"]}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: depends on what language you are creating the response in

Comment: do you mean you want to transform the response in javascript?

Comment: worst response u can get :P `x.split("[").join("").split("]").join("").replace(":",":[").replace("}","]}");`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Merge/flatten an Array of Arrays in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865025/merge-flatten-an-array-of-arrays-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

From the [mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```
var flattened = [[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5]].reduce(function(a, b) {
  return a.concat(b);
});
// flattened is [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var test={"result":[["abc","de"],["fgh"],["ij","kl"]]};
var tmp=[];
for(var i in test.result){
    for(var j in test.result[i]){
      tmp.push(test.result[i][j]);
    }
}
test.result=tmp;
alert(JSON.stringify(test));
```

`jsfiddle link` http://jsfiddle.net/fu26849m/

Answer (score 0):

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/plantface/df4cv29n/)

```
var arrayToFlatten = [[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5]];
```

Native (from [Merge/flatten an array of arrays in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865025/merge-flatten-an-array-of-arrays-in-javascript#answer-18307218)):

```
var flattenedNative = arrayToFlatten.reduce(function(a, b) {
  return a.concat(b);
});
alert(flattenedNative); // 0,1,2,3,4,5
```

jQuery (from [How to flatten array in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7875070/how-to-flatten-array-in-jquery#answer-7875083)):

```
var flattenedJQuery = $.map(arrayToFlatten, function(n) {
  return n;
});
alert(flattenedJQuery); // 0,1,2,3,4,5
```

Native alternative (from [Merge/flatten an array of arrays in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865025/merge-flatten-an-array-of-arrays-in-javascript#answer-10865042)):

```
var flattenedNativeAlt = [].concat.apply([], arrayToFlatten);
alert(flattenedNativeAlt); // 0,1,2,3,4,5
```

Answer (score 0):

The `reduce()` and `concat()` functions can be combined to flatten an array:

```
var json = {"result":[["abc","de"],["fgh"],["ij","kl"]]};

function concatArrays(a, b) { return a.concat(b); }
json.result = json.result.reduce(concatArrays);

console.log(json);  //{"result":["abc","de","fgh","ij","kl"]}
```

See it in action:
http://jsfiddle.net/cazomufn/

Answer (score 0):

My first suggestion for this is you should create json directly as you want to use.
Do not modify it after you get.

You can also use this , this will give you value as you want.:

```
    var mainText= JSON.parse('{"result":[["abc","de"],["fgh"],["ij","kl"]]}');
    var arr = [];
    for(var val1 in mainText.result)
    {   
        arr = arr.concat(mainText.result[val1]);
    }   
    mainText.result = arr;
    console.log(JSON.stringify(mainText));
```

Answer (score 0):

I like [lodash' flatten](http://lodash.com/docs#flatten) (if you can live with another dependency.)

```
json.result = _.flatten(json.result);  

// { result:['abc','de','fgh','ij','kl'] }
```

For example `reduce` isn't supported before IE9 but lodash would still work (compatibility build).