# best way to test if a variable is an array

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to detect if a variable is an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058427/how-to-detect-if-a-variable-is-an-array)

When I need to test if variable is an array (for example input argument in a function that could be object or array) I usually use this piece of code

```
typeof(myVar) === 'object' && myVar.length !== undefined;
```

Is this the correct way or is there a more efficient way, considering that even if  `myVar instanceof Array` [is faster](http://jsperf.com/js-array-test) it should be avoided due to `iframe` problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767486/how-do-you-check-if-a-variable-is-an-array-in-javascript

Comment: zepto.js (has good source code) uses instanceof: `function isArray(value) { return value instanceof Array }` [src](https://github.com/madrobby/zepto/blob/master/src/zepto.js)

Comment: @bokonic : The answer in the possible duplicate clearly tells that this will fail if the object is passed across frame boundaries as each frame has its own Array object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`Array.isArray`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray) is now available with [ECMAScript 5](http://es5.github.com/#x15.4.3.2), so you can use it with a [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray) for [older browsers](http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/):

```
if(!Array.isArray) {
  Array.isArray = function (vArg) {
    return Object.prototype.toString.call(vArg) === "[object Array]";
  };
}

Array.isArray(myVar);
```

Answer (score 0):

The "iframe problem` can be avoided simply by not using the same name for a frame and for an array. Not hard to do, in my opinion. That said, I've never had a need to assert whether or not something is an array...

Comment: The "iframe problem" is that an array created in an iframe is only instanceof the Array constructor of the iframe in which it was created, so if you pass it between frames then instanceof "fails".

Answer (score 0):

If you are already using jQuery within your code, you may use jQuery.isArray(). Here is the documentation:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isArray/

Answer (score 0):

You can try - Object.prototype.toString.call 
An example -

```
var a = [1,2]
console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(a))
```

This returns [object Array] 
which can be checked with string slice method in following way

```
console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(a).slice(8,-1)) <br />
```

which returns "Array"

```
var a = [1,2]
console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(a).slice(8,-1) == "Array") // true
```

Comment: or for less overhead you can just compare to the full string: `'[object Array]'` (like below)

Comment: Well I guess Jonathan has already answered this, I must say in a better way :)

Comment: Yes you are right Bokonic. I completely agree with you.

Comment: One more way to check this is by a.constructor == Array // returns true ( only if a is true array and a is not array-like )