# When does Object.prototype.toString.call(null) return [object Object]?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, object, object-type

I am using Object.prototype.toString.call to identify variable types. I would expect the following behavior:

```
Object.prototype.toString.call({}) => [object Object]
Object.prototype.toString.call([]) => [object Array]
Object.prototype.toString.call(undefined) => [object Undefined]
Object.prototype.toString.call(null) => [object Null]
```

This usually works fine, but I am currently faced with a situation (in Internet Explorer) where both `Object.prototype.toString.call(undefined)` and `Object.prototype.toString.call(null)` return [object Object], and I don't understand why. I tried to replicate it on jsfiddle.net but couldn't, so I am assuming I am in a specific quirk mode.

My questions:

- Is this a known "behavior", and when does this happen?
- is there a more reliable way to check object types (I need to support IE7+)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ECMAScript5 specification states in [§15.2.4.2 about the Object.prototype.toString method](http://es5.github.com/#x15.2.4.2):

> When the `toString` method is called, the following steps are taken:
>
> 1. If the this value is `undefined`, return `"[object Undefined]"`.
> 2. If the this value is `null`, return `"[object Null]"`.
> 3. Let O be the result of calling ToObject passing the this value as the argument.
> 4. Let class be the value of the [[Class]] internal property of O.
> 5. Return the String value that is the result of concatenating the three Strings `"[object "`, class, and `"]"`.

The problem you are facing is that IE7 and 8 follow the older [ECMAScript3 standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%203rd%20edition,%20December%201999.pdf), which states in the same section that

> When the `toString` method is called, the following steps are taken:
>
> 1. Get the [[Class]] property of this object.
> 2. Compute a string value by concatenating the three strings `"[object "`, Result(1), and `"]"`.
> 3. Return Result(2).

That is, in older versions of IE, the method will not return `[object Undefined]` or `[object Null]` unless they are constructed from functions named `Undefined` or `Null`.

You can check for types more reliably using the following methods:

```
typeof x === "object"    // x is any sort of object
typeof x === "undefined" // x is undefined
x instanceof Array       // x is an array
x === null               // x is null
```

Comment: IE 7 and 8 just followed a former version of the standard -- [Edition 3](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%203rd%20edition,%20December%201999.pdf).

Comment: @JonathanLonowski That makes sense, since the ES5 spec wasn't finalized until 2009.

Comment: Great answer, thanks! And thx @JonathanLonowski for the comment on standards.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, `null` is of type `Object` and representing *empty object reference*.

More reliable way of checking the type of value is [`typeof` operator](http://www.w3resource.com/javascript/operators/typeof.php).

As far as I know, it's been supported since IE 6. (Or earlier, I haven't checked.)

Comment: Unfortunately typeof doesn't tell the difference between objects, arrays and null, it returns "object" in all cases.

Comment: @Christophe sure, but `null` is straightforward: `x === null` and array can be dealt with using: `x instanceof Array` or method described here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4029057/1820695 Of course, you are the OP and *you* know best what you need :)

Comment: right, I was just pointing out that typeof alone is not enough. +1 for the link to a complete solution.