# IE8 - IsArray() gets an error object expected

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer, methods, internet-explorer-8

i'm curious why IE8 chokes on the line

```
if (isArray(obj))
```

This is what I get in the IE8 javascript console:

```
>>obj
{...}
>>typeof(obj)
"object"
>>Object.prototype.toString.call(obj)
"[object Array]"
```

and even

```
>>obj.length
7
```

However,

```
>>isArray(obj)
  Object expected
```

Why is that happening (ie8 doesn't support of isArray?) and what's the best way to fix it?

I'm trying to use new version of Angular for IE8. I know it is not officially supported however I will give a try the app to work better or worse.

Thank you.

Comment: I think that this thread is related to what you are after.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058427/how-to-detect-if-a-variable-is-an-array

Answer (score 8, accepted):

since IE 9 there is Array.isArray().

try this:

```
Array.isArray = function (obj) {
    return Object.prototype.toString.call(obj) === "[object Array]";
};

Array.isArray(obj);
```