# Why the Array.isArray algorithm is ES5 performs a type check?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, types, ecmascript-5

Every question found in SO and google about checking if an object is an Array most likely end up with this solution

```
function isArray(obj) {
    return Object.prototype.toString.call(obj) === '[object Array]'
}
```

All the other alternatives have false positives or are not completely supported.

#### Sources:

http://perfectionkills.com/instanceof-considered-harmful-or-how-to-write-a-robust-isarray/

[How to detect if a variable is an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058427/how-to-detect-if-a-variable-is-an-array)

When I read the ES5 spec in section [15.4.3.2](http://es5.github.io/#x15.4.3.2) found the described algorithm for the function Array.isArray that performs the same check in IE9+, Chrome 5+, Firefox 4+, Opera 10.5+ and Safari 5+ but this algorithm have two extra steps.

```
function isArray(obj) {
    if (typeof obj !== 'object') {
        return false;
    }
    // Here they check only against the [[Class]] part 
    // and of course they don't have to use the ugly Object.prototype.toString.call
    // but this is pretty much the same comparison
    if (Object.prototype.toString.call(obj) === '[object Array]') {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Now my question is why do they check for type first? Is there an special case where this will return false for an object that still has the [[Array]] internal class?

Comment: Note that this stuff is essentially obsolete, ES2015 doesn't use `[[Class]]`es at all.

Comment: @georg I know what you mean but until all browsers fully support [ES2015](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/) and there is only a minimum amount of browsers in the world that don't (which might take a decade) learning this is not completely useless because this is the languaje that we are still running today even when we are using transpilers.

Comment: Just saying, `Array.isArray` *is* completely supported in all serious browsers.

Comment: @Bergi Yes, I know this to be true. Please note that when I said that "until all browsers fully support ES2015 " I was talking about the [[Class]] internal property, not the absence of `Array.isArray` method. I've seen some people come with a pollyfill like `Array.isArray ? Array.isArray(obj) : Object.prototype....` just to be sure. Unbelievable as it is I've seen some environments where IE8 is still used o_O.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets look at the algorithm:

> 1. If Type(arg) is not Object, return false.
> 2. If the value of the [[Class]] internal property of arg is "Array", then return true.
> 3. Return false.

The algorithm contains this check because values that are not objects don't have [internal properties](https://es5.github.io/#x8.6.2). But since the algorithm accesses the value's internal property `[[Class]]`, it has to assert that the value is an object.

This check is indeed unnecessary for polyfills, since they don't access any properties on the value. However, it does bring the polyfill closer to the spec.

Comment: I read once someone doing `return typeof (obj) === 'object' && Object.prototype…` and I thought “Ok this must be wrong” but I didn’t know why. Thaks!!

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that `typeof` is not equivalent to the spec's `Type` function. `typeof null` and `typeof function() {}` have different results than `Type(null)` and `Type(function() {})`.

Comment: Cases of values that are not objects are [Null](http://es5.github.io/#x8.2) and [Undefined](http://es5.github.io/#x8.1) or they also include [String](http://es5.github.io/#x8.4) and [Boolean](http://es5.github.io/#x8.3) and [Number](http://es5.github.io/#x8.5)?

Comment: Null, Undefined, String, Number, Boolean and Symbol (ES6) are all primitive types. However, String, Number and Boolean also have Object equivalents, e.g. https://es5.github.io/#x4.3.18 . `"foo"` is a primitive string, `new String("foo")` is a string object. They are different types (String vs Object).

Comment: Yes, this is why the [Object.prototype.toString](http://es5.github.io/#x15.2.4.2) algorithm does not take into account these as "special cases" since they will be converted in step 3 when calling [ToObject](http://es5.github.io/#x9.9), turning them into their Object equivalents but Null and Undefined will throw TypeError hence the need for special handling. Thanks!!