# Is there a way to call the map method only if the element is an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am using the query-string library to parse query parameters from an URL.
When the query parmater is in the form `?foo=bar`, the lib returns an object like this:

```
{
  foo: bar
}
```

When in the form `?foo=bar1,bar2`, the object looks like this:

```
{
  foo: [bar1, bar2]
}
```

I want to apply the function `myFunction` on each element of `myObject.foo` to obtain something like `[myFunction(bar)]` or `[myFunction(bar1), myFunction(bar2)]`

Is there a way to do it easily with something like

```
myObject.foo.mapOrApply(myFunction)
```

without having to check if this is an array ?

For now, I am forced to do it this way and I find this very unaesthetic:

```
Array.isArray(myObject.foo)
   ? myObject.foo.map(myFunction)
   : [myFunction(myObject.foo)];
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect if a variable is an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058427/how-to-detect-if-a-variable-is-an-array)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) like this:

```
[].concat(myObject.foo).map(myFunction)
```

This works when `myObject.foo` is a single value or an array

Here's a snippet:

```js
const getMapped = ({ foo }, callback) => [].concat(foo).map(callback);

 // double a single value
console.log(getMapped({ foo: 1 }, n => 2 * n))

// prefix "new" to every item in the array
console.log(getMapped({ foo: ["bar1", "bar2"] }, str => "new " + str))
```

Answer (score 2):

You could convert to an array, if neccessary, then map with the function.

```
result = (Array.isArray(myObject.foo) ? myObject.foo : [myObject.foo]).map(myFunction);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply :

```
 [].concat(myObject.foo).map(myFunction)
```