# How to extend an existing JavaScript array with another array, without creating a new array

Tags: javascript, arrays, concatenation

There doesn't seem to be a way to extend an existing JavaScript array with another array, i.e. to emulate Python's `extend` method.

I want to achieve the following:

```
>>> a = [1, 2]
[1, 2]
>>> b = [3, 4, 5]
[3, 4, 5]
>>> SOMETHING HERE
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

I know there's a `a.concat(b)` method, but it creates a new array instead of simply extending the first one. I'd like an algorithm that works efficiently when `a` is significantly larger than `b` (i.e. one that does not copy `a`).

<sub>***Note:** This is **not a duplicate of [How to append something to an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/351409/appending-to-array)** -- the goal here is to add the whole contents of one array to the other, and to do it "in place", i.e. without copying all elements of the extended array.*</sub>

Comment: From @Toothbrush's comment on an answer: `a.push(...b)`. It's similar in concept to the top answer, but updated for ES6.

Answer (score 2148, accepted):

The [`.push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) method can take multiple arguments. You can use the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) to pass all the elements of the second array as arguments to `.push`:

```
>>> a.push(...b)
```

If your browser does not support ECMAScript 6, you can use [`.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) instead:

```
>>> a.push.apply(a, b)
```

Or perhaps, if you think it's clearer:

```
>>> Array.prototype.push.apply(a,b)
```

Please note that all these solutions will fail with a stack overflow error if array `b` is too long (trouble starts at about 100,000 elements, depending on the browser).
If you cannot guarantee that `b` is short enough, you should use a standard loop-based technique described in the other answer.

Comment: I think this is your best bet.  Anything else is going to involve iteration or another exertion of apply()

Comment: This answer will fail if "b" (the array to extend by) is large (> 150000 entries approx in Chrome according to my tests).  You should use a for loop, or even better use the inbuilt "forEach" function on "b". See my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374126/how-to-append-an-array-to-an-existing-javascript-array/17368101#17368101

Comment: @Deqing: Array's `push` method can take any number of arguments, which are then pushed to the back of the array. So `a.push('x', 'y', 'z')` is a valid call that will extend `a` by 3 elements. `apply` is a method of any function that takes an array and uses its elements as if they were all given explicitly as positional elements to the function. So `a.push.apply(a, ['x', 'y', 'z'])` would also extend the array by 3 elements. Additionally, `apply` takes a context as the first argument (we pass `a` again there to append to `a`).

Comment: Note: in this scenario, first return value isn't [1,2,3,4,5] but 5  while a 
== [1,2,3,4,5] afterward.

Comment: Also: push.apply() will also push undefined elements, so [1,2,3] and [7:7] will result in [1,2,3,undefined,undefined,undefined,7].

Comment: `apply` pulls each individual element from `b` out onto the stack, which is why as @jcdude notes this will fail for large `b`. This is slower than a simple `for (...) { a.push(b[i]); }` loop

Comment: Yet another slightly less confusing (and not much longer) invocation would be: `[].push.apply(a, b)`.

Comment: Not working on actual Chrome, I got:
 `Uncaught TypeError: CreateListFromArrayLike called on non-object`
But the  ES6 `a.push(...b)` works.

Comment: @user3701996: Not true, just checked all variants on Chrome 63.

Answer (score 357):

<sub>**Update 2018**: [A better answer is a newer one of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374126/how-to-extend-an-existing-javascript-array-with-another-array-without-creating#35223022): `a.push(...b)`. Don't upvote this one anymore, as it never really answered the question, but it was a 2015 hack around first-hit-on-Google :)</sub>

---

For those that simply searched for "JavaScript array extend" and got here, you can very well use `Array.concat`.

```
var a = [1, 2, 3];
a = a.concat([5, 4, 3]);
```

Concat will return a copy the new array, as thread starter didn't want. But you might not care (certainly for most kind of uses this will be fine).

---

There's also some nice ECMAScript 6 sugar for this in the form of the spread operator:

```
const a = [1, 2, 3];
const b = [...a, 5, 4, 3];
```

(It also copies.)

Comment: The question was clearly stating: *"without creating a new array?"*

Comment: @Wilt: This is true, the answer says why though :) This was first hit on Google a long time. Also the other solutions were ugly, wanted something ideomatic and nice. Though nowadays the `arr.push(...arr2)` is newer and better and a Technically Correct(tm) answer to this particular question.

Comment: I hear you, but I searched for *"javascript append array without creating a new array"*, then it is sad to see that a 60 times upvoted answer that is high up doesn't answer the actual question ;) I didn't downvote, since you made it clear in your answer.

Comment: @Wilt and I searched "js extend array with array" and got here so thank you :)

Answer (score 238):

You should use a loop-based technique. Other answers on this page that are based on using `.apply` can fail for large arrays.

A fairly terse loop-based implementation is:

```
Array.prototype.extend = function (other_array) {
    /* You should include a test to check whether other_array really is an array */
    other_array.forEach(function(v) {this.push(v)}, this);
}
```

You can then do the following:

```
var a = [1,2,3];
var b = [5,4,3];
a.extend(b);
```

[DzinX's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1374131/1280629) (using push.apply) and other `.apply` based methods fail when the array that we are appending is large (tests show that for me large is > 150,000 entries approx in Chrome, and > 500,000 entries in Firefox). You can see this error occurring in [this jsperf](http://jsperf.com/array-extending-push-vs-concat).

An error occurs because the call stack size is exceeded when 'Function.prototype.apply' is called with a large array as the second argument. (MDN has a note on the dangers of exceeding call stack size using [Function.prototype.apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) - see the section titled "apply and built-in functions".)

For a speed comparison with other answers on this page, check out [this jsperf](http://jsperf.com/array-extending-push-vs-concat/18) (thanks to EaterOfCode). The loop-based implementation is similar in speed to using `Array.push.apply`, but tends to be a little slower than `Array.slice.apply`.

Interestingly, if the array you are appending is sparse, the `forEach` based method above can take advantage of the sparsity and outperform the `.apply` based methods; check out [this jsperf](http://jsperf.com/array-extending-push-vs-concat/5) if you want to test this for yourself.

By the way, do not be tempted (as I was!) to further shorten the forEach implementation to:

```
Array.prototype.extend = function (array) {
    array.forEach(this.push, this);
}
```

because this produces garbage results! Why? Because `Array.prototype.forEach` provides three arguments to the function it calls - these are: (element_value, element_index, source_array). All of these will be pushed onto your first array for every iteration of `forEach` if you use "forEach(this.push, this)"!

Comment: p.s. to test whether other_array really is an array, choose one of the options described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767486/how-do-you-check-if-a-variable-is-an-array-in-javascript

Comment: Good answer. I wasn't aware of this problem. I've cited your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4156156/96100

Comment: `.push.apply` is actually much faster than `.forEach` in v8, the fastest is still an inline loop.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum - could you post a link to some results showing that?  As far as I can see from the results collected at the jsperf linked at the end of this comment, using `.forEach` is faster than `.push.apply` in Chrome/Chromium (in all versions since v25).  I've not been able to test v8 in isolation, but if you have please link your results.  See jsperf: http://jsperf.com/array-extending-push-vs-concat/5

Comment: @jcdude your jsperf is invalid. as all elements in your array are `undefined`, so `.forEach` will skip them, making it the fastest. `.splice` is actually the fastest?! http://jsperf.com/array-extending-push-vs-concat/18

Comment: @jcdude instead of using  the `.forEach` method, you should be using the flat `for` loop, it's much faster.

Comment: I believe that Safari has a hard limit of 65535 for the stack size.

Comment: Re-tested different approaches, on fromArray of 100K items, Chrome (circa July 2020)

`fromArray.forEach( el => toArray.push(el)); // 5ms`
`toArray.push.apply(toArray,fromArray); // 14ms`
`for(let el of fromArray) toArray.push(el); // 11ms`

and `Array.push.apply()` was still by far the slowest and, of course, the only technique subject to stack limitations.

Answer (score 187):

I feel the most elegant these days is:

```
arr1.push(...arr2);
```

The [MDN article on the spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator#A_better_push) mentions this nice sugary way in ES2015 (ES6):

> ### A better push
>
> Example: push is often used to push an array to the end of an existing
>   array. In ES5 this is often done as:
>
> ```
> var arr1 = [0, 1, 2];
> var arr2 = [3, 4, 5];
> // Append all items from arr2 onto arr1
> Array.prototype.push.apply(arr1, arr2);
> ```
>
> In ES6 with spread this becomes:
>
> ```
> var arr1 = [0, 1, 2];
> var arr2 = [3, 4, 5];
> arr1.push(...arr2);
> ```

Do note that `arr2` can't be huge (keep it under about 100 000 items), because the call stack overflows, as per jcdude's answer.

Comment: Just a warning from a mistake I just made.  The ES6 version is very close to `arr1.push(arr2)`.  This can be a problem like so `arr1 = []; arr2=['a', 'b', 'd'];  arr1.push(arr2)` the result being an array of arrays `arr1 == [['a','b','d']]` rather than two arrays combined.  It is an easy mistake to make.  I prefer your second answer below for this reason.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/31521404/4808079

Comment: There's a convenience when using `.concat` is that the second argument must not be an array. This can be achieved by combining spread operator with `concat`, e.g. `arr1.push(...[].concat(arrayOrSingleItem))`

Comment: This is modern, elegant Javascript for cases where the target array is not empty.

Comment: Is this fast enough?

Answer (score 91):

#### Overview

- `a.push(...b)` - limited, fast, modern syntax
- `a.push.apply(a, b)` - limited, fast
- `a = a.concat(b)` unlimited, slow if `a` is large
- `for (let i in b) { a.push(b[i]); }` - unlimited, slow if `b` is large

Each snippet modifies `a` to be extended with `b`.

The "limited" snippets pass each array element as an argument, and [the maximum number of arguments you can pass to a function is limited](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22747272/1201863). From that link, it seems that `a.push(...b)` is reliable until there are about 32k elements in `b` (the size of `a` does not matter).

Relevant MDN documentation: [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax), [.apply()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply), [.concat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat), [.push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

#### Speed considerations

Every method is fast if both `a` and `b` are small, so in most web applications you'll want to use `push(...b)` and be done with it.

If you're handling more than a few thousand elements, what you want to do depends on the situation:

- you're adding a few elements to a large array
  → `push(...b)` is very fast
- you're adding many elements to a large array
  → `concat` is slightly faster than a loop
- you're adding many elements to a small array
  → `concat` is much faster than a loop
- you're *usually* adding only a few elements to any size array
  → loops are about as fast as the limited methods for small additions, but will never throw an exception even if it is not the most performant when you add many elements
- you're writing a wrapper function to always get the maximum performance
  → you'll need to check the lengths of the inputs dynamically and choose the right method, perhaps calling `push(...b_part)` (with slices of the big `b`) in a loop.

This surprised me: I thought `a=a.concat(b)` would be able to do a nice memcpy of `b` onto `a` without bothering to do individual extend operations as `a.push(...b)` would have to do, thus always being the fastest. Instead, `a.push(...b)` is much, much faster especially when `a` is large.

The speed of different methods was measured in Firefox 88 on Linux using:

```js
a = [];
for (let i = 0; i < Asize; i++){
  a.push(i);
}
b = [];
for (let i = 0; i < Bsize; i++){
  b.push({something: i});
}
t=performance.now();
// Code to test
console.log(performance.now() - t);
```

Parameters and results:

```
 ms | Asize | Bsize | code
----+-------+-------+------------------------------
 ~0 |  any  |  any  | a.push(...b)
 ~0 |  any  |  any  | a.push.apply(a, b)
480 |   10M |    50 | a = a.concat(b)
  0 |   10M |    50 | for (let i in b) a.push(b[i])
506 |   10M |  500k | a = a.concat(b)
882 |   10M |  500k | for (let i in b) a.push(b[i])
 11 |    10 |  500k | a = a.concat(b)
851 |    10 |  500k | for (let i in b) a.push(b[i])
```

Note that a `Bsize` of 500 000 is the largest value accepted by all methods on my system, that's why it is smaller than `Asize`.

All tests were run multiple times to see if the results are outliers or representative. The fast methods are almost immeasurable in just one run using `performance.now()`, of course, but since the slow methods are so obvious and the two fast methods both work on the same principle, we needn't bother repeating it a bunch of times to split hairs.

The `concat` method is always slow if either array is large, but the loop is only slow if it has to do a lot of function calls and doesn't care how large `a` is. A loop is thus similar to `push(...b)` or `push.apply` for small `b`s but without breaking if it does get large; however, when you approach the limit, `concat` is a bit faster again.

Answer (score 48):

First a few words about `apply()` in JavaScript to help understand why we use it:

> The `apply()` method calls a function with a given `this` value, and
>   arguments provided as an array.

Push expects a *list* of items to add to the array. The `apply()` method, however, takes the expected arguments for the function call as an array. This allows us to easily `push` the elements of one array into another array with the builtin `push()` method.

Imagine you have these arrays:

```js
var a = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var b = [5, 6, 7];
```

and simply do this:

```js
Array.prototype.push.apply(a, b);
```

The result will be:

```js
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
```

The same thing can be done in ES6 using the spread operator ("`...`") like this:

```js
a.push(...b); //a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
```

Shorter and better but not fully supported in all browsers at the moment.

Also if you want to *move* everything from array `b` to `a`, emptying `b` in the process, you can do this:

```js
while(b.length) {
  a.push(b.shift());
}
```

and the result will be as follows:

```js
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
b = [];
```

Comment: or `while (b.length) { a.push(b.shift()); }`, right?

Answer (score 39):

If you want to use jQuery, there is [$.merge()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.merge/)

Example:

```
a = [1, 2];
b = [3, 4, 5];
$.merge(a,b);
```

Result: a = `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`

Comment: How can I find the implementation (in the source code) of `jQuery.merge()`?

Comment: Took me 10 minutes -- jQuery is open source and the source is published on Github. I did a search for "merge" and further on located what appeared to be the definition of the merge function in the core.js file, see: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L331

Comment: Not to be confused with operations that merge sorted lists, such as http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_merge.htm

Answer (score 19):

as the top voted answer says, `a.push(...b)` is probably the correct answer taking into account the size limit issue.

On the other hand, some of the answers on performance seem out of date.

These numbers below are for 2022-05-20

[image]

[image]

[image]

from [here](https://jsbenchit.org/?src=8f5b937c44c7a684709550b8aef4679c)

At appears that `push` is fastest across the board in 2022. That may change in the future.

Answers ignoring the question (generating a new array) are missing the point. Lots of code might need/want to modify an array in place given there can be other references to the same array

```
let a = [1, 2, 3];
let b = [4, 5, 6];
let c = a;
a = a.concat(b);    // a and c are no longer referencing the same array
```

Those other references could be deep in some object, something that was captured in a closure, etc...

As a probably bad design but as an illustration, imagine you had

```
const carts = [
  { userId: 123, cart: [item1, item2], },
  { userId: 456, cart: [item1, item2, item3], },
];
```

and a function

```
function getCartForUser(userId) {
  return customers.find(c => c.userId === userId);
}
```

Then you want to add items to the cart

```
const cart = getCartForUser(userId);
if (cart) {
  cart.concat(newItems);      // FAIL 
  cart.push(...newItems);     // Success! 
}
```

---

As an aside, the answers suggesting modifying `Array.prototype` are arguably bad adivce. Changing the native prototypes is bascially a landmine in your code. Another implementation maybe be different than yours and so it will break your code or you'll break their code expecting the other behavior. This includes if/when a native implmentation gets added that clashes with yours. You might say "I know what I'm using so no issue" and that might be true at the moment and you're a single dev but add a second dev and they can't read your mind. And, you are that second dev in a few years when you've forgotten and then graft some other library (analytics?, logging?, ...) on to your page and forget the landmind you left in the code.

This is not just theory. There are countless stories on the net of people running into these landmines.

Arguably there are just a few safe uses for modifying a native object's prototype. One is to polyfill an existing and specified implementation in an old browser. In that case, the spec is defined, the spec is implemented is shipping in new browsers, you just want to get the same behavior in old browsers. That's pretty safe. Pre-patching (spec in progress but not shipping) is arguably not safe. Specs change before shipping.

Answer (score 18):

I like the `a.push.apply(a, b)` method described above, and if you want you can always create a library function like this:

```
Array.prototype.append = function(array)
{
    this.push.apply(this, array)
}
```

and use it like this

```
a = [1,2]
b = [3,4]

a.append(b)
```

Comment: The push.apply method should not be used as it can cause a stack overflow (and therefore fail) if your "array" argument is a large array (e.g. > ~150000 entries in Chrome).  You should use "array.forEach" - see my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17368101/1280629

Comment: In ES6, just use `a.push(...b)`

Answer (score 14):

It is possible to do it using `splice()`:

```
b.unshift(b.length)
b.unshift(a.length)
Array.prototype.splice.apply(a,b) 
b.shift() // Restore b
b.shift() //
```

But despite being uglier it is not faster than `push.apply`, at least not in Firefox 3.0.

Comment: I have found the same thing, splice doesn't provide performance enhancements to pushing each item until about 10,000 element arrays http://jsperf.com/splice-vs-push

Comment: +1 Thanks for adding this and the performance comparison, saved me the effort of testing this method.

Comment: Using either splice.apply or push.apply can fail due to a stack overflow if array b is large. They are also slower than using a "for" or "forEach" loop - see this jsPerf: http://jsperf.com/array-extending-push-vs-concat/5 and my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374126/how-to-append-an-array-to-an-existing-javascript-array/17368101#17368101

Answer (score 5):

This solution works for me (using the spread operator of ECMAScript 6):

```js
let array = ['my', 'solution', 'works'];
let newArray = [];
let newArray2 = [];
newArray.push(...array); // Adding to same array
newArray2.push([...array]); // Adding as child/leaf/sub-array
console.log(newArray);
console.log(newArray2);
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm adding this answer, because despite the question stating clearly `without creating a new array`, pretty much every answer just ignores it.

Modern JavaScript works well with arrays and alike as iterable objects. This makes it possible to implement a version of `concat` that builds upon that, and spans the array data across its parameters logically.

The example below makes use of [iter-ops](https://github.com/vitaly-t/iter-ops) library that features such logic:

```
import {pipe, concat} from 'iter-ops';

const i = pipe(
    originalArray,
    concat(array2, array3, array4, ...)
); //=> Iterable

for(const a of i) {
    console.log(a); // iterate over values from all arrays
}
```

Above, no new array is created. Operator [concat](https://vitaly-t.github.io/iter-ops/functions/concat.html) will iterate through the original array, then will automatically continue into `array2`, then `array3`, and so on, in the specified order.

This is the most efficient way of joining arrays in terms of memory usage.

And if, at the end, you decide to convert it into an actual physical array, you can do so via the spread operator or `Array.from`:

```
const fullArray1 = [...i]; // pulls all values from iterable, into a new array

const fullArray2 = Array.from(i); // does the same
```

Answer (score 0):

Combining the answers...

```
Array.prototype.extend = function(array) {
    if (array.length < 150000) {
        this.push.apply(this, array)
    } else {
        for (var i = 0, len = array.length; i < len; ++i) {
            this.push(array[i]);
        };
    }  
}
```

Comment: No, there is no need to do this. A for loop using forEach is faster than using push.apply, and works no matter what the length of the array to extend by is.  Have a look at my revised answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17368101/1280629

In any case, how do you know that 150000 is the right number to use for all browsers?  This is a fudge.

Comment: lol. my answer is unrecognizable, but appears to be some combo of others found at the time - i.e. a summary. no worries

Answer (score 0):

You can create a polyfill for extend as I have below. It will add to the array; in-place and return itself, so that you can chain other methods.

```js
if (Array.prototype.extend === undefined) {
  Array.prototype.extend = function(other) {
    this.push.apply(this, arguments.length > 1 ? arguments : other);
    return this;
  };
}

function print() {
  document.body.innerHTML += [].map.call(arguments, function(item) {
    return typeof item === 'object' ? JSON.stringify(item) : item;
  }).join(' ') + '\n';
}
document.body.innerHTML = '';

var a = [1, 2, 3];
var b = [4, 5, 6];

print('Concat');
print('(1)', a.concat(b));
print('(2)', a.concat(b));
print('(3)', a.concat(4, 5, 6));

print('\nExtend');
print('(1)', a.extend(b));
print('(2)', a.extend(b));
print('(3)', a.extend(4, 5, 6));
```

```css
body {
  font-family: monospace;
  white-space: pre;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution to merge more than two arrays

```
var a = [1, 2],
    b = [3, 4, 5],
    c = [6, 7];

// Merge the contents of multiple arrays together into the first array
var mergeArrays = function() {
 var i, len = arguments.length;
 if (len > 1) {
  for (i = 1; i < len; i++) {
    arguments[0].push.apply(arguments[0], arguments[i]);
  }
 }
};
```

Then call and print as:

```
mergeArrays(a, b, c);
console.log(a)
```

Output will be: `Array [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]`

Answer (score -2):

The answer is super simple.

```
>>> a = [1, 2]
[1, 2]
>>> b = [3, 4, 5]
[3, 4, 5]
>>> SOMETHING HERE
(The following code will combine the two arrays.)

a = a.concat(b);

>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Concat acts very similarly to JavaScript string concatenation. It will return a combination of the parameter you put into the concat function on the end of the array you call the function on. The crux is that you have to assign the returned value to a variable or it gets lost. So for example

```
a.concat(b);  <--- This does absolutely nothing since it is just returning the combined arrays, but it doesn't do anything with it.
```

Comment: As clearly stated in [the docs for `Array.prototype.concat()` at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) this will return a **new Array**, it will not append to the existing array as OP was clearly asking.

Answer (score -2):

Another option, if you have lodash installed:

```
 import { merge } from 'lodash';

 var arr1 = merge(arr1, arr2);
```

Comment: I don't think this works on arrays like this. Please provide a link to a working snippet.

Answer (score -3):

Use `Array.extend` instead of `Array.push` for  > 150,000 records.

```
if (!Array.prototype.extend) {
  Array.prototype.extend = function(arr) {
    if (!Array.isArray(arr)) {
      return this;
    }

    for (let record of arr) {
      this.push(record);
    }

    return this;
  };
}
```

Answer (score -3):

You can do that by simply adding new elements to the array with the help of the `push()` method.

```js
let colors = ["Red", "Blue", "Orange"];
console.log('Array before push: ' + colors);
// append new value to the array
colors.push("Green");
console.log('Array after push : ' + colors);
```

Another method is used for appending an element to the beginning of an array is the unshift() function, which adds and returns the new length. It accepts multiple arguments, attaches the indexes of existing elements, and finally returns the new length of an array:

```js
let colors = ["Red", "Blue", "Orange"];
console.log('Array before unshift: ' + colors);
// append new value to the array
colors.unshift("Black", "Green");
console.log('Array after unshift : ' + colors);
```

There are other methods too. You can check them out [here](https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/javascript/how-to-add-new-elements-to-a-javascript-array.html).

Comment: This adds a value to an array. It does not add an array to an array (in-place) as per the question and as Python's list `extend` method does.

Answer (score -9):

Super simple, does not count on spread operators or apply, if that's an issue.

```
b.map(x => a.push(x));
```

After running some performance tests on this, it's terribly slow, but answers the question in regards to not creating a new array.  Concat is significantly faster, even jQuery's `$.merge()` whoops it.

https://jsperf.com/merge-arrays19b/1

Comment: You should use `.forEach` rather than `.map` if you're not using the return value. It better conveys the intention of your code.

Comment: @david - to each their own.  I prefer the synax of `.map` but you could also do `b.forEach(function(x) { a.push(x)} )`.  In fact I added that to the jsperf test and it's a hair faster than map.  Still super slow.

Comment: This isn't a case of preference. These 'functional' methods each have a specific meaning associated with them. Calling `.map` here looks very weird. It would be like calling `b.filter(x => a.push(x))`. It works, but it confuses the reader by implying something is happening when it's not.

Comment: Not worth my time to debate.  It works.  I called out the performance issue.  If you think it looks weird, don't use it.

Comment: @elPastor it should be worth your time, because some other guy like me would sit and scratch the nape of his neck wondering what else is happening there in your code he can't see. In most ordinary cases, it's the clarity of intent that matters, not the performance. Please respect the time of those who read your code, cause they might be many when you're just one. Thanks.

Comment: @Dmytro Y - you don't me, nor what is going on in my life, and thus you can't begin to know what is or is not worth my time.  If you take issue with the code itself, be specific about why and I'll improve my answer.  Finally, it's unclear what you mean by "what else is happening" in this context.  It's a simple `.map()` function performing exactly as intended with a result that is exactly as expected.  If you're not familiar with the `.map()` function itself, there is plenty of documentation online for further clarification.

Comment: @elPastor I know exactly what `.map()` does and that is the issue. This knowledge would make me think you need the resulting array, otherwise it would be a good thing to use `.forEach()` to make the reader cautious about the side-effects of the callback function. Strictly speaking your solution creates an additional array of natural numbers (results of `push`), while the question states: "without creating a new array".

Comment: Someone just edited my answer to use `.forEach()` instead of `.map()`.  I changed it back to the original answer.  Although I disagree with the negative comments, I think it's important to leave them up for discussion purposes.  At this point, this answer has a very negative score, I can't imagine anyone will implement it in any meaningful code.  Please do not edit further.