# Google Analytics: _gaq.push multiple items from another array

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I'm triyng to push multiple items into the _gaq.push() for google analytics.

I have an array of Ids that im looping through to create the array to pass to .push();

```
var gaDetails = new Array();
var productIdsArray = productIds.split(",");
for(var i = 0; i < productIdsArray.length; ++i)
    gaDetails.push(['_trackEvent', 'Quote', '' + step, '' + productIdsArray[i]]);

_gaq.push(gaDetails);
```

It looks like theres an extra set of [] around each array. Maybe I'm not seeing something but the way google describes their syntax looks wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you don't need the other array, and while you're at it you might as well use a faster loop.

```
var productIdsArray = productIds.split(","),
    i = productIdsArray.length;

while(i--)
{
   _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Quote', '' + step, '' + productIdsArray[i]]);
}
```

Comment: But theres a way to pass multiple objects to the .push method according to google's site

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment from Ryan, Google encourages to push an multiple commands via one call of _gaq.push

If one has an array of commands and wants to add them all to _gaq this can be achieved by

```
_gaq.push.apply(_gaq, gaDetails);
```

Got a clue from [Javascript push array values into another array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4156101/javascript-push-array-values-into-another-array)

For performance it's probably fine to just call _gaq.push with each element.