# Web speech API: Consistently get the supported speech synthesis voices on iOS safari

Tags: javascript, ios, safari, speech-synthesis

I'm trying to get the list of supported speech synthesis voices on iOS Safari.

As per the API, I should be able to get an array of voices by calling:

```
window.speechSynthesis.getVoices();
```

Sometimes this gives me list of voices, other times it doesn't. See the following jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sq7xf327/

If I open this on my iPhone 5 (iOS 8.1.3), I don't get back consistent results. Sometimes I get back all 37 voices, and other times I get returned 0 voices. If you keep on refreshing it sporadically displays either 37 or 0.

I know that in Chrome you can add an event listener to the

```
window.speechSynthesis.voiceschanged
```

event to know when the voices have loaded, but this event is not supported in Safari.

A trick I've tried is to check periodically:

```
var timer = setInterval(function () {
    window.voices_ = window.speechSynthesis.getVoices();
    if (window.voices_.length > 0) {
        clearInterval(timer);
    }
}, 1000);
```

This has also not given me consistent results.

Any idea how I can reliably and consistently get the supported speech synthesis voices on iOS Safari?

Answer (score 2):

I also encountered this and reported it as a bug to Apple. As of today the bug report is still open.

What I ended up doing as workaround was to hard-code an array of the 37 voices. If `speechSynthesis.getVoices()` returns an empty array then use the hard-coded array instead.

```
var _voices = [];

// iOS 8
var _iOSvoices = [
    {name: "pt-BR", voiceURI: "pt-BR", lang: "pt-BR", localService: true, default: true},
    {name: "fr-CA", voiceURI: "fr-CA", lang: "fr-CA", localService: true, default: true},
    {name: "sk-SK", voiceURI: "sk-SK", lang: "sk-SK", localService: true, default: true},
    {name: "th-TH", voiceURI: "th-TH", lang: "th-TH", localService: true, default: true},
    {name: "ro-RO", voiceURI: "ro-RO", lang: "ro-RO", localService: true, default: true},
    {name: "no-NO", voiceURI: "no-NO", lang: "no-NO", localService: true, default: true},
    {name: "fi-FI", voiceURI: "fi-FI", lang: "fi-FI", localService: true, default: true},
    {name: "pl-PL", voiceURI: "pl-PL", lang: "pl-PL", localService: true, default: true},
    {name: "de-DE", voiceURI: "de-DE", lang: "de-DE", localService: true, default: true},
    {name: "nl-NL", voiceURI: "nl-NL", lang: "nl-NL", localService: true, default: true},
    {name: "id-ID", voiceURI: "id-ID", lang: "id-ID", localService: true, default: true},
    {name: "tr-TR", voiceURI: "tr-TR", lang: "tr-TR", localService: true, default: true},
    {name: "it-IT", voiceURI: "it-IT", lang: "it-IT", localService: true, default: true},
    {name: "pt-PT", voiceURI: "pt-PT", lang: "pt-PT", localService: true, default: true},
    {name: "fr-FR", voiceURI: "fr-FR", lang: "fr-FR", localService: true, default: true},
    {name: "ru-RU", voiceURI: "ru-RU", lang: "ru-RU", localService: true, default: true},
    {name: "es-MX", voiceURI: "es-MX", lang: "es-MX", localService: true, default: true},
    {name: "zh-HK", voiceURI: "zh-HK", lang: "zh-HK", localService: true, default: true},
    {name: "sv-SE", voiceURI: "sv-SE", lang: "sv-SE", localService: true, default: true},
    {name: "hu-HU", voiceURI: "hu-HU", lang: "hu-HU", localService: true, default: true},
    {name: "zh-TW", voiceURI: "zh-TW", lang: "zh-TW", localService: true, default: true},
    {name: "es-ES", voiceURI: "es-ES", lang: "es-ES", localService: true, default: true},
    {name: "zh-CN", voiceURI: "zh-CN", lang: "zh-CN", localService: true, default: true},
    {name: "nl-BE", voiceURI: "nl-BE", lang: "nl-BE", localService: true, default: true},
    {name: "en-GB", voiceURI: "en-GB", lang: "en-GB", localService: true, default: true},
    {name: "ar-SA", voiceURI: "ar-SA", lang: "ar-SA", localService: true, default: true},
    {name: "ko-KR", voiceURI: "ko-KR", lang: "ko-KR", localService: true, default: true},
    {name: "cs-CZ", voiceURI: "cs-CZ", lang: "cs-CZ", localService: true, default: true},
    {name: "en-ZA", voiceURI: "en-ZA", lang: "en-ZA", localService: true, default: true},
    {name: "en-AU", voiceURI: "en-AU", lang: "en-AU", localService: true, default: true},
    {name: "da-DK", voiceURI: "da-DK", lang: "da-DK", localService: true, default: true},
    {name: "en-US", voiceURI: "en-US", lang: "en-US", localService: true, default: true},
    {name: "en-IE", voiceURI: "en-IE", lang: "en-IE", localService: true, default: true},
    {name: "he-IL", voiceURI: "he-IL", lang: "he-IL", localService: true, default: true},
    {name: "hi-IN", voiceURI: "hi-IN", lang: "hi-IN", localService: true, default: true},
    {name: "el-GR", voiceURI: "el-GR", lang: "el-GR", localService: true, default: true},
    {name: "ja-JP", voiceURI: "ja-JP", lang: "ja-JP", localService: true, default: true}
];

function populateVoices() {
    // wait first
    var watch = setTimeout(function() {
        _voices = speechSynthesis.getVoices();

        if (_voices.length === 0) {
            // use hard-coded list because speechSynthesis.getVoices() didn't work
            _voices = _iOSvoices;
        }

        clearTimeout(watch);
    }, 100);
}
```

**UPDATE**

iOS 9 is somewhat better at this if you remove the delay.

```
function _populateVoices() {
    _voices = speechSynthesis.getVoices();

    if (_voices.length === 0) {
        // use hard-coded list because speechSynthesis.getVoices() didn't work
        _voices = _iOS9voices;
    }
}

var _iOS9voices = [
  { name: "Maged", voiceURI: "com.apple.ttsbundle.Maged-compact", lang: "ar-SA", localService: true, "default": true },
  { name: "Zuzana", voiceURI: "com.apple.ttsbundle.Zuzana-compact", lang: "cs-CZ", localService: true, "default": true },
  { name: "Sara", voiceURI: "com.apple.ttsbundle.Sara-compact", lang: "da-DK", localService: true, "default": true },
  { name: "Anna", voiceURI: "com.apple.ttsbundle.Anna-compact", lang: "de-DE", localService: true, "default": true },
  { name: "Melina", voiceURI: "com.apple.ttsbundle.Melina-compact", lang: "el-GR", localService: true, "default": true },
  { name: "Karen", voiceURI: "com.apple.ttsbundle.Karen-compact", lang: "en-AU", localService: true, "default": true },
  { name: "Daniel", voiceURI: "com.apple.ttsbundle.Daniel-compact", lang: "en-GB", localService: true, "default": true },
  { name: "Moira", voiceURI: "com.apple.ttsbundle.Moira-compact", lang: "en-IE", localService: true, "default": true },
  { name: "Samantha (Enhanced)", voiceURI: "com.apple.ttsbundle.Samantha-premium", lang: "en-US", localService: true, "default": true },
  { name: "Samantha", voiceURI: "com.apple.ttsbundle.Samantha-compact", lang: "en-US", localService: true, "default": true },
  { name: "Tessa", voiceURI: "com.apple.ttsbundle.Tessa-compact", lang: "en-ZA", localService: true, "default": true },
  { name: "Monica", voiceURI: "com.apple.ttsbundle.Monica-compact", lang: "es-ES", localService: true, "default": true },
  { name: "Paulina", voiceURI: "com.apple.ttsbundle.Paulina-compact", lang: "es-MX", localService: true, "default": true },
  { name: "Satu", voiceURI: "com.apple.ttsbundle.Satu-compact", lang: "fi-FI", localService: true, "default": true },
  { name: "Amelie", voiceURI: "com.apple.ttsbundle.Amelie-compact", lang: "fr-CA", localService: true, "default": true },
  { name: "Thomas", voiceURI: "com.apple.ttsbundle.Thomas-compact", lang: "fr-FR", localService: true, "default": true },
  { name: "Carmit", voiceURI: "com.apple.ttsbundle.Carmit-compact", lang: "he-IL", localService: true, "default": true },
  { name: "Lekha", voiceURI: "com.apple.ttsbundle.Lekha-compact", lang: "hi-IN", localService: true, "default": true },
  { name: "Mariska", voiceURI: "com.apple.ttsbundle.Mariska-compact", lang: "hu-HU", localService: true, "default": true },
  { name: "Damayanti", voiceURI: "com.apple.ttsbundle.Damayanti-compact", lang: "id-ID", localService: true, "default": true },
  { name: "Alice", voiceURI: "com.apple.ttsbundle.Alice-compact", lang: "it-IT", localService: true, "default": true },
  { name: "Kyoko", voiceURI: "com.apple.ttsbundle.Kyoko-compact", lang: "ja-JP", localService: true, "default": true },
  { name: "Yuna", voiceURI: "com.apple.ttsbundle.Yuna-compact", lang: "ko-KR", localService: true, "default": true },
  { name: "Ellen", voiceURI: "com.apple.ttsbundle.Ellen-compact", lang: "nl-BE", localService: true, "default": true },
  { name: "Xander", voiceURI: "com.apple.ttsbundle.Xander-compact", lang: "nl-NL", localService: true, "default": true },
  { name: "Nora", voiceURI: "com.apple.ttsbundle.Nora-compact", lang: "no-NO", localService: true, "default": true },
  { name: "Zosia", voiceURI: "com.apple.ttsbundle.Zosia-compact", lang: "pl-PL", localService: true, "default": true },
  { name: "Luciana", voiceURI: "com.apple.ttsbundle.Luciana-compact", lang: "pt-BR", localService: true, "default": true },
  { name: "Joana", voiceURI: "com.apple.ttsbundle.Joana-compact", lang: "pt-PT", localService: true, "default": true },
  { name: "Ioana", voiceURI: "com.apple.ttsbundle.Ioana-compact", lang: "ro-RO", localService: true, "default": true },
  { name: "Milena", voiceURI: "com.apple.ttsbundle.Milena-compact", lang: "ru-RU", localService: true, "default": true },
  { name: "Laura", voiceURI: "com.apple.ttsbundle.Laura-compact", lang: "sk-SK", localService: true, "default": true },
  { name: "Alva", voiceURI: "com.apple.ttsbundle.Alva-compact", lang: "sv-SE", localService: true, "default": true },
  { name: "Kanya", voiceURI: "com.apple.ttsbundle.Kanya-compact", lang: "th-TH", localService: true, "default": true },
  { name: "Yelda", voiceURI: "com.apple.ttsbundle.Yelda-compact", lang: "tr-TR", localService: true, "default": true },
  { name: "Ting-Ting", voiceURI: "com.apple.ttsbundle.Ting-Ting-compact", lang: "zh-CN", localService: true, "default": true },
  { name: "Sin-Ji", voiceURI: "com.apple.ttsbundle.Sin-Ji-compact", lang: "zh-HK", localService: true, "default": true },
  { name: "Mei-Jia", voiceURI: "com.apple.ttsbundle.Mei-Jia-compact", lang: "zh-TW", localService: true, "default": true }
];
```

Comment: Thanks Sarah, do you have a link to this bug report? Also, even if you hard-code an array, would that be useful when setting the voice with which the speech synthesiser would talk? e.g. `SpeechSynthesisUtterance.voice = voices[x]`. You have to specify a `SpeechSynthesisVoice` object, not merely a string. I guess what I'm asking is: What does your hard-coded array look like?

Comment: @KenAdams The report is #19770992, unfortunately it's not public. I've added code above. The array is of Javascript objects, just like would be returned from `speechSynthesis.getVoices()`.

Comment: Hey, @SarahElan, I was just trying to implement your `_iOS9voices` workaround but `msg.voice = _iOS9voices[0]` throws `TypeError: The SpeechSynthesisUtterance.voice attribute must be an instance of SpeechSynthesisVoice` (msg defined as `var msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance()`). It seems like the `voice` parameter must be a properly initialized `SpeechSynthesisVoice` object. Did you have any ideas on how to go about that? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I implement that JS functionality for my site for Desktop, Android and iOS.

As I understood, for Mobile, the speech utterance is regulated by **GENERAL PHONE SETTINGS**, so user need go to TTS setting and choose preferable voice for  specify language, and maybe download the good voice. For example, iOS *Alex voice* is closed to 800mb and it works offline.
List of supported languages you can find on vendor site for specific Android or iOS version.

So finally we have:

**First**, we need to have function to check is it mobile:

// [Detecting a mobile browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381673/detecting-a-mobile-browser)

```
window.mobilecheck = function() {
    var check = false;
    (function(a){if(/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows ce|xda|xiino/i.test(a)||/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(a.substr(0,4)))check = true})(navigator.userAgent||navigator.vendor||window.opera);
    return check;
};
```

**Second**, initialization part, piece of Angular code, that you can change in your project, so I have  SpeechSynthesisService($log, $q, $cookies, $timeout, commonService) with following code:

```
    var languagesEnglish = {
        'en-US' : {desc: 'English (United States)', voices: []},
        'en-GB' : {desc: 'English (United Kingdom)', voices: []}
    };
    // 'ru_RU' android codes
    var languagesRussian = {
        'ru-RU' : {desc: 'Russian', voices: []}
    };

    var speakerEng = {lang: 'en-US', desc: 'English (United States)', voice: null};
    var speakerRu = {lang: 'ru-RU', desc: 'Russian', voice: null};
    var englishSpeakers = [];

    if ('speechSynthesis' in window) {
        if (window.mobilecheck()) {
            englishSpeakers = prepareEnglishSpeakers();
            initVoicesJob.resolve();
        }

        window.speechSynthesis.onvoiceschanged = function() {
            if (initVoicesJob.promise.$$state.status) return;
            $log.debug(currentTime() + " InitVoice: onvoiceschanged");
            desktopInitializeVoices();
            englishSpeakers = prepareEnglishSpeakers();
            initVoicesJob.resolve();
        };
    }
```

So in application I have active speakerEng and active speakerRu, for mobile version the *voices* arrays are empty.

**Third**, when I want in application to say any text I call the following function:

```
    function sayAnyText(speaker, voiceVolume, text) {
        if (isNotSupportSpeechSynthesis()) {
            var tJob = $q.defer();
            $timeout(function() {
                tJob.resolve();
            });
            return tJob.promise;
        }

        var phrases = [];
        if (text.constructor === Array) {
            for (var ti = 0, tn = text.length; ti<tn; ti++) {
                var iPhrases = splitToPhrase(text[ti]);
                // concat arrays, fast method: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4156101/javascript-push-array-values-into-another-array
                for (var pi = 0, pn = iPhrases.length; pi<pn; pi++) {
                    phrases.push(iPhrases[pi]);
                }
            }
        } else {
            phrases = splitToPhrase(text);
        }

        speechSynthesis.cancel();
        stopSpeechJob();
        startSpeechJob();

        for (var i = 0, n = phrases.length; i < n; i++) {
            var msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
            msg.lang = speaker.lang;
            if (speaker.voice) msg.voice = speaker.voice;
            msg.rate = 1;
            msg.volume = voiceVolume;
            msg.text = phrases[i];

            if (i + 1 == n) {
                msg.onend = function(event) {
                    $log.debug(currentTime() + "Speech ends: ", event.currentTarget.text, event);
                    stopSpeechJob();
                };
                msg.onerror = function(event) {
                    $log.error(currentTime() + "Speech ends with error: ", event.currentTarget.text, event);
                    stopSpeechJob();
                };
            } else {
                msg.onend = function(event) {
                    $log.debug(currentTime() + "Speech ends: ", event.currentTarget.text, event);
                };
                msg.onerror = function(event) {
                    $log.error(currentTime() + "Speech ends with error: ", event.currentTarget.text, event);
                };
            }

            speechSynthesis.speak(msg);
        }

        return getSpeechJob();
    }
```

The main piece is following:

```
msg.lang = speaker.lang;
if (speaker.voice) msg.voice = speaker.voice;
```

1.we always set a language
2.for desktop version speaker has a voice, for mobile version not.

p.s.
I tested it, and it works for iOS9 (iPhone 6), Android 5.0.1 (Samsung Galaxy 4), and desktop Chrome 48.0.
Feel free to ask if you have any questions or if you need more code.

Comment: "user need go to TTS setting" is not clear, there is no TTS setting.