# Cannot read property 'push' of undefined Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

Hi it seams like i can't push my array ?
code:

```
  $scope.arrResult = [];
  dpd.timesheets.get( function (result) {
    console.log(result);

    for (i = 0, n = result.length; i < n; i++) {
      var item = result[i];
      $scope.arrResult[item.week].push(item);
    }
    console.log($scope.arrResult);

  });
```

i get this console error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
```

if i set `$scope.arrResult[item.week].push(item); to   $scope.arrResult[item.week] = item;`
it works with no error
but i need / want to push, whats wrong ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is because

```
$scope.arrResult[item.week]
```

itself is not an array.

[push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) is of `Array.prototype`

To see what I mean, try

```
$scope.arrResult[item.week] = [];
```

or

```
$scope.arrResult[item.week] = new Array();
```

and then try `push()`

Comment: I see, mmm.. but how do i do this the correct way then, if i set = [] before push, i just get one object in the array, and i want all  :)

Comment: @Stweet, what do you mean 'all'. Maybe don't even need an array?

Comment: result contaions alot of objects, and i want this objects sortet in $scope.arrResult[week]
eg. $scope.arrResult[21] contains all objects of week 21

Comment: @Stweet, Ah! Use concat http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4156101/javascript-push-array-values-into-another-array

Comment: @Stweet So, if item is an array, then do  $scope.arrResult[item.week].concat(item);

Comment: mmm it gives me Cannot read property 'concat' of undefined

Comment: Did you do $scope.arrResult[item.week] = []; first?

Comment: but concat i also for array into array ?
i want like arrResult[21] = object1, object2, object3.....

Comment: no error with  $scope.arrResult[item.week] = [];
but it only gives me empty arrays :/

Comment: @Stweet, can you replicate the issue in a fiddle so I can better help?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/p8uzavrw/
as you see in console i got week 21  and 33 but they are empty, i want them to have the objects of week 21 and 33 :)

Comment: Try it with push like in https://jsfiddle.net/p8uzavrw/1/

Comment: i tried `outerArray[innerArray] = [];` and got `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '[' `