# How can I concatenate two arrays in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, concatenation

I saw this [response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374126/how-to-extend-an-existing-javascript-array-with-another-array) for extending one array with another so I tried:

```
console.log(['a', 'b'].push.apply(['c', 'd']));
```

but it prints:

```
2
```

shouldn't it print:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

If not, what was I doing wrong?

Comment: See here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat

Comment: `Array.prototype.push.apply(ABArray, CDArray)`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> if not what was i doing wrong?

First of all, [`.push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) returns the *new length* of the array:

```
var arr = [1, 1, 1];
console.log(arr.push(1)); // 4
console.log(arr); // [1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Second, [`.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) needs two arguments: The object you want to apply the function to, and an array of arguments. You only pass a single argument, so your code is basically equivalent to:

```
['c', 'd'].push()
```

I.e. you are not adding anything to the `['c', 'd']` array. That also explains why you see `2` in the output: `['c', 'd']` has length `2` and `.push()` doesn't add any elements to it so it still has length `2`.

If you want to use `.push` to mutate the original array (instead of creating a new one like [`.concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) does), it would have to look like:

```
var arr = ['a', 'b'];
arr.push.apply(arr, ['c', 'd']); // equivalent to Array.prototype.push.apply(arr, [...])
//              ^   ^--------^
//    apply to arr   arguments
console.log(arr); // ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

---

See also

- [How to append something to an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/351409/218196)
- [Javascript push array values into another array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4156101/218196)

Comment: maybe this example is clearer : `[].push.apply(arr, ['c', 'd']);`

Comment: I agree, however, I don't like creating arrays unnecessarily ;)

Answer (score 17):

Try this:

```
 console.log(['a', 'b'].concat(['c', 'd']));
```

Answer (score 16):

If your scenario allows for ES6 syntax, you can use the [spread element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) to concatenate arrays:

```
var arr1 = [1,2];
var arr2 = [3,4];
var arr3 = [...arr1, ...arr2];
console.log(arr3); // Logs [1,2,3,4]
```

Comment: Can we call it *spread element*? It's not an operator (even if you read this in places).

Comment: Updated to state `spread element`.  For anyone interested, Spread Element is the wording used in the ES6 specification.  You can check it in the [Expressions section](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-expressions).  Scroll down a bit to _SpreadElement_.  The more you know!

Answer (score 5):

If you're using a modern browser then you can use the spread operator, `...` like so:

```
console.log([...['a', 'b'], ...['c', 'd']])
```

If you're using an older browser/no transpiler then `concat` is the way to go:

```
console.log(['a', 'b'].concat(['c', 'd']))
```

Answer (score 3):

As there seems to be a general misunderstanding here about the use of various array appending methods I will add to it with the safest alternative to ES6's introduction of the spread operator

**Functional language**

Functional languages were developed to simplify code development allowing programmers and systems engineers to define functions to replace common operations/algorithms.
JS is a functional language, you write functions to make life easier, save you typing and making the program easier to test and validate, so why fight it with dangerous alternatives .

The mistake being made in the answers (with the exception of Jonathan Michalik answer) is they are all trying to either coerce the language into doing something that should be done by a function (`Function.apply`), or providing a solution without explanation of what it is doing (`Array.concat`).

Write a function to append arrays, for example.

```
function appendArray(array,array1){ // adds the items in array1 
                                    // array1 can be any type
                                    // to the end of array 
    var len,i;
    array1 = [].concat(array1);   // ensure array1 is an array
    len = array1.length;
    i = 0;
    while(i < len){
        array[array.length] = array1[i++]; // this is 2* quicker than invoking push
    }
    return array;
}
```

For the 60 seconds it takes to write, or less to include as part of a general library you have created a safe and general purpose array append function.

```
log(appendArray([0, 1, 2, 3], 4)); // 0,1,2,3,4
log(appendArray([0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])); // 0,1,2,3,4,5,6
```

Now to why the other answers are not good solutions.

**Array.concat**

is the safer option, and should be used if you are in control of all references to the array. It suffers from the fact that it creates a new array when it is used.

```
var array1 = [1,2,3];
var array2 = [4,5,6];
array1 = array1.concat(array2); // 1,2,3,4,5,6
```

Many are under the mistaken belief that the concat( array2 ) is added to array1, it is not, it is added to a copy of array1. If you have other references to the original array then you end up creating  a copy of the concatenated array, while the original array remains in memory.

```
function doSomething(array){
    ... generate some info
    array.concat(info);
}

var myArray = [...someData];  // the array
var myObject.setArray(myArray); // create a new referance to the array in myObject
myArray = doSomething(myArray);  // adds info via concat to the array.
```

It is not immediately apparent, but you now have two arrays the original inside myObject, and the concatenated version in `myObject` which may store the array referance in closure, that you can not change or delete unless you dereference all associated context. Nor do you know how many references to the original array exist.

**Function.apply()**

There are many reasons not to use this function but of particular note is using it on the `Array.push` function. It suffers from indeterminacy if you use it without type checking the arrays.

```
var myArray = [1,2,3,4];
var data = getSomeData(); // may return array or array like data
myArray = doSomeWorkOn(myArray); // the spec says this may return undefined
myArray.push.apply(myArray,data); // what happen here is indeterminate and
                                     // depends on the JS context, the JS mode
                                     // and the JS version
```

Without vetting myArray for undefined you can not predict what the result of apply will be. It could throw and error, or it may silently fail if the global scope has a push function and you are not in strict mode.

Without knowing the JS version ES5 or ES6 the apply may have pushed one object `data` onto myArray, or all the items in `data` ES5 does not recognise array like objects as arrays for `Function.apply` while ES6 does. So you must vet `myArray`, or `data` to be of the correct type for the current JS version.

Arguments have limits that are dependent on the current JS context, there is also inconsistency between JS context's handling of long argument lists. Some will throw an error, others will simply truncate the arguments.

```
var myPixelData = [];
myPixelData.push.apply(myPixelData,getSomePixelData()); // what will happen????
```

This may throw, or it may work, or it may have only pushed 65535 items onto the array, or more, or less. You will have to wrap it in a try catch, and vet the results against the length of the array returned by `getPixelData`. All the added complexity just to make it easier???

So why use `Function.apply` on `Array.push` or use `Array.concat` when it is so much easier to write a function to do what you want and save you from a long list of problems, ambiguities, and errors.

Answer (score 1):

You should try this:

```
a= ['a', 'b'];
b= ['c', 'd'];
a.push.apply(a,b);

console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 1):

you should use variables like so

```js
 <script type="text/javascript">
 var arr1=['a', 'b'];
 var arr2=['c', 'd'];
 Array.prototype.push.apply(arr1, arr2);
  console.log(arr1);
 </script>
```

Comment: This is a hacky solution

Comment: @Matías: Why do you think that?

Comment: Because there're better solutions than calling prototype's functions... See other answers to get further details

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer: 'Better' in terms of what? And only because there are 'better' solutions doesn't mean this one is hacky. You are calling prototype functions all the time! `Array.prototype.push` and `[].push` are the same function.

Comment: Apply should only be used when you wish to change the `this` value for the call to the function. You are just adding an addition call on the stack for no benefit and also risk contaminating the global object if you do not check the first argument for null or undefined if you don't use strict mode.

Comment: @Blindman67: `.push` will throw an error if `this` is `null` or `undefined`. `.apply` is also the only way to pass an array as arguments to a function in ES5 and below. I agree that one shouldn't use `.apply` if they don't understand what it does, but that isn't a problem here.

Comment: @FelixKling Apply will replace the first argument with the global object (window for browsers) depending on context if not in strict mode, push never gets to see the null/undefined. Also Apply passes the second array as an array of arguments, there are limits to the number of arguments that can be passed which is way below the  array length limits. Using it for array push has a very real possibility of throwing an error or truncating the argument list. Because this is JS implementation dependent you add ambiguity to the code making it untestable. Dont use it for array concatting.

Comment: @Blindman67: As you can read in the spec, that was the case in ES3, but was changed in ES5 (which was published  a while ago). Any limitation to the number arguments seems implementation specific. It's certainly important to know. I'm just against generalized statements. IMO context is important to decide whether a solution is "good" or "bad". Anyways, we are derailing. http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-function.prototype.apply