# javascript: loop through object array and pushing elements into one array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to loop through an object array (data.list) and pull out an element (required_fields.display_value) and push them into another array and concatenate.

I've written the following:

```
c.data.required_fields = [];
            for(var i=0; i<c.data.list.length; i++) {
                c.data.required_fields.push(
                    c.data.list[i].required_fields.display_value.split(',')             
                );
            }
```

which returns this:
[image]

What do I have to add to my code above so that required_fields is a single array?  Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how can I concatenate two arrays in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36989741/how-can-i-concatenate-two-arrays-in-javascript)

Comment: Can you please add the rest of the code needed to reproduce the problem? Like some dummy data in `c.data.list`?

Comment: `c.data.require_fields = c.data.list.reduce((acc, dat) => acc.concat(dat.require_fields.display_value), []);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
c.data.required_fields = [];
for(var i=0; i<c.data.list.length; i++) {
    c.data.required_fields = c.data.required_fields.concat(
        c.data.list[i].required_fields.display_value.split(',')             
    );
}
```

This should do the trick. Since every call to .split will return an array, you need to concat the contents of that array into the required_fields array. Concat returns a branch new array, however, hence the "c.data.required_fields = c.data.required_fields.concat..." assignment.

**This is a very simple fix. You could of course do something more readable with reduce, but I believe another answer has that covered.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are pushing all of the values for each `list[i]` in one single operation. This means that you are adding all the elements of each list into a single array slot, which creates an array of arrays.

One thing you can do is to flatten the array after you are done by

`c.data.require_field.flatten();`

Another option is to individually insert each entry within the list rather than pushing them all in at once:

```
for(var i=0; i<c.data.list.length; i++) {
   var list = c.data.list[i];

   //for each element in this list, add it to a new spot in the required_fields array
   for(var j=0; j<list.length){
      c.data.required_fields.push(
          c.data.list[j].required_fields.display_value.split(',')             
      );
   }                
}
```

The first is probably much simpler and succinct, but the second example is added here for clarity on what exactly is going wrong

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to flatten your array there is a code snippet on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatten

```
var arr1 = [1, 2, [3, 4]];
arr1.flatten();

//to flatten single level array
arr1.reduce((acc, val) => acc.concat(val), []);
// [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: This has terrible performance problems, I don't know why.  An array of 10000 arrays of 2 numbers takes 300ms.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your value is split into a new array that you do not iterate over to create a 1 dimensional array. I have two suggestions. Either iterate over the split array inside the loop, or concatenate all the comma separated strings first, them do the split.

```
var dataArray = [];
var list = c.data.list;

list.forEAch(function(listItem){
  var values = listItem.required_fields.display_value.split(',');
  values.forEach(function(value){
    dataArray.push(value);
  });
}

c.data.required_fields = dataArray;
```

Or perhaps:

```
var values = "";
var list = c.data.list;

list.forEAch(function(listItem){
  if( !!values ) {
    values += ",";
  }
  values += listItem.required_fields.display_value;
}

c.data.required_fields = values.split(',');
```

Answer (score -1):

To get your code working, you could simply change it to

```
c.data.required_fields = [];
        for(var i=0; i<c.data.list.length; i++) {
            Array.prototype.push.apply(c.data.required_fields,
                c.data.list[i].required_fields.display_value.split(',')             
            );
        }
```

Like that, you call `Array`'s `push` method on `c.data.required_fields` and use the contents of `c.data.list[i].required_fields.display_value.split(',')` as individual arguments rather than an array that'll be pushed into another array.

Answer (score -1):

You can simply merge array like.

Join array entries with `,`. This will give you a single string with `,` as delimiter and then you can split them with `,` to get array

```js
var r = [["Name","a","b"], ["Age","x","y"], ["hope","g","h"]];

console.log(r.join(",").split(','))
```

Comment: Looks like the data in required_fields has the format [["Name", "a", "b"], ["Age", "x", "y"], ["hope", "g", "h"]];

Comment: That was a typo. Is that's the reason it's downvoted ? or give me another reason