# Merging two objects in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, javascript-objects

I have following two objects

First:

```
var a = [{a:1},
 {b:2},
 {c:3}
]
```

Second:

```
var b = [{a:1},
 {b:2},
 {c:3}
]
```

I am trying to merge the objects using following function which I wrote:

```
var json_concat = async (o1, o2) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            for (var key in o2) {
                o1[key] = o2[key];
            }
            resolve(o1);
        } catch (e) {
            reject(e);
        }
    });
}
```

I am not getting the concatenated object by this.
The required result is:

```
var c = [
{a:1},
{b:2},
{c:3},
{a:1},
{b:2},
{c:3}
]
```

Please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how can I concatenate two arrays in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36989741/how-can-i-concatenate-two-arrays-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to make a specific `concat` function to get that result. Using `Array.concat`, you can get the result easily.

```js
var a = [
  {a:1},
  {b:2},
  {c:3}
];

var b = [
  {a:1},
  {b:2},
  {c:3}
];

const result = a.concat(b);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: This is a common question and at your rep you should be familiar with what kinds of questions will have been asked before.