# Rewrite following piece of javascript code

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to create a function that mimics Array.prototype.push.
It takes a variable number of arguments and pushes them into a specific array.
I have managed to do this with the following code:

```
var array=[];
function append(){
    for(var i=0;i<arguments.length;i++)
        array.push(arguments[i]);
}
```

Now my question is:Can I rewrite the append function without using "for loop"?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `return [].slice.call(arguments);`

Comment: You can try `arguments.forEach(function(arg) { ... })`. Still a loop, but a little cleaner in my opinion.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript push array values into another array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4156101/javascript-push-array-values-into-another-array)

Comment: @Nicholas Robinson `arguments.forEach()` won't work since arguments is not an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `Array.prototype.push.apply`

```
function append(){
    // make arguments an array
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    // return the number of elements pushed in the array
    return Array.prototype.push.apply(array, args);
}
```

So, what's happening here with `args`? We use `Array.prototype.slice.call` with arguments, the purpose being to make `arguments` an array, because it is a special object. `Function.prototype.call` is used to call a function with a specific context (aka `this`), and then the arguments to call the function with (comma separated). Conveniently, it appears that `slice()` looks at the `length` property of the `this` context, and `arguments` has one too, and when not empty, has properties from 0 to `length -1`, which allows `slice` to copy `arguments` in a new array.

Comment: Hey thanks it worked.Would you mind explaining to me what call does?

Answer (score 2):

If you need to get arguments array, you should use Array's slice function on an arguments object, and it will convert it into a standard JavaScript array:

```
var array = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
```

Comment: this will not work, you need first convert arguments to array.

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite this without a `for` loop, but you have to use a loop of some sort (you're working with multiple items, it's a necessity).

If you have access to ES6 or Babel, I would use something like:

```
function append(...args) {
  return array.concat(args);
}
```

Without ES6, you need to work around the fact that `arguments` isn't a real array. You can still apply most of the array methods to it, by accessing them through the `Array` prototype. Converting `arguments` into an array is easy enough, then you can `concat` the two:

```
function append() {
  var args = Array.prototype.map.call(arguments, function (it) {
    return it;
  });
  return array.concat(args);
}
```

Bear in mind that neither of these will *modify* the global `array`, but will return a new array with the combined values that can be used on its own or assigned back to `array`. This is somewhat easier and more robust than trying to work with `push`, if you're willing to `array = append(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually i honestly believe that push must be redefined for the functional JS since it's returning value is the length of the resulting array and it's most of the time useless. Such as when it's needed to push a value and pass an array as a parameter to a function you cant do it inline and things get messy. Instead i would like it to return a reference to the array it's called upon or even a new array from where i can get the length information anyway. My new push proposal would be as follows;

```
Array.prototype.push = function(...args) {
                         return args.reduce(function(p,c) {
                                              p[p.length] = c;
                                              return p
                                            }, this)
                       };
```

It returns a perfect reference to the array it's called upon.