# push array key to own array

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, key

I'm struggling to work out how I can push my array keys to an array of its own which I'm eventually going to use as column headings.

The below successfully logs my keys however the push is breaking

```
    let cols = []

    data.forEach(function (obj, index) {
      if (index === 0)
      {
        console.log(Object.keys(obj));
        this.cols.push(Object.keys(obj));
    }
    });
```

I don't actually have to loop the whole data object either I only need the first index but 1 step at a time!

My end result I expect would be cols = ["ValueDate", "AccountName", "Holding"]

Any thoughts please

Thnaks GWS

Data Extract:

```
[
  {
    "ValueDate": "2017-04-26T14:16:00",
    "AccountName": "CASHAUD",
    "Holding": 318622.53
  },
  {
    "ValueDate": "2017-04-26T14:16:00",
    "AccountName": "CASHCAD",
    "Holding": 7195
  },
  {
    "ValueDate": "2017-04-26T14:16:00",
    "AccountName": "CASHEUR",
    "Holding": 5077.97
  },
  {
    "ValueDate": "2017-04-26T14:16:00",
    "AccountName": "CASHGBP",
    "Holding": 19625
  },
  {
    "ValueDate": "2017-04-26T14:16:00",
    "AccountName": "CASHJPY",
    "Holding": 16463
  },
  {
    "ValueDate": "2017-04-26T14:16:00",
    "AccountName": "CASHNZD",
    "Holding": 601.56
  },
  {
    "ValueDate": "2017-04-26T14:16:00",
    "AccountName": "CASHSGD",
    "Holding": 1000
  },
  {
    "ValueDate": "2017-04-26T14:16:00",
    "AccountName": "CASHUSD",
    "Holding": 1716906.25
  },
  {
    "ValueDate": "2017-04-27T14:16:00",
    "AccountName": "CASHAUD",
    "Holding": 318622.53
  },
  {
    "ValueDate": "2017-04-27T14:16:00",
    "AccountName": "CASHCAD",
    "Holding": 7195
  },
  {
    "ValueDate": "2017-04-27T14:16:00",
    "AccountName": "CASHEUR",
    "Holding": 5077.97
  },
  {
    "ValueDate": "2017-04-27T14:16:00",
    "AccountName": "CASHGBP",
    "Holding": 19625
  },
  {
    "ValueDate": "2017-04-27T14:16:00",
    "AccountName": "CASHJPY",
    "Holding": 16463
  },
  {
    "ValueDate": "2017-04-27T14:16:00",
    "AccountName": "CASHNZD",
    "Holding": 601.56
  },
  {
    "ValueDate": "2017-04-27T14:16:00",
    "AccountName": "CASHSGD",
    "Holding": 1000
  },
  {
    "ValueDate": "2017-04-27T14:16:00",
    "AccountName": "CASHUSD",
    "Holding": 1720781.25
  }
]
```

Comment: `Object.keys()` returns an array, so this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4156101/javascript-push-array-values-into-another-array

Comment: Wouldn't `let cols = Object.keys(data[0])` work?

Comment: Saravanas solution worked as did Anis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only need to look at the first index anyway, just use `Object.keys(data[0])`. see working example below.

```js
data = [
  {
    "ValueDate": "2017-04-26T14:16:00",
    "AccountName": "CASHAUD",
    "Holding": 318622.53
  },
  {
    "ValueDate": "2017-04-26T14:16:00",
    "AccountName": "CASHCAD",
    "Holding": 7195
  },
  {
    "ValueDate": "2017-04-26T14:16:00",
    "AccountName": "CASHEUR",
    "Holding": 5077.97
  },
  {
    "ValueDate": "2017-04-26T14:16:00",
    "AccountName": "CASHGBP",
    "Holding": 19625
  },
  {
    "ValueDate": "2017-04-26T14:16:00",
    "AccountName": "CASHJPY",
    "Holding": 16463
  },
  {
    "ValueDate": "2017-04-26T14:16:00",
    "AccountName": "CASHNZD",
    "Holding": 601.56
  },
  {
    "ValueDate": "2017-04-26T14:16:00",
    "AccountName": "CASHSGD",
    "Holding": 1000
  },
  {
    "ValueDate": "2017-04-26T14:16:00",
    "AccountName": "CASHUSD",
    "Holding": 1716906.25
  },
  {
    "ValueDate": "2017-04-27T14:16:00",
    "AccountName": "CASHAUD",
    "Holding": 318622.53
  },
  {
    "ValueDate": "2017-04-27T14:16:00",
    "AccountName": "CASHCAD",
    "Holding": 7195
  },
  {
    "ValueDate": "2017-04-27T14:16:00",
    "AccountName": "CASHEUR",
    "Holding": 5077.97
  },
  {
    "ValueDate": "2017-04-27T14:16:00",
    "AccountName": "CASHGBP",
    "Holding": 19625
  },
  {
    "ValueDate": "2017-04-27T14:16:00",
    "AccountName": "CASHJPY",
    "Holding": 16463
  },
  {
    "ValueDate": "2017-04-27T14:16:00",
    "AccountName": "CASHNZD",
    "Holding": 601.56
  },
  {
    "ValueDate": "2017-04-27T14:16:00",
    "AccountName": "CASHSGD",
    "Holding": 1000
  },
  {
    "ValueDate": "2017-04-27T14:16:00",
    "AccountName": "CASHUSD",
    "Holding": 1720781.25
  }
]

let cols = Object.keys(data[0])
console.log(cols)
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
for(var key in obj){
}

data.forEach(function (obj, index) {
  if(index == 0){
    for(var key in obj){
       console.log(key);
    }
  }  
});
```

to loop through the object and get the key values

Answer (score 0):

let cols = []

```
data.forEach(function (obj, index) {
  if (index === 0)
  {
    console.log(Object.keys(obj));
    cols.push(Object.keys(obj));
 }
});
```

console.log(cols)