# Regex pattern highlight string words inside double quotes

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to add a condition if I have  words that inside `""` DOUBLE QUOTES  `var wordsToHighlight =' "word1, word2" '` means highlight word1 word2 in the whole text

exp `var wordsToHighlight = ' "a reference, server" '`  mean highlight `a reference` `server` in the whole text

my problem here needs to highlight the text that inside double quotes in the whole text

Explication:

- The `*` its a truncation and works well
- the `?` to highlight words+ n characters
- `.split(/"([^"]+)"|\s+/).filter(Boolean)`

  It will split the string with double quotes substrings while pushing
  the substring between double quotes into the resulting array
  (String#split always pushes the captured substrings into the
  resulting array), and with 1+ whitespaces and .filter(Boolean) will
  remove empty items that may result during the split operation.

```js
var row = {
  "Abstract": "I have a reference server for reference and just a server here server test." 
};

var wordsToHighlight = ' "a reference, server" jus? fo* ';
var result = row["Abstract"];
wordsToHighlight.split(/"([^"]+)"|\s+/).filter(Boolean).forEach(function (word) {
word = word.replace(/\*/g, '\\S*').replace(/\?/g, '.').replace(/\"/g, '.');
result = result.replace(new RegExp('(\\s|^)(' + word + ')(?=\\s|$)', "gi"),'$1<span style="background-color:yellow;">$2</span>');
});
document.querySelector("#result").innerHTML = result;
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

the result that i Expected:

[image]

Comment: It seems you could write `"a reference" server jus? fo*` to make it work with the current code. Do you have any control over the contents of the `wordsToHighlight`? Or is it user-defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to parse the words to highlight in a bit more sophisticated way: split out double quoted strings and chunks of non-whitespace. The latter ones can be added to the resulting array as is, but the contents from the double quotes should be split with a comma (and any enclosing spaces).

```js
var row = {
  "Abstract": "I have a reference server for reference and just a server here server test." 
};

var wordsToHighlight = ' "a reference, server" jus? fo* ';
var result = row["Abstract"];
var wordsTH2=[], m;
var rx = /"([^"]+)"|\S+/g;
while (m=rx.exec(wordsToHighlight)) {
  if (m[1]) {
     var arr = m[1].split(/\s*,\s*/);
     for (var i=0; i<arr.length;i++) {
        wordsTH2.push(arr[i]);
     }
  } else {
    wordsTH2.push(m[0]);
  }
}
wordsTH2.forEach(function (word) {
word = word.replace(/\*/g, '\\S*').replace(/\?/g, '.').replace(/\"/g, '.');
result = result.replace(new RegExp('(\\s|^)(' + word + ')(?=\\s|$)', "gi"),'$1<span style="background-color:yellow;">$2</span>');
});
document.querySelector("#result").innerHTML = result;
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: You may use ideas on how to push an array to an array [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4156101/javascript-push-array-values-into-another-array).

Comment: thanks, my javascript birt doesn't recognize this sentence `var r of m[1].split(/\s*,\s*/)`  missing ; after for-loop initializer?

Comment: Sure, it must be `for (var r of m[1].split(/\s*,\s*/))`. But there are other ways to add the matches obtained via `m[1].split(/\s*,\s*/)`

Comment: could you change it in your solution BIRT script didn't know `for (var r of m[1].split(/\s*,\s*/))`   he dont have the  feature  `of` in his library

Comment: Use the easiest `for (var i=0; i<arr.length;i++) {`

Comment: this `rx = /"([^"]+)"|\S+/g;` its just for `" "` how can i make it for this kind  quotes  `“ ”` also

Comment: `rx = /["“]([^"”]+)["”]|\S+/g;`

Comment: why It doesn't work for me when I have input with whitespace `" a reference "` as an example

Comment: I want to add this quotes also  `' '` to my `var rx = /["“']([^"”']+)["”']|\S+/g;` but its doesn't work could you explain me why?

Comment: the problem is when I have a simple word  `reference` and `'a reference'` just the first word reference it will be highlighted https://jsfiddle.net/szj8mwxw/9/

Comment: @MokiNex That has nothing to do with quotes. Your first `reference` got matched and highlighted, so `a reference` cannot match any longer. See [this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/szj8mwxw/10/).

Comment: yes, you are right so now the problem with the matching words but and sometimes the word `reference` can be in the front of the query and I'm not allowed to change the query

Comment: @MokiNex Not a problem, just sort `wordsTH2` by length in a descending order, see [this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Lw6dq01g/).

Comment: this is my final method for highlighting n sequences words my method works well only in this condition I don't know what is the problem I still hours to figure out  the problem https://jsfiddle.net/Lw6dq01g/2/

Comment: can you explain to me how u fixed the duplicate words for highlighting?

Comment: I added a `<span style="background-color:yellow;">.*?</span>|` alternative to the final regex, you may replace `.` with `[^]` to also match across lines, it will match terms that are already highlighted and won't touch them since if it matches, Group 1 and 2 are undefined and if Group 1 and 2 match,  a term (`$2`) will get wrapped with the new span.

Comment: thnx https://jsfiddle.net/Lw6dq01g/4/ why in this case I cant highlight `a reference` when its in the front of the phrase

Comment: @MokiNex I am busy right now, but I see you posted another question. Maybe your whole approach should be changed, e.g. create a regex with search words as alternations, to process a string with a single replace.

Comment: if I put whitespace in front of the word `a reference` it will be highlighted do you know why? https://jsfiddle.net/Lw6dq01g/5/

Comment: @MokiNex I answered your other question.