# Array not being pushed as a new index, but as a new array

Tags: javascript, vue.js

My object contains the following format:

```
[
    { },
    { }
]
```

But the way my code is written, it adds it in as,

```
[
    [
        { }
    ],
    [
        { }
    ]
]
```

Not sure what's going on, here is my code:

```
var commentArray = [];

commentArray.push({
    'text': comment,
    'user': vm.user
});

reference.reference.comments.push(commentArray);
```

Something like this works:

```
reference.reference.comments.push({
    'text': comment,
    'user': vm.user
});
```

But I want to push `commentArray`?

Comment: Well `commentArray` is indeed an *array*.  It's not clear what's surprising about the result of pushing an array into another array; the whole array is added.

Comment: commentArray = {text, user}

Comment: Change it to: `reference.reference.comments.push(...commentArray)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Push array items into another array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4156101/push-array-items-into-another-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see if I can make it clear to you:

```
var commentArray = []; 
// here you are creating an empty array called commentArray 

commentArray.push({
    'text': comment,
    'user': vm.user
}); 
// Here you define an object, with 2 properties (text and user) 
// and push it to commentArray you created so 
// commentArray = [{'text': comment, 'user': vm.user}];

reference.reference.comments.push(commentArray);
/// here you push an array (commentArray) into another array (comments)
// so reference.reference.comments will be [[{'text': comment, 'user': vm.user}]];
```

I'll do a working example in a moment.

```js
var comments = [];
var commentArray = [];

commentArray.push({
    'text': 'comment',
    'user': 'someuser'
});
console.log('comments:', comments);
console.log('commentArray:', commentArray);

comments.push(commentArray);
console.log('comments:', comments);
console.log('commentArray:', commentArray);
```

So you shouldn't create an intermediary array. You should create only the object. Like this:

```
var comment = {
    'text': comment,
    'user': vm.user
};

reference.reference.comments.push(comment);
```

or more directly like this:

```
reference.reference.comments.push({
    'text': comment,
    'user': vm.user
});
```

Comment: Thank you, this explained it well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you want to push a single comment into your comments array, not an array into an array.

```
var comment = {
    'text': comment,
    'user': vm.user
};

reference.reference.comments.push(comment);
```