# css continue grid flow across multiple parent divs

Tags: html, css

I'm wondering if there is any way to maintain the grid layout over multiple parent divs

For example, if I have 1 parent div (red) with a 3 column layout of child divs (blue). If the 2nd row in the first parent div only has 1 child div, Could I somehow break out from the following parent div with more child elements so it continues the grid flow.

I've attached an image of the current layout:

[image]

And this would be the proposed layout where the child divs break out of the parent div

[image]

Comment: share the code you are using. This can be possible based on your case. There is no generic solution

Answer (score -1):

If you dont use any Framework or Libary its a bit tricky you have to work with javascript and make some if-else statements. I think a solution for your problem can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4156101/copy-array-items-into-another-array#:~:text=push()%20can%20take%20multiple,than%20creating%20a%20new%20array.).