# How to bind childArray within ParentArray(nested) in mat-table

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-ui, mat-table

Let suppose i have **elements** array containing 2 items.

```
var elements = [{ _id: 1, name: 'Paul Walker' },
    { _id: 2, name: 'Lisa' }];
```

Then i have **arrayelements** array containing **elements** array

```
var arrayelements = [];
    arrayelements.push(elements);
```

i know i can bind **elements** array directly to datasource but how can i bind the **arrayelemnts** array to datasource of mat-table to show the content of **elements** array.

```
this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(arrayelements);
```

I tried this [STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6vs4cw-cz6rqc?file=app%2Ftable-sorting-example.ts) but unable to get all items in **elements** array

Comment: On your example, you push `elements` to `arrayelements`, so finally you got only one element on your `arrayelements`. So what do you want to show on your table ? Because you will iterate over an array with only one element, which is an array.

Comment: @LeBavarois . Got it working, thank you. unable to mark it as answer due to low reputation . sorry mate!

Answer (score 0):

@Alexis is right, you are pushing an array to an array.
You could try to concat the arrays instead, for more information look for example here:
[Copy array items into another array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4156101/copy-array-items-into-another-array)

Your code would then look like this:
Relevant part Component

```
ngOnInit() {
  var elements = [{ _id: 1, name: 'Paul Walker' },
    { _id: 2, name: 'Lisa' }];
  var arrayelements = [];
  arrayelements = arrayelements.concat(elements);
  this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(arrayelements);
  this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
}
```

Template

```
  <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort class="mat-elevation-z8" >

  <!-- Position Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="_id">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> No. </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element._id}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Name Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Name </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```