# Using the spread operator on an array of filters to create a Firestore query

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working on a filter component for my React web app and want to return (pass through props) an array of conditions for the Firestore query.

For example if the user wants to filter out posts with no comments, they check a checkbox and a `where("commentsCount", ">", "0")` is added to the array of filters.

```
  const queryParams = [
    collection(db, "posts"),
    orderBy(sortType, sortMethod),
    limit(POSTS_PER_PAGE),
  ];
  const filters = [
    where("commentsCount", ">", "0"),
    // And possibly more where's
  ];
  queryParams.push(...filters);
  
  // Create a firestore query object using the parameters
  const _query = query(...queryParams);
```

But doing this gives me a TypeScript error: `A spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter.  TS2556`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4156101/copy-array-items-into-another-array you want a new array that concatenates `queryParams` and `filters` rather than just pushing it.

Comment: @iunfixit concatenating queryParams and filters isn't the problem. My problem is the TypeScript error I get when I try to use the spread operator inside the query constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot pass an argument of type `(CollectionReference<DocumentData> | QueryConstraint)[]` in `query`. Try adding `collection()` directly in `query` and removing it from `queryParams` so it'll be an array of type `QueryContraint[]`:

```js
const queryParams = [
  orderBy(sortType, sortMethod),
  limit(POSTS_PER_PAGE),
];

const filters = [
  where("commentsCount", ">", "0"),
  // And possibly more where's
];
  
// Create a firestore query object using the parameters
const _query = query(collection(db, "posts"), ...queryParams);
```

Comment: My method of concating the array does not seem to be the problem. If I use your solution I get the exact same error as my original post.

Comment: @Vid can you restart the typescript server and try? Also can you share a screenshot of the error?

Comment: Here's a screenshot of the error https://i.imgur.com/Ct2SXOd.png

Comment: @Vid now I'm curios where is `query` defined. Can you share that complete file so we can see the import?

Comment: query is imported from "firebase/firestore" like so `import {query} from "firebase/firestore";`

Comment: your updated answer works. Thank you for your help. I marked your answer as the solution.