# how to trace the for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

```js
function zeroArray(m, n) {
  // Creates a 2-D array with m rows and n columns of zeroes
  let newArray = [];
  let row = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < m; i++) {
    // Adds the m-th row into newArray

    for (let j = 0; j < n; j++) {
      // Pushes n zeroes into the current row to create the columns
      row.push(0);
    }
    // Pushes the current row, which now has n zeroes in it, to the array
    newArray.push(row);
  }
  return newArray;
}

let matrix = zeroArray(3, 2);
console.log(JSON.stringify(matrix));
```

this code should print this

```
[[0,0], [0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0,0,0]]
```

but instead its printing this

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

can someone trace the code?

Comment: What do you mean "trace the code"?

Comment: Write to the [console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console) what you need to see in the loop to understand what the loop is doing.

Comment: What you're probably looking for is something akin to `for (let j = 0; j < i; j++)` in your second loop.  Notice the condition is checking against i instead of n?

Comment: You are using only 1 row array because you do `let row = [];` only once. That single row array is pushed multiple times into to `newArray` variable. At the same time you also push new `0`s into that single row array. The single row array has 6 `0`s at the end, and newArray contains that single row array 3 times so it prints 3 times the 6 `0`s.

Comment: any browser have a step by step debugger (**F12**)

Comment: When you `push` `row`, you are not pushing the *contents* of the row array, you are pushing a *reference* to the row array. As the row array changes through the loops, the values in the reference are updating. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374126/how-to-extend-an-existing-javascript-array-with-another-array-without-creating/17368101#17368101 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4156101/copy-array-items-into-another-array

Answer (score 0):

I think this is about variable scope.you should declare row in for loop

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

When you push row, you are not pushing the contents of the row array, you are pushing a reference to the row array. As the row array changes through the loops, the values in the reference are updating.

If you `slice()` the row array when you `push` it into the new array, you will copy the values of the array, instead of a reference to it:

```
function zeroArray(m, n) {
  // Creates a 2-D array with m rows and n columns of zeroes
  let newArray = [];
  let row = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < m; i++) {
    // Adds the m-th row into newArray

    for (let j = 0; j < n; j++) {
      // Pushes n zeroes into the current row to create the columns
      row.push(0);
    }
    // Pushes the current row, which now has n zeroes in it, to the array
    newArray.push(row.slice());
  }
  return newArray;
}

let matrix = zeroArray(3, 2);
console.log(matrix);
```

output:

```
[[0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

See:

[Copy array by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486085/copy-array-by-value)