# keeping elements in array when adding new elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

Can't keep data in the array when adding new. This code is in a loop btw

```
let placeHolder = facArray[key].filter(i => i.M == map).map(i => i.W)
    mapArray[map] = [...placeHolder]
```

I am trying to store data in an array with the value of map as an index and I would like to push data to it this is in a loop btw but it keeps removing the previous data how do I keep the previous data while adding to it

Comment: Your question consists of one run-on sentence which is confusing. Can you try to clarify your question?

Comment: I do not understand what you are trying to do or, more importantly, why you are using this intermediary placeholder array. You say "push" data, do you know about https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push ?

Comment: try using `Array.concat()` method instead of `mapArray[map] = [...placeHolder]` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4156101/copy-array-items-into-another-array

Answer (score 0):

You need to put a reference to the non-primitive instance of Array, to use as a Map key. For reference :

```
    var mapArray = new Map();
    ...
    ...
    let placeHolder = facArray[key].filter(i => i.M == map).map(i => i.W)
    mapArray.set(map,[...placeHolder]);
    ...
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to make sure there was actually something in the array before i could use the spread operater to get all the old data

```
if(mapArray[map] === undefined){
    mapArray[map] = [...placeHolder]
}else{
    mapArray[map] = [...placeHolder, ...mapArray[map]]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it with a simple `Array.push()`:

```js
const mapArray={abc:[1,3,5,7]}, map="abc", 
  placeHolder=[2,4,6,8];

(mapArray[map]??=[]).push(...placeHolder);

console.log(mapArray[map]);
```

The expression `(mapArray[map]??=[])` will initialise an Array in `mapArray` in case it did not exist before.