# Adding two json objects and sorting

Tags: javascript, json

I have got three similar json objects. Now i wish to join the entire list and then sort the complete list according to one of the index. Here, goes the objects description

**Object 1**

```
[{"link":"#","prod":"Fundamentals Of Software Engineering","price":" Rs. 200 "},{"link":"##","prod":"Real-Time Systems: Theory And Practice","price":" Rs. 394 "}]
```

**Object 2**

```
[{"link":"#","prod":"Fundamentals Of Software Engineering","price":" Rs. 200 "},{"link":"##","prod":"Real-Time Systems: Theory And Practice","price":" Rs. 394 "}]
```

**Object 3**

```
[{"link":"#","prod":"Fundamentals Of Software Engineering","price":" Rs. 200 "},{"link":"##","prod":"Real-Time Systems: Theory And Practice","price":" Rs. 394 "}]
```

Once, I join all of them , I wish to sort the complete array (new one) w.r.t to price index.

Any hint for this will be appreciated.
thanks :)

Comment: The three objects will not be having same data

Comment: Where are you stuck? [How to parse JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/how-to-parse-json-in-javascript), [how to concatenate arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080028/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-concatenate-n-arrays-in-javascript), [how to sort an array of objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sorting-objects-in-an-array-by-a-field-value-in-javascript/1129270#1129270) or something else?

Comment: I am not able to concate them

Comment: Then follow the link in my comment. FYI, if you have already parsed the JSON into JavaScript objects/arrays, then your question is not related to JSON anymore.

Comment: What is more preferrable, to concat JSON object or to javascript object ?

Comment: I'd say working with the objects/arrays in JavaScript is easier and less error-prone than string processing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if Object1 , Object2 and Object3 are JSON strings convert it to Javascript objects using `eval` function.

Then merge them using `concat` method.
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_concat_array.asp

```
var mergedArray = arr1.concat(arr2, arr3);
```

Then sort using `sort` method in Javascript Array.
ref : http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp
ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

```
var sorted = mergedArray.sort(function(a, b){

    // This function is used by sort method for sorting process
    // This function gets called with parameters a,b which are the elements in array (here product objects from your JSON)
    // if this function returns value < 0 a is placed before b
    // if this function returns 0 nothing is changed
    // if this function returns value > 0 b is placed before a
    // a.price.replace("Rs.", "") removes Rs. from price string. so "Rs. 200" becomes 200
    // parseFloat(a.price.replace("Rs.", "")) makes it number.  "200" becomes 200. "200.50" becomes 200.5
    // priceA - priceB returns -ve value if priceA < priceB, 0 if priceA = priceB, +ve value if priceA > priceB.

    var priceA = parseFloat(a.price.replace("Rs.", ""));
    var priceB = parseFloat(b.price.replace("Rs.", ""));
    return priceA - priceB;



});
```

Use `return priceB - priceA;` for descending order. 
jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/diode/FzzHz/

.

Comment: can you please explain the last part? After merging array, I am not getting how this code sorts them. Please explain a bit

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got everything :D

Answer (score 1):

Convert them to object and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1129270/475726) should do the trick

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) method to concatenate the arrays:

```
var result = arr1.concat(arr2, arr3);
```

and then you could sort the resulting array.

Let's write the sort function that will sort them using the `prod` property (you could sort them by any property you wish):

```
function SortByProd(a, b) {
    var aProd = a.prod.toLowerCase();
    var bProd = b.prod.toLowerCase(); 
    return ((aProd < bProd) ? -1 : ((aProd > bProd) ? 1 : 0));
}
```

and then sort:

```
result.sort(SortByProd);
```