# add two json objects

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Adding two json objects and sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8869123/adding-two-json-objects-and-sorting)

Iam having two json objects

```
[
{"name": "Graduation"},
{"name": "Post Graduation"}
]
```

and another one is also same

```
[
{"name": "first sem"},
{"name": "second sem"},
{"name": "third sem"}
]
```

how can i add two json objects into one,like

```
[
{"name": "Graduation"},
{"name": "Post Graduation"},
{"name": "first sem"},
{"name": "second sem"},
{"name": "third sem"}
]
```

I tried

```
_this.model = new qualification();
_this.model1 = new sems();
 jsondata = _this.model.toJSON();
 jsonData = _.extend(_this.model1.toJSON(),jsonData)
```

getting json by overriding keys

```
even I tried
var result = _.union([jsonData1],[jsonData2]);
console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

and with concat also it prints output as

```
[{"0":{"name":"first sem"},"1":{"name":"second sem"},"2":{"name":"third sem"}},{"0":{"name":"Graduation"},"1":{"name":"Post Graduation"}}],
```

Answer (score 1):

Well if you are talking of objects then _.extend is perfect but these are arrays. Hence you shall do below

[_.union(*array);](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#union)

#### Code

```
var A = [
    {
    "name": "Graduation"},
{
    "name": "Post Graduation"}
];

var B = [
    {
    "name": "first sem"},
{
    "name": "second sem"},
{
    "name": "third sem"}
];

console.log(_.union(A,B)​);​​​​
```

#### JsFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/7FkWs/

Answer (score 0):

By "JSON objects" I'm assuming you mean just JavaScript objects, in this case, arrays.  You can append them together using the [`Array#concat()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat):

```javascript
var a1 = [{"name":"Graduation"}, {"name":"Post Graduation"}];
var a2 = [{"name":"first sem"}, {"name":"second sem"}, {"name":"third sem"}];
var a3 = a1.concat(a2);
a3; // [{"name":"Graduation"}, {"name":"Post Graduation"}, {"name":"first sem"}, {"name":"second sem"}, {"name":"third sem"}];
```

Note that if these objects are indeed serialized JSON strings then you can do the following:

```javascript
var a4 = JSON.parse(a1).concat(JSON.parse(a2));
a4; // [{"name":"Graduation"}, {"name":"Post Graduation"}, {"name":"first sem"}, {"name":"second sem"}, {"name":"third sem"}];
```