# Merge/flatten an array of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, merge, flatten

I have a JavaScript array like:

```
[["$6"], ["$12"], ["$25"], ["$25"], ["$18"], ["$22"], ["$10"]]
```

How would I go about merging the separate inner arrays into one like:

```
["$6", "$12", "$25", ...]
```

Comment: All of the solutions that use `reduce` + `concat` are O((N^2)/2) where as a accepted answer (just one call to `concat`) would be at most O(N*2) on a bad browser and O(N) on a good one. Also Denys solution is optimized for the actual question and upto 2x faster than the single `concat`. For the `reduce` folks it's fun to feel cool writing tiny code but for example if the array had 1000 one element subarrays all the reduce+concat solutions would be doing [500500 operations](https://jsperf.com/concat-vs-reduce-concat-vs-loop) where as the single concat or simple loop would do 1000 operations.

Comment: With the latest browsers that support [ES2019](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat): `array.flat(Infinity)` where `Infinity` is the maximum depth to flatten.

Comment: I'm glad they put a maximum depth.. :D

Comment: Flatmap works like  champ, try this.   var d = [[1], [2], [3], [4,5,6]].flatMap(x => x);

Answer (score 2571, accepted):

---

#### ES2019

ES2019 introduced the [`Array.prototype.flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) method which you could use to flatten the arrays. It is compatible with [most environments](https://caniuse.com/array-flat), although it is only available in Node.js starting with version 11, and not at all in Internet Explorer.

```js
const arrays = [
      ["$6"],
      ["$12"],
      ["$25"],
      ["$25"],
      ["$18"],
      ["$22"],
      ["$10"]
    ];
const merge3 = arrays.flat(1); //The depth level specifying how deep a nested array structure should be flattened. Defaults to 1.
console.log(merge3);
```

---

#### Older browsers

For older browsers, you can use [`Array.prototype.concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) to merge arrays:

```js
var arrays = [
  ["$6"],
  ["$12"],
  ["$25"],
  ["$25"],
  ["$18"],
  ["$22"],
  ["$10"]
];
var merged = [].concat.apply([], arrays);

console.log(merged);
```

Using the `apply` method of `concat` will just take the second parameter as an array, so the last line is identical to this:

```
var merged = [].concat(["$6"], ["$12"], ["$25"], ["$25"], ["$18"], ["$22"], ["$10"]);
```

Comment: Or `Array.prototype.concat.apply([], arrays)`.

Comment: Note: this answer only flattens one level deep. For a recursive flatten, see the answer by @Trindaz.

Comment: Further to @Sean's comment: ES6 syntax makes this super concise: `var merged = [].concat(...arrays)`

Comment: Building on @Sethi's comment: `Array.prototype.concat(...arrays)`. This version works with Typescript's 2.3.0 `--strict` mode. Doesn't work with nested arrays (it's not recursive).

Comment: 'apply' will stack overflow on large inputs for some vms, like v8. It's really not meant for this use case.

Comment: as @Sethi mentioned, for ES6:
`[].concat(...arrays)`
 also works in Typescript

Comment: Array.prototype.flat is now official! And [supported in Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)!

Comment: @Gumbo your solution will result 4,9, 5, , , 6, 4,5,5,7, 65, 56 for [[[4,9],5,null,[],6,[4,[5,5],7],65],56] whereas it should return may be 4,9, 5, null, 6, 4,5,5,7, 65, 56 or may be 4,9, 5, 6, 4,5,5,7, 65, 56

Comment: On advantage over flat(): as of Nov 23, 2019, this works in Edge, while the prettier flat() does not.

Comment: Can we use this method for any depth of arrays? It seems that this code runs only for 1-level nested array.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why in `var merged = [].concat.apply([], arrays);`, thisArg is set to an empty array?

Comment: Also worth checking that if you have more than one (flat) arrays. `[].concat(arrayA, arrayB)`

Comment: If I use any of the various suggestions that start with `[].` I get an error back saying "Argument of type 'number[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ConcatArray<never>'. (I'm merging a 2-dimensional array of numbers.) The error resolves and I get the expected output if I change this to `new Array().concat(...arrays)`

Comment: `[].concat(...arrays).length` this helped me do a count / empty check without changing original array. Thanks!

Answer (score 614):

Here's a short function that uses some of the newer JavaScript array methods to flatten an n-dimensional array.

```
function flatten(arr) {
  return arr.reduce(function (flat, toFlatten) {
    return flat.concat(Array.isArray(toFlatten) ? flatten(toFlatten) : toFlatten);
  }, []);
}
```

Usage:

```
flatten([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5]]); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
flatten([[[1, [1.1]], 2, 3], [4, 5]]); // [1, 1.1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: What's the memory usage profile for this solution? Looks like it creates a lot of intermediate arrays during the tail recursion....

Comment: Why is there an empty array passed as an argument?  The code breaks without it, but what does it do?

Comment: @ayjay, it's the starting accumulator value for the reduce function, what [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) calls the initial value.  In this case it's the value of `flat` in the first call to the anonymous function passed to `reduce`.  If it is not specified, then the first call to `reduce` binds the first value out of the array to `flat`, which would eventually result in `1` being bound to `flat` in both the examples.  `1.concat` is not a function.

Comment: It is a nice solution and in most cases I would happily use it, but performance might not be the best:
If you have for an array structure that has at the deepest child level a lot of values, it will still go through those even though it doesn't change them, so e.g. in the questions example it will go through all the arrays, not just the parent array. Even though it doesn't need to flatten anything else except the first tier. I had (naturally) performance issues with array structure of 10000+ arrays inside 2 parent arrays.

Comment: Or in a shorter, sexier form:

`const flatten = (arr) =>  arr.reduce((flat, next) => flat.concat(next), []);`

Comment: Riffing on @TsvetomirTsonev and Noah's solutions for arbitrary nesting: `const flatten = (arr) => arr.reduce((flat, next) => flat.concat(Array.isArray(next) ? flatten(next) : next), []);`

Comment: Bad memory profile, too many intermediate arrays, this answer will be rejected in most first-tier company interviews.

Comment: @GeorgeKatsanos We don't know that - yes, `concat` is supposed to create a new array, but the runtimes can optimize just like hey already do e.g. for lots of kinds of string operations. If they detect the array is immediately discarded, and they can even limit the detection to the `reduce` function specifically, they can reuse the same array internally. Fort your interviews, I would say anybody who thinks that the observable behavior of JS code always  is exactly the same as what the runtime does internally should maybe not be rejected but definitely educated - this stuff may change any time.

Comment: I like the idea here but this will break if any of the original array values are not arrays

Comment: I know that this is a super old answer, but I think it's great - so thank you for that Noah. However I have some trouble understanding what line number 3 does. As I understand it, it concats something to the accumulator but what exactly, the ternary operator kind of breaks my mind. I would really appreciate you giving me a hand! ^^

Answer (score 359):

There is a confusingly hidden method, which constructs a new array without mutating the original one:

```js
var oldArray = [[1],[2,3],[4]];
var newArray = Array.prototype.concat.apply([], oldArray);
console.log(newArray); // [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
```

Comment: I'm not really convinced that this is "performant" as I seem to have hit a stack overflow with this sort of call (on an array with 200K entries which are lines in a file).

Comment: If you can use ES2015 you might also write it easier for the eye with array spreads: `[].concat(...[ [1],[2,3],[4] ])`.

Comment: did not work with  array [2, [3, [4, [5, [6, [7, [8]]]]]]]

Comment: Very clever approach, I like it! Extremely useful if you have to flatten an array inside of an array, since using apply would presume you are passing in an array of parameters. Only bummer is if you have arrays inside your array that are more than two levels deep.

Comment: I like this approach... here for n-dimensional arrays: `flat = (e) => Array.isArray(e)? [].concat.apply([], e.map(flat)) : e`

Answer (score 246):

It can be best done by javascript reduce function.

```
var arrays = [["$6"], ["$12"], ["$25"], ["$25"], ["$18"], ["$22"], ["$10"], ["$0"], ["$15"],["$3"], ["$75"], ["$5"], ["$100"], ["$7"], ["$3"], ["$75"], ["$5"]];

arrays = arrays.reduce(function(a, b){
     return a.concat(b);
}, []);
```

Or, with ES2015:

```
arrays = arrays.reduce((a, b) => a.concat(b), []);
```

[js-fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zAzaH/)

[Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?v=control)

Comment: Since you use ES6, you could also use [the spread-operator as array literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator).
`arrays.reduce((flatten, arr) => [...flatten, ...arr])`

Answer (score 212):

There's a new native method called [flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) to do this exactly.

*(As of late 2019, `flat` is now published in the ECMA 2019 standard, and `core-js@3` (babel's library)  includes it in their polyfill [library](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js/blob/master/docs/2019-03-19-core-js-3-babel-and-a-look-into-the-future.md#what-changed-in-core-js3))*

```
const arr1 = [1, 2, [3, 4]];
arr1.flat(); 
// [1, 2, 3, 4]

const arr2 = [1, 2, [3, 4, [5, 6]]];
arr2.flat();
// [1, 2, 3, 4, [5, 6]]

// Flatten 2 levels deep
const arr3 = [2, 2, 5, [5, [5, [6]], 7]];
arr3.flat(2);
// [2, 2, 5, 5, 5, [6], 7];

// Flatten all levels
const arr4 = [2, 2, 5, [5, [5, [6]], 7]];
arr4.flat(Infinity);
// [2, 2, 5, 5, 5, 6, 7];
```

Comment: It's a shame this isn't even on the first page of answers. This feature is available in Chrome 69 and Firefox 62 (and Node 11 for those working in the backend)

Comment: And there’s https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap

Comment: -1; nope, this isn't part of [ECMAScript 2018](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/). It's still just a proposal that hasn't made it to any ECMAScript spec.

Comment: I think now we can consider this .. because now it's part of standard (2019) .. can we revisit the performance part of this once ?

Comment: Seems it's not yet supported by any Microsoft browser though (at least at the time I write this comment)

Comment: As of Nov 23, 2019, flat() works in chrome but not in edge.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat

Comment: Today, [non-Chromium Edge is the only major browser that doesn't support `flat()`](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-javascript_builtins_array_flat). But that's not a big deal, Chromium Edge is already available so you can tell your users to upgrade to it, and if nothing else [the next Windows 10 update will include Chromium Edge by default](https://gadgets.ndtv.com/apps/news/microsoft-edge-chromium-browser-added-by-default-next-windows-10-20h2-update-2247538).

Comment: Fwiw, [here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53072385/array-prototype-flat-is-undefined-in-nodejs/63995108#63995108) an unoptimized `flat` polyfill outside of babel. And then `flatMap` polyfill can be `return Array.isArray(array) ? array.map(callback).flat() : array;`. If you [need `map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Browser_compatibility) as well, [MDN has a `map` poly](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Polyfill). Or just transpile your code like most folk in 2020. ;^D

Answer (score 89):

Most of the answers here don't work on huge (e.g. 200 000 elements) arrays, and even if they do, they're slow.

Here is **the fastest solution, which works also on arrays with multiple levels of nesting**:

```
const flatten = function(arr, result = []) {
  for (let i = 0, length = arr.length; i < length; i++) {
    const value = arr[i];
    if (Array.isArray(value)) {
      flatten(value, result);
    } else {
      result.push(value);
    }
  }
  return result;
};
```

### Examples

#### Huge arrays

```
flatten(Array(200000).fill([1]));
```

It handles huge arrays just fine. On my machine this code takes about 14 ms to execute.

#### Nested arrays

```
flatten(Array(2).fill(Array(2).fill(Array(2).fill([1]))));
```

It works with nested arrays. This code produces `[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]`.

#### Arrays with different levels of nesting

```
flatten([1, [1], [[1]]]);
```

It doesn't have any problems with flattening arrays like this one.

Comment: Except your huge array is pretty flat. This solution won't work for deeply nested arrays. No recursive solution will. In fact no browser but Safari has TCO right now, so no recursive algorithm will perform well.

Comment: @nitely But in what real-world situation would you have arrays with more than a few levels of nesting?

Comment: Usually, when the array is generated out of user generated content.

Comment: @0xcaff In Chrome it doesn't work at all with a 200 000-element array (you get `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`). For 20 000-element array it takes 2-5 milliseconds.

Comment: what's the O notation complexity of this?

Comment: @MichałPerłakowski 
i just tested this https://stackoverflow.com/a/49895394/4948383
with huge array and it works.

Comment: @MichałPerłakowski `But in what real-world situation would you have arrays with more than a few levels of nesting?` -> When you design grammars, their parsers/lexers can generate deeply nested arrays easily.

Comment: You linked an answer which works for 1 level arrays: "polkovnikov.ph's answer". I don't see a user with this name and the link just takes me up to the question. Was it deleted?

Comment: @HumanZeroHumanZero Yes.

Answer (score 66):

**Update: it turned out that this solution doesn't work with large arrays. It you're looking for a better, faster solution, check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39000004/3853934).**

---

```
function flatten(arr) {
  return [].concat(...arr)
}
```

Is simply expands `arr` and passes it as arguments to `concat()`, which merges all the arrays into one. It's equivalent to `[].concat.apply([], arr)`.

You can also try this for deep flattening:

```
function deepFlatten(arr) {
  return flatten(           // return shalowly flattened array
    arr.map(x=>             // with each x in array
      Array.isArray(x)      // is x an array?
        ? deepFlatten(x)    // if yes, return deeply flattened x
        : x                 // if no, return just x
    )
  )
}
```

See demo on [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/pimici/2/edit?js,console).

References for ECMAScript 6 elements used in this answer:

- [Spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)
- [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

---

Side note: methods like `find()` and arrow functions are not supported by all browsers, but it doesn't mean that you can't use these features right now. Just use [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) — it transforms ES6 code into ES5.

Comment: Because almost all the replies here misuse `apply` in this way, I removed my comments from yours. I still think using `apply`/spread this way is bad advise, but since no one cares...

Comment: @LUH3417 It's not like that, I really appreciate your comments. It turned out you're right -- this solution indeed doesn't work with large arrays. I posted [another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39000004/3853934) which works fine even with arrays of 200 000 elements.

Comment: If you are using ES6, you can reducer further to: `const flatten = arr => [].concat(...arr)`

Comment: What do you mean "does not work with large arrays"? How large? What happens?

Comment: @GEMI For example trying to flatten a 500000-element array using this method gives "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded".

Answer (score 55):

You can use [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/):

```
var x = [[1], [2], [3, 4]];

_.flatten(x); // => [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: 1+ - You can also specify that you want a shallow flattened array [by specifying `true` for the second argument](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865025/merge-flatten-an-array-of-arrays-in-javascript/28015986#28015986).

Answer (score 45):

Generic procedures mean we don't have to rewrite complexity each time we need to utilize a specific behaviour.

`concatMap` (or `flatMap`) is exactly what we need in this situation.

```js
// concat :: ([a],[a]) -> [a]
const concat = (xs,ys) =>
  xs.concat (ys)

// concatMap :: (a -> [b]) -> [a] -> [b]
const concatMap = f => xs =>
  xs.map(f).reduce(concat, [])

// id :: a -> a
const id = x =>
  x

// flatten :: [[a]] -> [a]
const flatten =
  concatMap (id)

// your sample data
const data =
  [["$6"], ["$12"], ["$25"], ["$25"], ["$18"], ["$22"], ["$10"]]

console.log (flatten (data))
```

#### foresight

And yes, you guessed it correctly, it only flattens **one** level, which is exactly how it *should* work

Imagine some data set like this

```js
// Player :: (String, Number) -> Player
const Player = (name,number) =>
  [ name, number ]

// team :: ( . Player) -> Team
const Team = (...players) =>
  players

// Game :: (Team, Team) -> Game
const Game = (teamA, teamB) =>
  [ teamA, teamB ]

// sample data
const teamA =
  Team (Player ('bob', 5), Player ('alice', 6))

const teamB =
  Team (Player ('ricky', 4), Player ('julian', 2))

const game =
  Game (teamA, teamB)

console.log (game)
// [ [ [ 'bob', 5 ], [ 'alice', 6 ] ],
//   [ [ 'ricky', 4 ], [ 'julian', 2 ] ] ]
```

Ok, now say we want to print a roster that shows all the players that will be participating in `game` …

```
const gamePlayers = game =>
  flatten (game)

gamePlayers (game)
// => [ [ 'bob', 5 ], [ 'alice', 6 ], [ 'ricky', 4 ], [ 'julian', 2 ] ]
```

If our `flatten` procedure flattened nested arrays too, we'd end up with this garbage result …

```
const gamePlayers = game =>
  badGenericFlatten(game)

gamePlayers (game)
// => [ 'bob', 5, 'alice', 6, 'ricky', 4, 'julian', 2 ]
```

---

#### rollin' deep, baby

That's not to say sometimes you don't want to flatten nested arrays, too – only that shouldn't be the default behaviour.

We can make a `deepFlatten` procedure with ease …

```js
// concat :: ([a],[a]) -> [a]
const concat = (xs,ys) =>
  xs.concat (ys)

// concatMap :: (a -> [b]) -> [a] -> [b]
const concatMap = f => xs =>
  xs.map(f).reduce(concat, [])

// id :: a -> a
const id = x =>
  x

// flatten :: [[a]] -> [a]
const flatten =
  concatMap (id)

// deepFlatten :: [[a]] -> [a]
const deepFlatten =
  concatMap (x =>
    Array.isArray (x) ? deepFlatten (x) : x)

// your sample data
const data =
  [0, [1, [2, [3, [4, 5], 6]]], [7, [8]], 9]

console.log (flatten (data))
// [ 0, 1, [ 2, [ 3, [ 4, 5 ], 6 ] ], 7, [ 8 ], 9 ]

console.log (deepFlatten (data))
// [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ]
```

There. Now you have a tool for each job – one for squashing one level of nesting, `flatten`, and one for obliterating all nesting `deepFlatten`.

Maybe you can call it `obliterate` or `nuke` if you don't like the name `deepFlatten`.

---

**Don't iterate twice !**

Of course the above implementations are clever and concise, but using a `.map` followed by a call to `.reduce` means we're actually doing more iterations than necessary

Using a trusty combinator I'm calling `mapReduce` helps keep the iterations to a minium; it takes a mapping function `m :: a -> b`, a reducing function `r :: (b,a) ->b` and returns a new reducing function - this combinator is at the heart of *transducers*; if you're interested, [I've written other answers about them](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A633183+transducer)

```js
// mapReduce = (a -> b, (b,a) -> b, (b,a) -> b)
const mapReduce = (m,r) =>
  (acc,x) => r (acc, m (x))

// concatMap :: (a -> [b]) -> [a] -> [b]
const concatMap = f => xs =>
  xs.reduce (mapReduce (f, concat), [])

// concat :: ([a],[a]) -> [a]
const concat = (xs,ys) =>
  xs.concat (ys)

// id :: a -> a
const id = x =>
  x

// flatten :: [[a]] -> [a]
const flatten =
  concatMap (id)
  
// deepFlatten :: [[a]] -> [a]
const deepFlatten =
  concatMap (x =>
    Array.isArray (x) ? deepFlatten (x) : x)

// your sample data
const data =
  [ [ [ 1, 2 ],
      [ 3, 4 ] ],
    [ [ 5, 6 ],
      [ 7, 8 ] ] ]

console.log (flatten (data))
// [ [ 1. 2 ], [ 3, 4 ], [ 5, 6 ], [ 7, 8 ] ]

console.log (deepFlatten (data))
// [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 ]
```

Comment: Frequently, when I see your replies I want to withdraw mine, because they have become worthless. Great answer! `concat` itself doesn't blow up the stack, only `...` and `apply` does (along with very large arrays). I didn't see it. I just feel terrible right now.

Comment: Please note that `concat` in Javascript has a different meaning than in Haskell. Haskell's `concat` (`[[a]] -> [a]`) would be called `flatten` in Javascript and is implemented as `foldr (++) []` (Javascript: `foldr(concat) ([])` assuming curried functions). Javascript's `concat` is a weird append (`(++)` in Haskell), which can handle both `[a] -> [a] -> [a]` and `a -> [a] -> [a]`.

Comment: I guess a better name were `flatMap`, because that is exactly what `concatMap` is: The `bind` instance of the `list` monad. `concatpMap` is implemented as `foldr ((++) . f) []`. Translated into Javascript: `const flatMap = f => foldr(comp(concat) (f)) ([])`. This is of course similar to your implementation without `comp`.

Comment: what's the complexity of that algorithm?

Answer (score 40):

To flatten an array of single element arrays, you don't need to import a library, a simple loop is both the simplest and [most efficient](http://jsperf.com/flatten-constant-depht-array) solution :

```
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  a[i] = a[i][0];
}
```

To downvoters: please read the question, don't downvote because it doesn't suit your very different problem. This solution is both the fastest and simplest for the asked question.

Comment: It doesn't really matter how cryptic it is. This code "flattens" this `['foo', ['bar']]` to `['f', 'bar']`.

Comment: Well. Of course. It's an answer to the question. What's not clear in *an array of arrays* ? This answer doesn't try to answer a more general question which woukd be less efficient...

Comment: indeed, you're correct. I was focused too much on the other examples - not explicitly on the wording.

Answer (score 34):

A solution for the more general case, when you may have some non-array elements in your array.

```
function flattenArrayOfArrays(a, r){
    if(!r){ r = []}
    for(var i=0; i<a.length; i++){
        if(a[i].constructor == Array){
            flattenArrayOfArrays(a[i], r);
        }else{
            r.push(a[i]);
        }
    }
    return r;
}
```

Comment: This approach was very effective in flattening the nested array form of result-sets you get from a [JsonPath query](https://code.google.com/p/jsonpath/wiki/Javascript).

Comment: This will break if we manually pass in the second argument. For example, try this: `flattenArrayOfArrays (arr, 10)` or this `flattenArrayOfArrays(arr, [1,[3]]);` - those second arguments are added to the output.

Answer (score 34):

You can also try the new [`Array.flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) method. It works in the following manner:

```js
let arr = [["$6"], ["$12"], ["$25"], ["$25"], ["$18"], ["$22"], ["$10"]].flat()

console.log(arr);
```

The `flat()` method creates a new array with all sub-array elements concatenated into it recursively up to the 1 layer of depth (i.e. arrays inside arrays)

If you want to also flatten out 3 dimensional or even higher dimensional arrays you simply call the flat method multiple times. For example (3 dimensions):

```js
let arr = [1,2,[3,4,[5,6]]].flat().flat().flat();

console.log(arr);
```

### Be careful!

[`Array.flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) method is relatively new. Older browsers like ie might not have implemented the method. If you want you code to work on all browsers you might have to transpile your JS to an older version. Check for [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) for current browser compatibility.

Comment: to flat higher dimensional arrays you simply can call the flat method with `Infinity` argument. Like this: `arr.flat(Infinity)`

Answer (score 33):

Another ECMAScript 6 solution in functional style:

Declare a function:

```
const flatten = arr => arr.reduce(
  (a, b) => a.concat(Array.isArray(b) ? flatten(b) : b), []
);
```

and use it:

```
flatten( [1, [2,3], [4,[5,[6]]]] ) // -> [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

```js
 const flatten = arr => arr.reduce(
         (a, b) => a.concat(Array.isArray(b) ? flatten(b) : b), []
       );


console.log( flatten([1, [2,3], [4,[5],[6,[7,8,9],10],11],[12],13]) )
```

Consider also a native function [Array.prototype.flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) (proposal for ES6) available in last releases of modern browsers. *Thanks to @(Константин Ван) and @(Mark Amery) mentioned it in the comments.*

The `flat` function has one parameter, specifying the expected depth of array nesting, which equals `1` by default.

```
[1, 2, [3, 4]].flat();                  // -> [1, 2, 3, 4]

[1, 2, [3, 4, [5, 6]]].flat();          // -> [1, 2, 3, 4, [5, 6]]

[1, 2, [3, 4, [5, 6]]].flat(2);         // -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

[1, 2, [3, 4, [5, 6]]].flat(Infinity);  // -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

```js
let arr = [1, 2, [3, 4]];

console.log( arr.flat() );

arr =  [1, 2, [3, 4, [5, 6]]];

console.log( arr.flat() );
console.log( arr.flat(1) );
console.log( arr.flat(2) );
console.log( arr.flat(Infinity) );
```

Comment: This is nice and neat but I think you have done an ES6 overdose.  There is no need for the outer function to be an arrow-function.  I would stick with the arrow-function for the reduce callback but flatten itself ought to be a normal function.

Comment: @StephenSimpson but is there a need for the outer function to be a *non*-arrow-function ? *"flatten itself ought to be a normal function"* – by "normal" you mean "non-arrow", but why? *Why* use an arrow function in the call to reduce then? Can you supply your line of reasoning?

Comment: @naomik My reasoning is that it is unnecessary. It's mainly a matter of style; I should have much clearer in my comment.  There is no major coding reason to use one or the other.  However, the function is easier to see and read as non-arrow.  The inner function is useful as an arrow function as it is more compact (and no context created of course). Arrow functions are great for creating compact easy to read function and avoiding this confusion.  However, they can actually make it more difficult to read when a non-arrow would suffice. Others may disagree though!

Comment: Getting a `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`

Comment: @Matt, please share the evnironment you use to reproduce the error

Comment: @diziaq Sorry I don't have that code anymore.  Ended up using the accepted answer after all.

`[].concat.apply([], arrays);`

Comment: You know what else is ES6? [`.flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)!

Comment: -1; `flat` isn't part of [ES6](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/). It's not even part of [ES9](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/). It's a [proposal](https://tc39.github.io/proposal-flatMap/#sec-Array.prototype.flat), not yet part of the ECMAScript spec, and [not yet available in all major JavaScript environments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat#Browser_compatibility).

Answer (score 30):

What about using `reduce(callback[, initialValue])` method of `JavaScript 1.8`

```
list.reduce((p,n) => p.concat(n),[]);
```

Would do the job.

Answer (score 24):

```
const common = arr.reduce((a, b) => [...a, ...b], [])
```

Answer (score 21):

You can use [`Array.flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) with [`Infinity`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Infinity) for any depth of nested array.

```js
var arr = [ [1,2,3,4], [1,2,[1,2,3]], [1,2,3,4,5,[1,2,3,4,[1,2,3,4]]], [[1,2,3,4], [1,2,[1,2,3]], [1,2,3,4,5,[1,2,3,4,[1,2,3,4]]]] ];

let flatten = arr.flat(Infinity)

console.log(flatten)
```

check here for browser [compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat#Browser_compatibility)

Answer (score 13):

## ES6 One Line Flatten

*See [lodash flatten](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#flatten), [underscore flatten (shallow `true`)](http://underscorejs.org/#flatten)*

```
function flatten(arr) {
  return arr.reduce((acc, e) => acc.concat(e), []);
}
```

[or](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10865042/2013580)

```
function flatten(arr) {
  return [].concat.apply([], arr);
}
```

Tested with

```
test('already flatted', () => {
  expect(flatten([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])).toEqual([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
});

test('flats first level', () => {
  expect(flatten([1, [2, [3, [4]], 5]])).toEqual([1, 2, [3, [4]], 5]);
});
```

## ES6 One Line Deep Flatten

*See [lodash flattenDeep](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#flattenDeep), [underscore flatten](http://underscorejs.org/#flatten)*

```
function flattenDeep(arr) {
  return arr.reduce((acc, e) => Array.isArray(e) ? acc.concat(flattenDeep(e)) : acc.concat(e), []);
}
```

Tested with

```
test('already flatted', () => {
  expect(flattenDeep([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])).toEqual([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
});

test('flats', () => {
  expect(flattenDeep([1, [2, [3, [4]], 5]])).toEqual([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
});
```

Comment: Your 2nd example is better written as `Array.prototype.concat.apply([], arr)` because you create an extra array just to get to the `concat` function. Runtimes may or may not optimize it away when they run it, but accessing the function on the prototype doesn't look any uglier than this already is in any case.

Answer (score 13):

Using the spread operator:

```js
const input = [["$6"], ["$12"], ["$25"], ["$25"], ["$18"], ["$22"], ["$10"]];
const output = [].concat(...input);
console.log(output); // --> ["$6", "$12", "$25", "$25", "$18", "$22", "$10"]
```

Answer (score 12):

**Please note:** When `Function.prototype.apply` (`[].concat.apply([], arrays)`) or the spread operator (`[].concat(...arrays)`) is used in order to flatten an array, both can cause stack overflows for large arrays, because every argument of a function is stored on the stack.

Here is a stack-safe implementation in functional style that weighs up the most important requirements against one another:

- reusability
- readability
- conciseness
- performance

```js
// small, reusable auxiliary functions:

const foldl = f => acc => xs => xs.reduce(uncurry(f), acc); // aka reduce

const uncurry = f => (a, b) => f(a) (b);

const concat = xs => y => xs.concat(y);


// the actual function to flatten an array - a self-explanatory one-line:

const flatten = xs => foldl(concat) ([]) (xs);

// arbitrary array sizes (until the heap blows up :D)

const xs = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]];

console.log(flatten(xs));


// Deriving a recursive solution for deeply nested arrays is trivially now


// yet more small, reusable auxiliary functions:

const map = f => xs => xs.map(apply(f));

const apply = f => a => f(a);

const isArray = Array.isArray;


// the derived recursive function:

const flattenr = xs => flatten(map(x => isArray(x) ? flattenr(x) : x) (xs));

const ys = [1,[2,[3,[4,[5],6,],7],8],9];

console.log(flattenr(ys));
```

As soon as you get used to small arrow functions in curried form, function composition and higher order functions, this code reads like prose. Programming then merely consists of putting together small building blocks that always work as expected, because they don't contain any side effects.

Comment: Haha. Totally respect your answer, although reading functional programming like this is still like reading Japanese character by character to me (English speaker).

Comment: If you find yourself implementing features of language A in language B not as a part of project with the sole goal of doing exactly this then someone somewhere had taken a wrong turn. Could it be you? Just going with `const flatten = (arr) => arr.reduce((a, b) => a.concat(b), []);` saves you visual garbage *and* explanation to your teammates why you need 3 extra functions *and* some function calls too.

Comment: @Daerdemandt But if you write it as separate functions, you will probably be able to reuse them in other code.

Comment: @MichałPerłakowski If you need to use them in several places then don't reinvent the wheel and choose a package from [these](https://github.com/stoeffel/awesome-fp-js) - documented and supported by other people.

Comment: Awkward and slow.

Answer (score 10):

I recommend a space-efficient [generator function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*):

```js
function* flatten(arr) {
  if (!Array.isArray(arr)) yield arr;
  else for (let el of arr) yield* flatten(el);
}

// Example:
console.log(...flatten([1,[2,[3,[4]]]])); // 1 2 3 4
```

If desired, create an array of flattened values as follows:

```
let flattened = [...flatten([1,[2,[3,[4]]]])]; // [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: I like this approach. Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/35073573/1175496 , but uses the spread operator `...` to iterate through the generator.

Answer (score 9):

If you only have arrays with 1 string element:

```
[["$6"], ["$12"], ["$25"], ["$25"]].join(',').split(',');
```

will do the job. Bt that specifically matches your code example.

Comment: Whoever down voted, please explain why. I was searching for a decent solution and of all the solutions I liked this one the most.

Comment: @Anonymous I didn't downvote it since it technically meets the requirements of the question, but it's likely because this is a pretty poor solution that isn't useful in the general case. Considering how many better solutions there are here, I'd never recommend someone go with this one as it breaks the moment you have more than one element, or when they're not strings.

Comment: It doesn't handle just arrays with 1 string elements, it also handles this array     `['$4', ["$6"], ["$12"], ["$25"], ["$25", "$33", ['$45']]].join(',').split(',')`

Comment: I discovered this method on my own, however knew it must have already been documented somewhere, my search ended here.

The drawback with this solution is, it coerces numbers, booleans etc to strings, try `[1,4, [45, 't', ['e3', 6]]].toString().split(',')`   ---- or -----    `[1,4, [45, 't', ['e3', 6], false]].toString().split(',')`

Answer (score 8):

I have done it using recursion and closures

```
function flatten(arr) {

  var temp = [];

  function recursiveFlatten(arr) { 
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      if(Array.isArray(arr[i])) {
        recursiveFlatten(arr[i]);
      } else {
        temp.push(arr[i]);
      }
    }
  }
  recursiveFlatten(arr);
  return temp;
}
```

Comment: Simple and sweet, this answer works better than the accepted answer. It flattens deeply nested levels to, not just the first level

Comment: AFAIK that is lexical scoping and not a closure

Comment: @dashambles is correct - the difference is that if it was a closure you would return the inner function to the outside and when the outer function is finished you can still use the inner function to access its scope. Here the lifetime of the outer function is longer than that of the inner function so a "closure" is never created.

Answer (score 8):

A Haskellesque approach

```js
function flatArray([x,...xs]){
  return x ? [...Array.isArray(x) ? flatArray(x) : [x], ...flatArray(xs)] : [];
}

var na = [[1,2],[3,[4,5]],[6,7,[[[8],9]]],10];
    fa = flatArray(na);
console.log(fa);
```

Answer (score 8):

if you use lodash, you can just use its `flatten` method: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.14#flatten

The nice thing about lodash is that it also has methods to flatten the arrays:

i) recursively: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.14#flattenDeep

ii) upto n levels of nesting: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.14#flattenDepth

For example

```
const _ = require("lodash");
const pancake =  _.flatten(array)
```

Answer (score 7):

ES6 way:

```js
const flatten = arr => arr.reduce((acc, next) => acc.concat(Array.isArray(next) ? flatten(next) : next), [])

const a = [1, [2, [3, [4, [5]]]]]
console.log(flatten(a))
```

ES5 way for `flatten` function with ES3 fallback for N-times nested arrays:

```js
var flatten = (function() {
  if (!!Array.prototype.reduce && !!Array.isArray) {
    return function(array) {
      return array.reduce(function(prev, next) {
        return prev.concat(Array.isArray(next) ? flatten(next) : next);
      }, []);
    };
  } else {
    return function(array) {
      var arr = [];
      var i = 0;
      var len = array.length;
      var target;

      for (; i < len; i++) {
        target = array[i];
        arr = arr.concat(
          (Object.prototype.toString.call(target) === '[object Array]') ? flatten(target) : target
        );
      }

      return arr;
    };
  }
}());

var a = [1, [2, [3, [4, [5]]]]];
console.log(flatten(a));
```

Answer (score 6):

I was goofing with [ES6 Generators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*) the other day and wrote [this gist](https://gist.github.com/ashwell/3dcc6702158604978d96). Which contains...

```
function flatten(arrayOfArrays=[]){
  function* flatgen() {
    for( let item of arrayOfArrays ) {
      if ( Array.isArray( item )) {
        yield* flatten(item)
      } else {
        yield item
      }
    }
  }

  return [...flatgen()];
}

var flatArray = flatten([[1, [4]],[2],[3]]);
console.log(flatArray);
```

Basically I'm creating a generator that loops over the original input array, if it finds an array it uses the [yield*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield*) operator in combination with recursion to continually flatten the internal arrays. If the item is not an array it just [yields](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield) the single item. Then using the [ES6 Spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) (aka splat operator) I flatten out the generator into a new array instance.

I haven't tested the performance of this, but I figure it is a nice simple example of using generators and the yield* operator.

But again, I was just goofing so I'm sure there are more performant ways to do this.

Answer (score 5):

just the best solution without lodash

```
let flatten = arr => [].concat.apply([], arr.map(item => Array.isArray(item) ? flatten(item) : item))
```

Answer (score 5):

I would rather transform the whole array, as-is, to a string, but unlike other answers, would do that using `JSON.stringify` and not use the `toString()` method, which produce an unwanted result.

With that `JSON.stringify` output, all that's left is to remove all brackets, wrap the result with start & ending brackets yet again, and serve the result with `JSON.parse` which brings the string back to "life".

- Can handle infinite nested arrays without any speed costs.
- Can rightly handle Array items which are strings containing commas.

### ```js
var arr = ["abc",[[[6]]],["3,4"],"2"];

var s = "[" + JSON.stringify(arr).replace(/\[|]/g,'') +"]";
var flattened = JSON.parse(s);

console.log(flattened)
```

- *Only for multidimensional Array of Strings/Numbers (not Objects)*

Comment: Your solution is incorrect. It will contain the comma when flattening inner arrays `["345", "2", "3,4", "2"]` instead of separating each of those values to separate indices

Comment: @realseanp - you misunderstood the value in that Array item. I intentionally put that comma as a value and not as an Array delimiter comma to emphasize the power of my solution above all others, which would output `"3,4"`.

Comment: I did misunderstand

Comment: that seems definitely the fastest solution I've seen for this; are you aware of any pitfalls @vsync (except the fact it looks a bit hacky of course - treating nested arrays as strings:D)

Comment: @GeorgeKatsanos - This method will not work for array items (and nested items) which are not of Primitive value, for example an item which points to a DOM element

Comment: @vsync - I  got it.

Answer (score 5):

## Ways for making flatten array

- using Es6 flat()
- using Es6 reduce()
- using recursion
- using string manipulation

### [1,[2,[3,[4,[5,[6,7],8],9],10]]] - [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

```js
// using Es6 flat() 
let arr = [1,[2,[3,[4,[5,[6,7],8],9],10]]]
console.log(arr.flat(Infinity))

// using Es6 reduce()
let flatIt = (array) => array.reduce(
  (x, y) => x.concat(Array.isArray(y) ? flatIt(y) : y), []
)
console.log(flatIt(arr))

// using recursion
function myFlat(array) {
  let flat = [].concat(...array);
  return flat.some(Array.isArray) ? myFlat(flat) : flat;
}
console.log(myFlat(arr));

// using string manipulation
let strArr = arr.toString().split(','); 
for(let i=0;i<strArr.length;i++)
  strArr[i]=parseInt(strArr[i]);

console.log(strArr)
```

Comment: Which is the fastest?

Comment: @mesqueeb thanks for questioning, I think simple loop is faster.

Answer (score 5):

I think array.flat(Infinity) is a perfect solution. But flat function is a relatively new function and may not run in older versions of browsers. We can use recursive function for solving this.

```js
const arr = ["A", ["B", [["B11", "B12", ["B131", "B132"]], "B2"]], "C", ["D", "E", "F", ["G", "H", "I"]]]
const flatArray = (arr) => {
    const res = []
    for (const item of arr) {
        if (Array.isArray(item)) {
            const subRes = flatArray(item)
            res.push(...subRes)
        } else {
            res.push(item)
        }
    }

    return res
}

console.log(flatArray(arr))
```

Comment: Thanks just now an interviewer asked me the same question.

Answer (score 5):

You can use **"join()"** and **"split()"**:

```js
let arrs = [
  ["$6"],
  ["$12"],
  ["$25"],
  ["$25"],
  ["$18"],
  ["$22"],
  ["$10"]
];

let newArr = arrs.join(",").split(",");

console.log(newArr); // ["$6", "$12", "$25", "$25", "$18", "$22", "$10"]
```

In addition, you can use **"toString()"** and **"split()"** as well:

```js
let arrs = [
  ["$6"],
  ["$12"],
  ["$25"],
  ["$25"],
  ["$18"],
  ["$22"],
  ["$10"]
];

let newArr = arrs.toString().split(",");

console.log(newArr); // ["$6", "$12", "$25", "$25", "$18", "$22", "$10"]
```

However, **both two ways above don't work properly if string contains commas**:

**"join()"** and **"split()"**:

```js
let arrs = [
  ["$,6"],
  ["$,12"],
  ["$2,5"],
  ["$2,5"],
  [",$18"],
  ["$22,"],
  ["$,1,0"]
];

let newArr = arrs.join(",").split(",");

console.log(newArr); 
// ["$", "6", "$", "12", "$2", "5", "$2", "5", "", "$18", "$22", "", "$", "1", "0"]
```

**"toString()"** and **"split()"**:

```js
let arrs = [
  ["$,6"],
  ["$,12"],
  ["$2,5"],
  ["$2,5"],
  [",$18"],
  ["$22,"],
  ["$,1,0"]
];

let newArr = arrs.toString().split(",");

console.log(newArr); 
// ["$", "6", "$", "12", "$2", "5", "$2", "5", "", "$18", "$22", "", "$", "1", "0"]
```

Comment: This is an extremely problematic and error prone way to do this.

Comment: @Brad. But it's fast if you're sure your array won't contain commas

Answer (score 4):

That's not hard, just iterate over the arrays and merge them:

```
var result = [], input = [["$6"], ["$12"], ["$25"], ["$25"], ["$18"]];

for (var i = 0; i < input.length; ++i) {
    result = result.concat(input[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It looks like this looks like a job for RECURSION!

- Handles multiple levels of nesting
- Handles empty arrays and non array parameters
- Has no mutation
- Doesn't rely on modern browser features

**Code:**

```
var flatten = function(toFlatten) {
  var isArray = Object.prototype.toString.call(toFlatten) === '[object Array]';

  if (isArray && toFlatten.length > 0) {
    var head = toFlatten[0];
    var tail = toFlatten.slice(1);

    return flatten(head).concat(flatten(tail));
  } else {
    return [].concat(toFlatten);
  }
};
```

**Usage:**

```
flatten([1,[2,3],4,[[5,6],7]]);
// Result: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Comment: careful, `flatten(new Array(15000).fill([1]))` throws `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` and freezed my devTools for 10 seconds

Comment: @pietrovismara, my test is around 1s.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the recursive way...

```
function flatten(arr){
    let newArray = [];
    for(let i=0; i< arr.length; i++){
        if(Array.isArray(arr[i])){
          newArray =  newArray.concat(flatten(arr[i]))
        }else{
          newArray.push(arr[i])
        }
    }
  return newArray; 
}

console.log(flatten([1, 2, 3, [4, 5] ])); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
console.log(flatten([[[[1], [[[2]]], [[[[[[[3]]]]]]]]]]))  // [1,2,3]
console.log(flatten([[1],[2],[3]])) // [1,2,3]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
function flatten(input) {
  let result = [];
  
  function extractArrayElements(input) {
    for(let i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
      if(Array.isArray(input[i])){
        extractArrayElements(input[i]);
      }else{
        result.push(input[i]);
      }
    }
  }
  
  extractArrayElements(input);
  
  return result;
}


// let input = [1,2,3,[4,5,[44,7,8,9]]];
// console.log(flatten(input));

// output [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is the fastest solution in **Typescript**, which works also on arrays with multiple levels of nesting:

```
export function flatten<T>(input: Array<any>, output: Array<T> = []): Array<T> {
    for (const value of input) {
        Array.isArray(value) ? flatten(value, output) : output.push(value);
    }
    return output;
}
```

and than:

```
const result = flatten<MyModel>(await Promise.all(promises));
```

Answer (score 4):

```
const arr = [1, 2, [3, 4]];

arr.reduce((acc, val) => acc.concat(val), []);
```

Answer (score 4):

Well if your coding environment supports ES6 (ES2015), you need not write any recursive functions or use array methods like map, reduce etc.

A simple [spread operator](https://medium.com/coding-at-dawn/how-to-use-the-spread-operator-in-javascript-b9e4a8b06fab) (...) will help you flatten an **Array of arrays** into a **single Array**

eg:

```
  const data = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5],[2]]
  let res = []
  data.forEach(curSet=>{
      res = [...res,...curSet]
  })
  console.log(res) //[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2]
```

Answer (score 4):

I am using this method to flat mixed arrays:  (which seems easiest for me). Wrote it in longer version to explain steps.

```js
function flattenArray(deepArray) {
    // check if Array
    if(!Array.isArray(deepArray)) throw new Error('Given data is not an Array')

    const flatArray = deepArray.flat() // flatten array
    const filteredArray = flatArray.filter(item => !!item) // filter by Boolean
    const uniqueArray = new Set(filteredArray) // filter by unique values
    
    return [...uniqueArray] // convert Set into Array
}
```

// shorter version:

```js
const flattenArray = (deepArray) => [...new Set(deepArray.flat().filter(item=>!!item))]
```

```
flattenArray([4,'a', 'b', [3, 2, undefined, 1], [1, 4, null, 5]])) // 4,'a','b',3,2,1,5
```

[Codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/javascript-flat-array-xwo00d?file=/src/index.js)

#### Modern method

Use of **[].flat(Infinity)** method

```js
const nestedArray = [1,[2,[3],[4,[5,[6,[7]]]]]]
const flatArray = nestedArray.flat(Infinity)
console.log(flatArray)
```

Answer (score 3):

I propose two short solutions without recursion. They are not optimal from a computational complexity point of view, but work fine in average cases:

```
let a = [1, [2, 3], [[4], 5, 6], 7, 8, [9, [[10]]]];

// Solution #1
while (a.find(x => Array.isArray(x)))
    a = a.reduce((x, y) => x.concat(y), []);

// Solution #2
let i = a.findIndex(x => Array.isArray(x));
while (i > -1)
{
    a.splice(i, 1, ...a[i]);
    i = a.findIndex(x => Array.isArray(x));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The logic here is to convert input array to string and remove all brackets([]) and parse output to array. I'm using ES6 template feature for this.

```
var x=[1, 2, [3, 4, [5, 6,[7], 9],12, [12, 14]]];

var y=JSON.parse(`[${JSON.stringify(x).replace(/\[|]/g,'')}]`);

console.log(y)
```

Comment: this is the fastest and cleverest way to do it. I was using this to avoid recursion and easily rebuild the array, but yours is 3% faster. Way to go :)
```const flatten = function (A) {
  return A
  .toString()
  .split(',')
  .reduce( (a,c) => {
   let i = parseFloat(c);
   c = (!Number.isNaN(i)) ? i : c;
   a.push(c);
   return a;
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a version in Typescript based on the answer by artif3x, with a bonus implementation of `flatMap` for Scala fans.

```
function flatten<T>(items: T[][]): T[] {
  return items.reduce((prev, next) => prev.concat(next), []);
}

function flatMap<T, U>(items: T[], f: (t: T) => U[]): U[] {
  return items.reduce((prev, next) => prev.concat(f(next)), new Array<U>());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's another deep flatten for modern browsers:

```
function flatten(xs) {
  xs = Array.prototype.concat.apply([], xs);
  return xs.some(Array.isArray) ? flatten(xs) : xs;
};
```

Comment: dumping code is not an answer..please explain the steps of this solution. it seems like a very elegant one, but also, complex.

Answer (score 2):

Nowadays the best and easy way to do this is joining and spliting the array like this.

```
var multipleArrays = [["$6","$Demo"], ["$12",["Multi","Deep"]], ["$25"], ["$25"], ["$18"], ["$22"], ["$10"], ["$0"], ["$15"],["$3"], ["$75"], ["$5"], ["$100"], ["$7"], ["$3"], ["$75"], ["$5"]]

var flattened = multipleArrays.join().split(",")
```

This solution works with multiple levels and is also oneliner.

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/c0bq8ksu/)

**EDIT for ECMAScript 6**

Since ECMAScript 6 has been standardized, you can change the operation `[].concat.apply([], arrays);` for  `[].concat(...arrays);`

```
var flattened = [].concat(...input);
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/c0bq8ksu/1/)

**EDIT Most Efficient solution**

The most efficient way to solve the problem is using a loop. You can compare the "ops/sec" velocity [here](http://jsperf.com/flatten-an-array-loop-vs-reduce)

```
var flattened=[];
for (var i=0; i<input.length; ++i) {
    var current = input[i];
    for (var j=0; j<current.length; ++j)
        flattened.push(current[j]);
}
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/c0bq8ksu/2/)

Hope It Helps

Comment: It doesn't work when array contains strings which contain commas, for example: `[[","]].join().split(",")` doesn't give desired result.

Answer (score 2):

```
const flatten = array => array.reduce((a, b) => a.concat(Array.isArray(b) ? flatten(b) : b), []);
```

Per request, Breaking down the one line is basically having this.

```
function flatten(array) {
  // reduce traverses the array and we return the result
  return array.reduce(function(acc, b) {
     // if is an array we use recursion to perform the same operations over the array we found 
     // else we just concat the element to the accumulator
     return acc.concat( Array.isArray(b) ? flatten(b) : b);
  }, []); // we initialize the accumulator on an empty array to collect all the elements
}
```

Comment: **From review queue**: May I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.

Comment: Your code is written in cutting-edge, shortest way but honestly It takes me more time to figure out what it is actually doing... not good for maintenance

Comment: Nice one! You can flatten array like objects too if you change `Array.isArray(b)` in to `b.length` and add a `Array.from(array)` after the return instead of `array`.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to the great solutions. I used recursion to solve this.

```
            const flattenArray = () => {
                let result = [];
                return function flatten(arr) {
                    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                        if (!Array.isArray(arr[i])) {
                            result.push(arr[i]);
                        } else {
                            flatten(arr[i])
                        }
                    }
                    return result;
                }
            }
```

Test results: https://codepen.io/ashermike/pen/mKZrWK

Answer (score 2):

It's better to do it in a **recursive way**, so if still another array inside the other array, can be **filtered** easily...

```
const flattenArray = arr =>
  arr.reduce(
    (res, cur) =>
       !Array.isArray(cur) 
       ? res.concat(cur)
       : res.concat(flattenArray(cur)), []);
```

And you can call it like:

```
flattenArray([[["Alireza"], "Dezfoolian"], ["is a"], ["developer"], [[1, [2, 3], ["!"]]]);
```

and the result isas below:

```
["Alireza", "Dezfoolian", "is a", "developer", 1, 2, 3, "!"]
```

Comment: This answer needs to be shown in a simpler fashion as a function. It's very hard to read and understand.

Answer (score 2):

Simply using spread operator we can flatten in the following way.

```js
var OriginalArray = [[5, 1], [6], [2], [8]];
var newArray = [];

for (let i = 0; i < OriginalArray.length; i++) {
  newArray.push(...OriginalArray[i]);
}

console.log(newArray)
```

Answer (score 2):

**I have just try to solve the problem without using any inbuild function.**

```
var arr = [1, 3, 4, 65, [3, 5, 6, 9, [354, 5, 43, 54, 54, 6, [232, 323, 323]]]];
var result = [];

function getSingleArray(inArr) {
  for (var i = 0; i < inArr.length; i++) {
    if (typeof inArr[i] == "object") {
      getSingleArray(inArr[i]); // Calling Recursively
    } else {
      result.push(inArr[i]);
    }
  }
}

getSingleArray(arr);
console.log(result); // [1, 3, 4, 65, 3, 5, 6, 9, 354, 5, 43, 54, 54, 6, 232, 323, 323]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution non recursive flatten deep using a stack.

```
    function flatten(input) {
        const stack = [...input];
        const res = [];
        while (stack.length) {
            const next = stack.pop();
            if (Array.isArray(next)) {
                stack.push(...next);
            } else {
                res.push(next);
            }
        }
        return res.reverse();
    }
    const arrays = [["$6"], ["$12"], ["$25"], ["$25"], ["$18"], ["$22"], ["$10"]];
    flatten(arrays);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[1,[2,3],[4,[5,6]]].reduce(function(p, c) {
    return p.concat(c instanceof Array ? 
                    c.reduce(arguments.callee, []) : 
                    [c]); 
}, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

if your array only consists out of integers or strings you can use this dirty hack:

```
var arr = [345,2,[34],2,[524,[5456]],[5456]];
var flat = arr.toString().split(',');
```

Works, in FF, IE and Chrome didn't test the other browsers yet.

Comment: Just wondering why this is a hack? I think it is a smart and simple way to do it.

Comment: IMO it's a hack because it abuses the `.toString()` function (`.toString` will call for me `.toString` recursively) which if I recall correctly returned previously `"[object Array]"` instead of a recursive `arr.join(',')` :)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I have just experienced that yesterday. =)

Comment: @TimHong haha I hope nothing broke

Comment: Hahaha. It was all good. I tested it before checking in anything. In the end, I wrote my own version of it. =) I pasted my answer here. (Should be on top now, since it is the newest answer.) Yeah, thanks for asking. Hahaha.

Comment: What will happen if the value contains a 'COMMA' ??

Comment: just like you expect, if arr is `[[1,2],["3,4"]]` it'll end up with: `["1","2","3", "4"]`

Comment: @EaterOfCode - but that isn't what you would expect, which should be  `["1","2","3,4"]`

Comment: Needless to say, numbers are converted to strings with this solution. But it also fails with empty arrays: `[1,[2,3], [], 4, [5]].toString().split(',');` will output `["1", "2", "3", "", "4", "5"]`. Assuming we are interested in numbers, one alternative would be: `[1,[2,3], [], 4, [5]].toString().split(',').filter((e) => e !== '').map(Number);`.

Answer (score 1):

To flatten a two-dimensional array in one line:

```
[[1, 2], [3, 4, 5]].reduce(Function.prototype.apply.bind(Array.prototype.concat))
// => [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
```

Comment: That's pretty brilliant.  It does fail at a certain nesting depth: `[[1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, [[7]]]]`.

Comment: Nice hack! You can shorten your code if you use the following auxiliary functions: `const bindable = Function.bind.bind(Function.bind); const applicable = bindable(Function.apply);` and then `[[1, 2], [3, 4, 5]].reduce(applicable([].concat));`.

Answer (score 1):

There's a much faster way of doing this than using the merge.concat.apply() method listed in the top answer, and by faster I mean more than **several orders of magnitude** faster. This assumes your environment has access to the ES5 Array methods.

```
var array2d = [
  ["foo", "bar"],
  ["baz", "biz"]
];
merged = array2d.reduce(function(prev, next) {
    return prev.concat(next);
});
```

Here's the jsperf link: http://jsperf.com/2-dimensional-array-merge

Comment: I don’t know what’s wrong with the JSPerf because the link is dead, but this is backwards. Repeated `concat` is not only slower, it’s *asymptotically* slower.

Answer (score 1):

I'm aware that this is hacky, but the must succinct way I know of to flatten an array(of any depth!) of strings(without commas!) is to turn the array into a string and then split the string on commas:

```
var myArray =[["$6"], ["$12"], ["$25"], ["$25"], ["$18"], ["$22"], ["$10"], ["$0"], ["$15"],["$3"], ["$75"], ["$5"], ["$100"], ["$7"], ["$3"], ["$75"], ["$5"]];
var myFlatArray = myArray.toString().split(',');

myFlatArray;
// ["$6", "$12", "$25", "$25", "$18", "$22", "$10", "$0", "$15", "$3", "$75", "$5", "$100", "$7", "$3", "$75", "$5"]
```

This should work on any depth of nested arrays containing only strings and numbers(integers and floating points) with the caveat that numbers will be converted to strings in the process. This can be solved with a little mapping:

```
var myArray =[[[1,2],[3,4]],[[5,6],[7,8]],[[9,0]]];
var myFlatArray = myArray.toString().split(',').map(function(e) { return parseInt(e); });
myFlatArray;
// [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]
```

Comment: Doesn't quite work. See my comments on previous answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21551946/4470169

Answer (score 1):

Recursive version that works on all datatypes

```
 /*jshint esversion: 6 */

// nested array for testing
let nestedArray = ["firstlevel", 32, "alsofirst", ["secondlevel", 456,"thirdlevel", ["theinnerinner", 345, {firstName: "Donald", lastName: "Duck"}, "lastinner"]]];

// wrapper function to protect inner variable tempArray from global scope;
function flattenArray(arr) {

  let tempArray = [];

  function flatten(arr) {
    arr.forEach(function(element) {
      Array.isArray(element) ? flatten(element) : tempArray.push(element);     // ternary check that calls flatten() again if element is an array, hereby making flatten() recursive.
    });
  }

  // calling the inner flatten function, and then returning the temporary array
  flatten(arr);
  return tempArray;
}

// example usage:
let flatArray = flattenArray(nestedArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
/**
* flatten an array first level
* @method flatten
* @param array {Array}
* @return {Array} flatten array
*/
function flatten(array) {
  return array.reduce((acc, current) => acc.concat(current), []);
}


/**
* flatten an array recursively
* @method flattenDeep
* @param array {Array}
* @return {Array} flatten array
*/
function flattenDeep(array) {
  return array.reduce((acc, current) => {
    return Array.isArray(current) ? acc.concat(flattenDeep(current)) : acc.concat([current]);
  }, []);
}

/**
* flatten an array recursively limited by depth
* @method flattenDepth
* @param array {Array}
* @return {Array} flatten array
*/
function flattenDepth(array, depth) {
  if (depth === 0) {
    return array;
  }
  return array.reduce((acc, current) => {
    return Array.isArray(current) ? acc.concat(flattenDepth(current, --depth)) : acc.concat([current]);
  }, []);
}
```

Comment: Why do you even have a ternary operator, if the values on left and right are doing the same thing in first solution: `return Array.isArray(current) ? acc.concat(current) : acc.concat([current]);`? Why even check for if the item is also an array, if it's just one level :)

Comment: I mean: `[1,2].concat(3)` is same as `[1,2].concat([3])`

Answer (score 1):

The following code will flatten deeply nested arrays:

```
/**
 * [Function to flatten deeply nested array]
 * @param  {[type]} arr          [The array to be flattened]
 * @param  {[type]} flattenedArr [The flattened array]
 * @return {[type]}              [The flattened array]
 */
function flattenDeepArray(arr, flattenedArr) {
  let length = arr.length;

  for(let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    if(Array.isArray(arr[i])) {
      flattenDeepArray(arr[i], flattenedArr);
    } else {
      flattenedArr.push(arr[i]);
    }
  }

  return flattenedArr;
}

let arr = [1, 2, [3, 4, 5], [6, 7]];

console.log(arr, '=>', flattenDeepArray(arr, [])); // [ 1, 2, [ 3, 4, 5 ], [ 6, 7 ] ] '=>' [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 ]

arr = [1, 2, [3, 4], [5, 6, [7, 8, [9, 10]]]];

console.log(arr, '=>', flattenDeepArray(arr, [])); // [ 1, 2, [ 3, 4 ], [ 5, 6, [ 7, 8, [Object] ] ] ] '=>' [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just keep on using Array.flat() method to achieve this even when array is a lot more nested.

```
[1,2,3,[2]].flat()
```

is equivalent to

```
[1,2,3,[2]].flat(1)
```

so as your nesting increases you can keep on increasing number.

eg:

```
[1,[2,[3,[4]]]].flat(3) // [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

And if you are not sure about level of nesting you can just pass Infinity as parameter

```
[1,2,3,[2,[3,[3,[34],43],[34]]]].flat(Infinity) //[1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 34, 43, 34]
```

Comment: This doesn't work if the array contains a string which contains a comma. For example, `[['test,test'], ['test']].join().split(',')` gives `['test', 'test', 'test']`  instead of `['test,test', 'test']`.

Comment: I understand it but comma is just an separator. if you want you can use any other which is for sure not be part of json. or you can use combination of special characters as separator. that's logical right. any ways thanks for down voting @MichałPerłakowski

Comment: I normally use some jibberish, a pattern that is impossible in the dataset.

Comment: @MichałPerłakowski I hope this fits better for all Array type. I found it on twitter and looks worth updating here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Ramda JS** [flatten](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#flatten)

```js
var arr = [[1,2], [3], [4,5]];
var flattenedArray = R.flatten(arr); 

console.log(flattenedArray)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let arr = [["$6"], ["$12"], ["$25"], ["$25"], ["$18"], ["$22"], ["$10"], ["$0"], ["$15"],["$3"], ["$75"], ["$5"], ["$100"], ["$7"], ["$3"], ["$75"], ["$5"]];
arr = arr.reduce((a, b) => a.concat(b)); // flattened
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple flatten util i've written

```
const flatten = (arr, result = []) => {
    if (!Array.isArray(arr)){
        return [...result, arr];
    }
     arr.forEach((a) => {
         result = flatten(a, result)
    })

    return result
}

console.log(flatten([1,[2,3], [4,[5,6,[7,8]]]])) // [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 ]
```

Answer (score 1):

**Define an array of arrays in javascript called foo and flatten that array of arrays into a single array using javascript's array concat builtin method:**

```
const foo = [["$6"], ["$12"], ["$25"], ["$25"], ["$18"], ["$22"], ["$10"]] 
console.log({foo}); 

const bar = [].concat(...foo) 
console.log({bar});
```

Should print:

```
{ foo: 
   [ [ '$6' ],
     [ '$12' ],
     [ '$25' ],
     [ '$25' ],
     [ '$18' ],
     [ '$22' ],
     [ '$10' ] ] }
{ bar: [ '$6', '$12', '$25', '$25', '$18', '$22', '$10' ] }
```

Answer (score 1):

Since ES2019 has introduced flat and flatMap then flat any array can be done like this:

```
const myArr = [["$6"], ["$12"], ["$25"], ["$25"], ["$18"], ["$22"], ["$10"]]
const myArrFlat= myArr.flat(Infinity);
console.log(myArrFlat); // ["$6", "$12", "$25", ...]
```

Ref. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat

Answer (score 1):

Recursively calling the `deepFlatten` function so we can spread the inner array without using any external helper method is the way to go.

```
const innerArr = ['a', 'b'];
const multiDimArr = [[1, 2], 3, 4, [5, 6, innerArr], 9];

const deepFlatten = (arr) => {
  const flatList = [];
  arr.forEach(item => {
    Array.isArray(item)
     ? flatList.push(...deepFlatten(item)) // recursive call
     : flatList.push(item)
  });
  return flatList;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution will work for any depth level (specifying how deep a nested array structure should be) of array.

```
function flatten(obj) {
    var out = [];
    function cleanElements(input) {
        for (var i  in input){
            if (input[i]instanceof Array){
                cleanElements(input[i]);
            }
            else {
                out.push(input[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    cleanElements(obj);
    return (out);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this method to flat two arrays

```
arr1.concat(...arr2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my version of it. It allows you to flatten a complicated object which could be used in more scenarios:

**Input**

```
var input = {
   a: 'asdf',
   b: [1,2,3],
   c: [[1,2],[3,4]],
   d: {subA: [1,2]}
}
```

**Code**

The function is like this:

```
function flatten (input, output) {

  if (isArray(input)) {
    for(var index = 0, length = input.length; index < length; index++){
      flatten(input[index], output);
    }
  }
  else if (isObject(input)) {
    for(var item in input){
      if(input.hasOwnProperty(item)){
        flatten(input[item], output);
      }
    }
  }
  else {
    return output.push(input);
  }
};

function isArray(obj) {
  return Array.isArray(obj) || obj.toString() === '[object Array]';
}

function isObject(obj) {
  return obj === Object(obj);
}
```

**Usage**

```
var output = []

flatten(input, output);
```

**Output**

["asdf", 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2]

Answer (score 0):

If you need to support IE8 and, therefore, can't use methods such as reduce or isArray, here is a possible solution. It is a verbose approach to help you to understand the recursive algorithm.

```
function flattenArray(a){

    var aFinal = [];

    (function recursiveArray(a){

        var i,
            iCount = a.length;

        if (Object.prototype.toString.call(a) === '[object Array]') {
            for (i = 0; i < iCount; i += 1){
                recursiveArray(a[i]);
            }
        } else {
            aFinal.push(a);
        }

    })(a);

    return aFinal;

}

var aMyArray = [6,3,4,[12,14,15,[23,24,25,[34,35],27,28],56],3,4];

var result = flattenArray(aMyArray);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var arrays = [["$6"], ["$12"], ["$25"], ["$25"], ["$18"], ["$22"], ["$10"], ["$0"], ["$15"],["$3"], ["$75"], ["$5"], ["$100"], ["$7"], ["$3"], ["$75"], ["$5"]];
var merged = [].concat.apply([], arrays);
alert(merged);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can flatten an array of arrays using `Array.prototype.reduce()` and `Array.prototype.concat()`

```js
var data = [["$6"], ["$12"], ["$25"], ["$25"], ["$18"], ["$22"], ["$10"], ["$0"], ["$15"],["$3"], ["$75"], ["$5"], ["$100"], ["$7"], ["$3"], ["$75"], ["$5"]].reduce(function(a, b) {
  return a.concat(b);
}, []);
console.log(data);
```

Related docs:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Answer (score 0):

I originally thought to use the `.reduce` method and recursively call a function to flatten inner arrays, however this can lead to stack overflows when you are working with a deeply nested array of deeply nested arrays. Using concat is also not the best way to go, because each iteration will create a new shallow copy of the array. What we can do instead is this:

```
const flatten = arr => {
    for(let i = 0; i < arr.length;) {
        const val = arr[i];
        if(Array.isArray(val)) {
            arr.splice(i, 1, ...val);
        } else {
            i ++;
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
```

We are not creating new arrays via concat and we are not recursively calling any functions.

http://jsbin.com/firiru/4/edit?js,console

Answer (score 0):

I have a simple solution without using in a special js function. (like reduce etc)

```
const input = [[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5]]
let flattened=[];

for (let i=0; i<input.length; ++i) {
    let current = input[i];
    for (let j=0; j<current.length; ++j)
        flattened.push(current[j]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another approach using jQuery $.map() function.
From jQuery documentation:

> The function can return an array of values, which will be flattened into the full array.

```
var source = [["$6"], ["$12"], ["$25"], ["$25"], ["$18"], ["$22"], ["$10"]];
var target = $.map(source, function(value) { return value; }); // ["$6", "$12", "$25", "$25", "$18", "$22", "$10"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let arr = [1, [2, 3, [4, 5, [6, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11, 12]]]];

function flattenList(nestedArr) {
  let newFlattenList = [];

  const handleFlat = (array) => {
    let count = 0;
    while (count < array.length) {
      let item = array[count];
      if (Array.isArray(item)) {
        handleFlat(item);
      } else {
        newFlattenList.push(item);
      }
      count++;
    }
  };
  handleFlat(nestedArr);
  return newFlattenList;
}`enter code here`

console.log(flattenList(arr));
```

[CodeSandBox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/flatten-array-javascript-xijsvr?file=/src/index.js)

Answer (score 0):

Simple and handles multiple levels of nested:

```js
// deeply nested array
const myArray = [1, 2, [3, 4, [5, 6, [[[7,8, [[[[[9, 10]]]]]]]]]]] ;

const flatten = (arr) => {
    for (let index = 0; index < arr.length; index++) {
        const elem = arr[index];

        if (Array.isArray(elem)) {
            arr.splice(index, 1, ...elem);
            index--;
        }
    }
};

flatten(myArray);
console.log(myArray); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let mainArr =[["$6"], ["$12"], ["$25"], ["$25"], ["$18"], ["$22"], ["$10"]]
let temp = [];

const flattenArray = (arr) =>{
  
  let n = arr.length;

  for(let i=0;i<n;i++){
    if(typeof(arr[i]) == "string" || typeof(arr[i]) == "number"){
      temp.push(arr[i]);
    }
    else if(typeof(arr[i]) == "object"){
      flattenArray(arr[i]);
    }
  }
}

flattenArray(mainArr)
console.log(temp)
```

Answer (score 0):

Flatten polyfill using recursion:

```js
function flatten(arr) {
  let ans = [];
  const convert = (arr) => {
    if (!Array.isArray(arr)) {
      ans.push(arr);

      return;
    }

    arr.forEach((it) => {
      convert(it)
    });
  };

  convert(arr);

  return ans;
}

console.log(flatten([ [ 1, 2 ], [ 3, [ 4 ] ] ]));
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Array.prototype.flatten = Array.prototype.flatten || function() {
    return [].reduce.call(this, function(flat, toFlatten) {
        return flat.concat(Array.isArray(toFlatten) ? toFlatten.flatten() : toFlatten);
    },[])
};
```

Comment: I'm reviewing, can you add some more information around your solution? Why you feel it's efficient?

Answer (score -1):

I answer this question just with `ES6`, assume the deep array is:

```
const deepArray = ['1',[['a'],['b']],[2],[[[['4',[3,'c']]]],[5]]];
```

If you know or guess the depth of your arrays is not more than a number like `7`, use below code:

```
const flatArray = deepArray.flat(7);
```

But if you don't know the depth of your deep arrays or your `JavaScript` engine doesn't support `flat` like `react-native` `JavaScriptCore`, use below function that is used `JavaScript` `reduce` function:

```
 const deepFlatten = arr =>
         arr.reduce(
           (acc, val) =>
             Array.isArray(val) 
               ? acc.concat(deepFlatten(val)) 
               : acc.concat(val),
             []
         );
```

Both of methods return below result:

```
["1", "a", "b", 2, "4", 3, "c", 5]
```

Answer (score -1):

Much simpler and straight-forward one; with option to deep flatten;

```
const flatReduce = (arr, deep) => {
    return arr.reduce((acc, cur) => {
        return acc.concat(Array.isArray(cur) && deep ? flatReduce(cur, deep) : cur);
    }, []);
};

console.log(flatReduce([1, 2, [3], [4, [5]]], false)); // =>  1,2,3,4,[5]
console.log(flatReduce([1, 2, [3], [4, [5, [6, 7, 8]]]], true)); // => 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
const arr = [1, 2, '22',[1,33,44,['ddd'], 5678], 'abbb', 'ccc', 1234];

const flat = String(arr).split(',').map((elm)=>  {

    return  !isNaN(elm) ? Number(elm) : elm
    
})
console.log(flat)
```

Answer (score -2):

## What about deep flatten & Object Oriented ?

```
[23, [34, 454], 12, 34].flatten();
// -->   [23,34, 454, 12, 34]
```

---

```
[23, [34, 454,[66,55]], 12, 34].flatten();

// -->  [23, 34, 454, [66,55], 12, 34]
```

#### DEEP Flatten :

```
[23, [34, 454,[66,55]], 12, 34].flatten(true);

// --> [23, 34, 454, 66, 55, 12, 34]
```

## [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/X3Xex/4/)

## [**CDN**](https://rawgit.com/abdennour/spl/master/js/jsdk/array.js)

---

If all array elements are Integer,Float,... or/and String , So just , do this trick :

```
var myarr=[1,[7,[9.2]],[3],90];
eval('myarr=['+myarr.toString()+']');
print(myarr);
// [1, 7, 9.2, 3, 90]
```

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/abdennour/3fqs93jf/)

Comment: The code in the demo **doesn't make sense**, unless explained.

Comment: [FYI, extending the native Array's prototype is generally discouraged.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8859828/javascript-what-dangers-are-in-extending-array-prototype)

Answer (score -3):

I believe that the best way to do this would be something like this:

```
var flatten = function () {
  return [].slice.call(arguments).toString().split(',');
};
```

Answer (score -3):

I was just looking for the faster and easy solution to do this, why? because I get this as a one interview question and I got curious, so I made this:

```
function flattenArrayOfArrays(a, r){
    if(!r){ r = []}
    for(var i=0; i<a.length; i++){
        if(a[i].constructor == Array){
            flattenArrayOfArrays(a[i], r);
        }else{
            r.push(a[i]);
        }
    }
    return r;
}

var i = [[1,2,[3]],4,[2,3,4,[4,[5]]]], output;

// Start timing now
console.time("flatten");
output = new Array(JSON.stringify(i).replace(/[^\w\s,]/g,"")); 
output
// ... and stop.
console.timeEnd("flatten");

// Start timing now
console.time("flatten2");
output = [].concat.apply([], i)
output
// ... and stop.
console.timeEnd("flatten2");

// Start timing now
console.time("flatten3");
output = flattenArrayOfArrays(i)
output
// ... and stop.
console.timeEnd("flatten3");
```

I used the most popular answers here and my solution. I guess somebody will find this interesting. Cheers!

Answer (score -3):

Sheer Magic of ES6

```
const flat = A => A.reduce((A, a) => Array.isArray(a) ? [...A, ...flat(a)] : [...A, a], []);
```

Answer (score -4):

Using code from [there](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/805364/LINQ-for-JavaScript).

I would write:

```
myArray.enumerable().selectMany(function(x) { return x; }).array()
```