# How do you filter an array of objects for undefined values?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, underscore.js, lodash

I have the following array:

```
[{object}, {object}, {object}]
```

Each object looks something like:

```
{key0: 3, key1: undefined, key2: 7}
```

I want to filter the array for undefined properties so that each object in the array now looks like:

```
{key0: 3, key2: 7}
```

I've tried everything with Lo_Dash and I'm thinking I must be going crazy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What code do you have written right now?

You could do something like this:

```
_.each(array, function(item, index, collection){
  collection[index] = _.filter(item, function(value){
    return value !== undefined;
  });
});
```

This will iterate over the array, then filter each object in the array.

EDIT:

If you'd like to maintain the array elements as objects, you can use _.reduce instead. IE:

```
_.each(array, function(item, index, collection){
  collection[index] = _.reduce(item, function(result, value, key){
    if(value !== undefined) { result[key] = value; }
    return result;
  }, {});
});
```

Comment: I tried this.  It definitely takes out the undefined value but it also reformats my array of objects to an array of arrays; I need to keep the key value pairs that have defined values as key value pairs.

Comment: Ah I see, try it with `_.reduce` instead of `_.filter` then. See my edit.

Comment: Great solution!  Reduce is really helpful but underused for those of us not in the know . . . I came up with a solution for concating arrays with reduce fairly recently: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080028/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-concatenate-n-arrays-in-javascript/30421311#30421311

I still have a lot to learn about functional coding

Answer (score 1):

This is the approach that I would take. Use `filter` on your array and check for all the undefined props in a loop. Then simply delete them from your object. I just looked and another poster noted this. I've included the hasOwnProperty check as well.

```
var data = [{
    key0: 3,
    key1: undefined,
    key2: 7
}, {
    key0: 4,
    key1: undefined,
    key2: 8
}, {
    key0: 5,
    key1: undefined,
    key2: 9
}];

function removeUndefined(obj) {
    for (var prop in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop) && obj[prop] === undefined) {
            // do stuff
           delete obj[prop];
        }
    }
    return obj;
}

var filtered = data.filter(removeUndefined);

console.log(filtered);
```

Answer (score 1):

In LoDash you can use a combination of `map` + `omit`:

```
objs = _.map(objs, function(x) {
    return _.omit(x, _.isUndefined)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through all properties and remove undefined properties using the "delete" keyword.

```js
var myObj = {key0: 3, key1: undefined, key2: 7};

for (var i in myObj) {
  if (myObj[i] === undefined) {
    delete myObj[i];
  }
}
```

Comment: When looping objects you should generally use a `hasOwnProperty` check, but I suppose that's really up to the OP.

Comment: Thanks fellas! I'm trying your solutions now. Will follow up shortly

Comment: I a similar version to what you provided with LoDash but it seems like I can't use the delete key word while using strict mode. Any solution around the strict mode limitation besides turning it off?