# get each data from multidimentional array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have data like this

```
var data = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]];
```

I want to get each data from that array like `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ,7 ,8` using `for` looping but I can't get each data.

this is my code for get each data using looping

```
var each = [];
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            each.push(data[i]);
            for (var i = 0; i < each.length; i++) {
                console.log(each[i]);
            };
        };
```

in my thinking, I can get each of my array data like `1,2,3 etc`

but the looping result is `[1,2,3,4]`. This is first data in my array

please anybody tell me the best way to get each data from that array

Comment: what do you mean with "get each data"? Is  this `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ,7 ,8]` array should be expected output?

Comment: I want the result is `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8` in no array. it means i want to get every item from that array

Comment: so, should it be a string like `"1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8"` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the most efficient way to concatenate N arrays in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080028/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-concatenate-n-arrays-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The more appropriate way is to use `Array#reduce` but you can also make your code work with below changes:

```
var each = [];
 for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { 
        each = each.concat(data[i]);           
        for (var j = 0; j < each.length; j++) {
            console.log(each[j]);
        }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [`Array#concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) to get a flat array.

```js
var data = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]],
    each = data.reduce(function (r, a) { return r.concat(a); }, []);

console.log(each);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```js
data = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]];
var joined = [].concat.apply([], data).join(",");
   console.log(joined);
```

Answer (score 0):

another option will be to use a concat with apply

```
var data = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]];   
var flat = [].concat.apply([],data);
console.log(flat);
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the simplest way would be

```
var data = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]],
       z = [].concat(...data); // [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
```