# how to print given array in for each using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an array like below.

```
[{
  'i_id':'119',
  'name':'Brinjal-250',
  'weight':'250.Gm',
  'qty':'1',
  'price':'5',
  'market':'55',
  'image':'f_control/images/vegetables/Brinjal-PNG-Image-min'
 },   
 {  
  'i_id':'101',
  'name':'Tomato',
  'weight':'500.Gm',
  'qty':'1',
  'price':'4',
  'market':'44',
  'image':'f_control/images/vegetables/tometo-min.jpg'
}]
```

And i want it to in for each loop using java script, It is possible?
If possible then please guide me in right direction, Thanks.

***The demo output***[image]

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: Your array structure does not look good. Please update your question and try to make it more meaningful.

Comment: There are two arrays here. Update the question with correct structure and expected output

Comment: Question is not clear..

Comment: okay, wait while i clear my question.

Comment: @DroidNoob  Can i know that which kind of correct array structure to print in loop?

Comment: Is those two objects supposed to be in the same array?

Comment: This question might be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript?rq=1

Comment: @DroidNoob yes...

Comment: Check the above link

Comment: Okay, I am trying on @Mary 's link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using different array for each object ? You can push both objects in a single array , then you can use forEach loop like this :-`

```
var array = [
    {
        'i_id':'119',
        'name':'Brinjal-250',
        'weight':'250.Gm',
        'qty':'1',
        'price':'5',
        'market':'55',
        'image':'f_control/images/vegetables/Brinjal-PNG-Image-min'
    },
    {
        'i_id':'101',
        'name':'Tomato',
        'weight':'500.Gm',
        'qty':'1',
        'price':'4',
        'market':'44',
        'image':'f_control/images/vegetables/tometo-min.jpg'
    }
    ];
        array.forEach(function(value){
            console.log(value.name);
        });`
```

Comment: Thanks, But How can i push both objects in single array?

Comment: when you are making these objects on the backend.

Comment: You may try Array.prototype.concat() https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat

Comment: @Mary will concating the arrays is an efficient method ? because on the client end if there are thousands of arrays and you have to concat them will take time and memory also because after concating these arrays it returns a new array.

Comment: @AshishKumar you may check discussion about concat efficiency here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080028/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-concatenate-n-arrays-in-javascript

Comment: @VishalPanara please upvote the answer if you found it useful . thanks.

Comment: @Mary i request you to please go through your link once again. In your link the answer is that if there are many arrays more than (100 ,000) the best approach is to use forloop in which you can push one array in to another array. And its also written there is .concat() is a method for convenience and likely performance not for the best performance

Comment: @AshishKumar all true. They say that method is better with the big amount of items.
In case that not many people will reach this comment discussion on the bottom of the page I suggest you to edit your question one more time and add all your issues there. Tell about your big amount of arrays of objects (btw, are your arrays of objects are come in a single array?), efficiency, and tell about methods you found but can't ore don't want to use (like concat). Because it look like a request about forEach JS syntax for now.

Answer (score 1):

If both objects are in the same array, just like below:

```
[{'i_id':'119',
'name':'Brinjal-250',
'weight':'250.Gm',
'qty':'1',
'price':'5',
'market':'55',
'image':'f_control/images/vegetables/Brinjal-PNG-Image-min'},
{'i_id':'101',
    'name':'Tomato',
    'weight':'500.Gm',
    'qty':'1',
    'price':'4',
    'market':'44',
    'image':'f_control/images/vegetables/tometo-min.jpg'}]
```

then use:

```
arrayName.forEach(function (item, index) {
  console.log(item["name"]);
})
```

or else use:

```
for(var key in arrayName) {
   console.log("key: "+key+" Value: "+arrayName[key]["name"]);
}
```

Check out the fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/NayanaDas/42f3yxho/

Updated Answer:

if you want to make this array `[{'i_id':'101'}] [{'i_id':'102'}]` like this  `[{'i_id':'101'},{'i_id':'102'}]` , then use JavaScript Array concat() Method :

```
var arr1 = [{'i_id':'101'}];
var arr2 = [{'i_id':'102'}];

var array = arr1.concat(arr2);

console.log(JSON.stringify(array));
```

See the fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/NayanaDas/eaumhnvw/

Comment: I am getting the array like this [{'i_id':'101'}] [{'i_id':'102'}] and i want like this [{'i_id':'101'},{'i_id':'102'}] . any suggestion?

Comment: @VishalPanara : please check out the updated answer. Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

The requirement is not clear. If you want to loop through he array use `forEach` or conventinal `for-loop` will also work.

```
var myArray=[//json array]
myArray.forEach(function(item,index){
  console.log(item.name) // will seperately log Brinjal-250, & Tomato
})
```