# How Do I Concatenate An Array Using Functional JS?

Tags: javascript

I want to do this...

```
var all = [];
_.each(leftArr, (leftItem) => { 
   all.concat(leftItem.concat(getSomeOtherArray());
})
return all;
```

But I want to do it in a clean functional way. How can I do it without opening the foreach loop?

Comment: Provide your array and expected result.

Comment: What's `leftArr`?  What about `getSomeOtherArray()`?  Why are you calling `getSomeOtherArray()` for each element in `leftArr`?

Comment: Also `.concat()` returns a new array, so your `all` array is not getting filled with anything.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the most efficient way to concatenate N arrays in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080028/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-concatenate-n-arrays-in-javascript)

Comment: Also, how is this not "clean?"  What do you mean by "functional?"

Answer (score 1):

Use [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to concat the `leftItem` with the results of `getSomeOtherArray()`, then flatten everything by [spreading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) into another concat:

```js
const leftArr = [[1], [2], [3]];

const getSomeOtherArray = () => ['a'];

const all = [].concat(...leftArr.map((leftItem) => leftItem.concat(getSomeOtherArray())));

console.log(all);
```

Comment: Are you sure that this is what OP does expect?

Comment: It seems like a reasonable conclusion from his code, but I might be wrong.