# Convert array to object and push object into array -javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js, object

I getting the response array data is:

```
var data =[{
    'id':'1','name':'sam'
}];
var data =[{
    'id':'2','name':'ram'
}];
var data =[{
    'id':'2','name':'ragu'
}];
```

I am getting this data into looping method .
This results are my server side console only.
But, my client side as only view the **first array data** only
so, i need to convert  that array data into object and push into another **var = arraydata**.

I tried this code:

```
            var arrayData =[];
            var  [objectData] = data;
            arrayData.push(objectData);
```

I Tried result is:

```
var arrayData =[{
            'id':'1','name':'sam'
        }];
```

but i getting single **data** only

my expected result is :

```
var arrayData =[{
        'id':'1','name':'sam'
    },{
        'id':'2','name':'ram'
    },{
        'id':'2','name':'ragu'
    }];
```

please give any solution solution for me!

Comment: `i need to convert that array data into object` It is already object

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the most efficient way to concatenate N arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080028/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-concatenate-n-arrays)

Comment: Please add  `loop` in the question as well

Answer (score 1):

You can try Array [concat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) method.

```js
var data1 =[{
    'id':'1','name':'sam'
}];
var data2 =[{
    'id':'2','name':'ram'
}];
var data3 =[{
    'id':'2','name':'ragu'
}];

var arrayData = data1.concat(data2, data3);

console.log(arrayData);
```

Using ES6 [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) :

```js
let data1 =[{
    'id':'1','name':'sam'
}];
let data2 =[{
    'id':'2','name':'ram'
}];
let data3 =[{
    'id':'2','name':'ragu'
}];

[...arrayData] = [...data1, ...data2, ...data3];

console.log(arrayData)
```

Answer (score 1):

## ES6

You could use [`[].concat.apply([],[v1,va2.... so on]))`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) to get the required result.

**DEMO**

```js
var data =[{'id':'1','name':'sam'}], 
    data1 =[{'id':'2','name':'ram'}], 
    data2 =[{'id':'2','name':'ragu'}];
    
console.log([].concat.apply([],[data,data1,data2]))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important;top: 0;}
```

---

You can also use the [`Spread_syntax`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

**DEMO**

```js
const data =[{'id':'1','name':'sam'}], 
    data1 =[{'id':'2','name':'ram'}], 
    data2 =[{'id':'2','name':'ragu'}];
    
console.log([...data,...data1,...data2])
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important;top: 0;}
```

Comment: I am getting const data value into looping . that are get one by one in to const data

Comment: So you can use same inside of looping.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is `var arrayData =[];`, this code create `arrayData` is empty.

You should use `var arrayData = arrayData  || [];`
I hope it help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can youse `.concat()` as per the example below:

```
var data1 = [{
    'id':'1','name':'sam'
}];

var data2 = [{
    'id':'2','name':'ram'
}];

var out = [].concat(data1, data2);


// After more data, or one at a time example
var data3 = [{
    'id':'3','name':'ragu'
}];

out = out.concat(data3)

console.log(out);

-> [{
->    'id':'1','name':'sam'
-> },{
->    'id':'2','name':'ram'
-> },{
->     'id':'2','name':'ragu'
-> }];
```

Answer (score 0):

you can concat all the arrays into one::

suppose I have 3 arrays

```
var data =[{
'id':'1','name':'sam'
```

}];
var data1 =[{
    'id':'2','name':'ram'
}];
var data2 =[{
    'id':'3','name':'ragu'
}];

you can get the result by

```
var output=data.concat(data1,data)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use .forEatch()

```
var data = [{
    'id':'1','name':'sam'
}];

var data2 = [{
    'id':'2','name':'ram'
}];

data2.forEach(element => {
    data.push(element);
});

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

use ES6 spread operator and push the new array object into old array.

```
var data =[{
    'id':'1','name':'sam'
}];
var data1 =[{
    'id':'2','name':'ram'
}];

data.push(...data1)
```

Hope this helps you :)

Answer (score 0):

An array of Objects can be created by using the Spread operators

```
var data1 = [{
    'id':'1','name':'sam'
}];

var data2 = [{
    'id':'2','name':'ram'
}];
var data3 =[{
   'id':'2','name':'ragu'
}]; 
var data=[...data1,...data2, data3]

//console.log(data)
```

This will return you JSON object [{},{},{}]