# Append objects in loop

Tags: javascript

I've chunks of data coming as response of each call and is retrieved as parameter of a function in below format. I need to append all the chunks of data into one.

```
function getJSONdata(jsondata){
//Below is where I need help
//cumilatedJSONdata = cumilatedJSONdata + jsondata
}
```

Below is the Format of the objects coming:

```
var jsondata = {"results":[
{"code":"1101696","name":"1101696","price":{"formattedValue":"36.00 
CAD"}},
{"code":"1101693","name":"1101693","price":{"formattedValue":"33.00 
CAD"}},
{"code":"1101699","name":"1101699","price":{"formattedValue":"39.00 
CAD"}}
]};
```

I want the `cumilatedJSONdata` structure should be something like

```
var cumilatedJSONdata = {"results":[
{"code":"1101696","name":"1101696","price":{"formattedValue":"36.00 
CAD"}},
{"code":"1101693","name":"1101693","price":{"formattedValue":"33.00 
CAD"}},
{"code":"1101699","name":"1101699","price":{"formattedValue":"39.00 
CAD"}},
{"code":"1101693","name":"1101693","price":{"formattedValue":"33.00 
CAD"}},
{"code":"1101699","name":"1101699","price":{"formattedValue":"39.00 
CAD"}},
{"code":"1101693","name":"1101693","price":{"formattedValue":"33.00 
CAD"}},
{"code":"1101699","name":"1101699","price":{"formattedValue":"39.00 
CAD"}}
]};
```

I tried something like this

```
var cumilatedJSONdata= {"results":[]}

function getJSONdata(jsondata){
var cumilatedJSONdata = $.extend(true,cumilatedJSONdata, jsondata
}
 );
```

This is not persisting previous data and getting replaced with new data.

Could anyone please help me on this.

Comment: `var cumulatedData = ''; function getJSONdata(jsondata){ cumulatedData += jsondata; }`

Comment: You are dealing with regular JavaScript objects, not JSON. The JSON format is for *serialised* data and it's text. Since you have actual objects and arrays, you can simply combine the arrays.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080028/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-concatenate-n-arrays

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374126/how-to-extend-an-existing-javascript-array-with-another-array-without-creating

Comment: I'm not exactly able to correlate those solutions here @www.admiraalit.nl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the concat method of javascript

```
cumilatedJSONdata.results = cumilatedJSONdata.results.concat(jsondata.results);
```

Comment: This is giving as cumilatedJSONdata is not defined ReferenceError: cumilatedJSONdata is not defined

Comment: Try running this:
var cumilatedJSONdata = {"results":[]};
var jsondata = {"results":[
{"code":"1101696","name":"1101696","price":{"formattedValue":"36.00 CAD"}},
{"code":"1101693","name":"1101693","price":{"formattedValue":"33.00 CAD"}},
{"code":"1101699","name":"1101699","price":{"formattedValue":"39.00 CAD"}}
]};

cumilatedJSONdata.results = cumilatedJSONdata.results.concat(jsondata.results);

Comment: Are you getting the jsondata from a request?

Comment: Thank you there was an issue with the scope and now its resolved

Answer (score 1):

```
let results = [];

// do your async loop / promise loop here
while (needToGetResults) {
    let newResponse = await asyncRequest();
    results = results.concat(newResponse.results);
}

return results;
```

alternatively,

```
return {results:results}
```