# How can I append an array of objects to an already existing array?

Tags: javascript

I created the following array:

```
$scope.testAccounts[0] = { id: 99, name: "Select Account" };
```

I tried

```
$scope.testAccounts.push(result.data);
```

where results.data looks something like this:

```
[{ id: 1, name: "x" },{ id: 2, name: "y" }]
```

However this does not seem to work as it tries to add an array as the second element. What I need is to have the contents of the array result.data appended to the array $scope.testAccounts

**Please note** that all the examples I have seen so far seem to not work if the array is an array of objects. This is what I have. Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/351409/appending-to-array

Comment: Check your result.data if it matches your array layout.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374126/how-to-append-an-array-to-an-existing-javascript-array?rq=1 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/351409/appending-to-array?rq=1

Comment: The problem is my array comprises of an object in the first row followed by another array in the second. What I need to do is to add the contents of the second array to the first. What happens is my code adds the whole array as the second element.

Comment: Sorry. I just above provided more details

Comment: `$scope.testAccounts.concat([{ id: 1, name: "x" },{ id: 2, name: "y" }]);`

Comment: Is result.data an object? or an array?

Comment: should `$scope.testAccounts.push(result.data[0]);` works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for [Array.concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)

```
> foo = [1,2,3]
[1, 2, 3]
> foo.concat([4,5,6])
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: The problem is that my 1,2,3,4,5,6 are objects such as {id: 0, name:"x"}. I can't get it to work when they are objects.

Comment: @Anne: array functions generally don't care what arguments you provide. `concat` should work just fine with objects. Could you post your exact data and code?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried again and it worked.