# How to add dynamic objects to javascript object property

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am trying to develop a wordpress plugin and for it I need to add tinymce listbox with dynamic values. At the moment I have stored dynamic objects in **listv** array and I need to push them in to **tinyMCE.activeEditor.settings.myKeyValueList**. But it wont work. even I have tried **push** and **valueOf** javascript methods but still no luck.

```
function getValues() {
    //Set new values to myKeyValueList 
    var listv = [];
    var len = pw_script_vars.ad;
    for (i = 0; i < len.length; i++) {
        listv[i] = {
            text: pw_script_vars.ad[i],
            value: pw_script_vars.ad[i]
        };
    }
    for (i = 0; i < listv.length; i++) {
        tinyMCE.activeEditor.settings.myKeyValueList += [listv[i]];
    }

    return tinyMCE.activeEditor.settings.myKeyValueList;
}
```

Comment: Please post your attempt with `.push()`. `+=` is definitely wrong.

Comment: its something like this                                        for(i=0; i < listv.length; i++){
tinyMCE.activeEditor.settings.myKeyValueList.push([listv[i]]);
}

Comment: i assume += is wrong but as i said in the description push() also did not work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I have seen by searching for `tinyMCE myKeyValueList`, it seems like you have to simply assign the value

```
tinyMCE.activeEditor.settings.myKeyValueList = listv;
```

instead of trying to add to it:

```
for (i = 0; i < listv.length; i++) {
    tinyMCE.activeEditor.settings.myKeyValueList += [listv[i]];
}
```

---

If you want to append to the existing `myKeyValueList` array (if it actually exists), see [How to extend an existing JavaScript array with another array, without creating a new array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374126/how-to-append-an-array-to-an-existing-javascript-array) .

Comment: thanx mate it works.. i was trying to fix this for almost 5 hours.. thank you you saved my day...!