# How to extend an existing js-array with another?

Tags: javascript, arrays, extend

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374126/how-to-extend-an-existing-javascript-array-with-another-array?rq=1) question but unfortunately it was just closed. There are many good answers but I wonder why no one suggested the following solution:

`a = a.concat(b)`

The author said he don't wanted to have an new array but extend the array a.

Comment: `concat()` returns a **new** array. That is not the same as extending an array. Sometimes code depends on references not changing

Comment: yes but I set `a` on this array, so it will be updated to this array and so it is extended. I don't understand the problem :/

Comment: Like I said, `concat()` generates a **new** array, so nothing is extended. You may be setting `a` to the new array, but the original value (array reference) is lost

Comment: ok, but if i do this: `a.push.apply(a, b)`how can i access on the original reference of a? Where is the difference to setting a to a new array?

Comment: I'm still new with Javascript and I try to understand it :)

Answer (score 1):

Setting the local variable to the value does not necessarily mean that will propagate to everywhere that variable is referenced. Take the example:

```js
var foo = (function() {
  var bar = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
  return {
    get: function() {
      return bar;
    },
    show: function() {
      $("html").append("<div>" + bar.length + "</div>");
    }
  };
})();

var a = foo.get();
foo.show();

a = foo.get();
a = a.concat([6, 7]);
foo.show();

a = foo.get();
a.push([6, 7]);
foo.show();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The second call to `show` prints "5", because `bar` was not modified by `a = a.concat`. Because `a` and `bar` are references, when you set `a` to the return value of `bar.concat`, a copy of `bar` is made and assigned to `a`. The location `bar` references does not change, nor do the contents of the array previously known as `bar`.

When one reference is reassigned, that does not propagate to every place referencing `bar` (if it did, copying would be nigh-impossible).

---

Getting into which array methods are the most helpful in this situation, you probably `push` or `splice`. It depends on the exact use (appending or inserting at a particular index, removing existing elements, one at a time or from another array).

[Splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) can do some interesting things within an array, and has the fun property of returning elements that are removed. It can both insert and replace elements, depending on the parameters provided.

[Push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) does just that, appending elements to the end of the array as if it were a list. If you have another array, `it.push.apply(other)` is a handy way to combine them.

If you have access to [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/), many of the collection methods in there can be useful. They typically return a new array, but offer such functionality as `flatten` and `union`.