# Calling underscore each (_.each) on an object's method

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I'm trying to use the underscore.js `each` function to push each element of an array onto an existing array, in-place.

To do this, I assumed I could use the `push` array *method*, rather than the usual *anonymous function* passed to `each`, provided that I passed a context object as the 3rd argument to `each`:

```
> var a = [1,2,3]
> var b = []
> _.each(a, b.push, b)
```

I'd expect `b` to now be `[1,2,3]`, but it is actually:

```
Array [ 1, 0, Array[3], 2, 1, Array[3], 3, 2, Array[3] ]
```

What is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`_.each` doesn't work in the same way as `foreach` in many other functional programming languages or libraries. As described in the [documentation](http://underscorejs.org/#each),

> Each invocation of iteratee is called with three arguments: (element,
>   index, list)

If you instead use `console` methods, you can see this:

```
> _.each(a, console.log, console)

  1 0 Array [ 1, 2, 3 ]
  2 1 Array [ 1, 2, 3 ]
  3 2 Array [ 1, 2, 3 ]
```

so `push` ends up accepting those nine values, rather than the three one might hope for. One can just use an anonymous function:

```
_.each(a, function(x) { b.push(x) })
```

and `b` is then `[1,2,3]` as expected.

Or, in this particular case, use one of the other ways to [extend an array in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374126/how-to-extend-an-existing-javascript-array-with-another-array).