# Unable to assign value to global array without using .push()

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

For some reason I cannot assign anything to a global array without using `.push()`.

```
(function() {
    var globalEmail = [];

    var testClear = function() {
        var arr = [1, 2, 3];

        if (globalEmail.length > 1) {
            globalEmail = [];
        }
        else {
            globalEmail = arr;
        }
    };

    window.globalEmail = globalEmail;
    window.testClear = testClear;
})();
```

If I call `testClear()` and then `globalEmail` in the console, `globalEmail` remains unchanged.

Comment: Works fine for me... pasted your code in the console, called `testClear();`, then `window.globalEmail` - result: `(3) [1, 2, 3]` `globalEmail` is also populated.

Comment: You are loosing your references when you do `globalEmail = [];` or `globalEmail = arr;`, so window.globalEmail is different than the new globalEmail array. You need to modify the array in place (with splice and concat, for your example).

Comment: @tymeJV: try executing this code inside an IIFE, and then use `globalEmail` and `testClear` to reproduce the issue.

Comment: the code works fine! If the code has to be executed in a IIFE, this should be mentioned in the question

Comment: @kLabz Thank you, this solution works fine. If you want to add it as an answer I will accept it. :)

Comment: I agree that it's not clear, but this code is run in another context as when @j-doe is running `testClear` and checking `globalEmail`, that's why there is `window.globalEmail` and `window.testClear`. You run both in the same context, so you have a direct reference to `globalEmail`, that's why it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in comments, you are loosing references here because you assign `globalEmail` to new arrays, so window.globalEmail is different than the new globalEmail array.

You need to modify the array in place (with `splice` and `concat`, for your example).

Answer (score 2):

For empty an array, you could set the lenght to zero and for assigning, you could use [`Array#push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) with [spread syntax `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)

```js
var globalEmail = [],
    testClear = function() {
        var arr = [1, 2, 3];

        if (globalEmail.length > 1) {
            globalEmail.length = 0;
        } else {
            globalEmail.push(...arr);
        }
    };

testClear();
console.log(globalEmail);

testClear();
console.log(globalEmail);
```

Comment: assuming you use a transpiler for the that ;-)

Comment: @MarouenMhiri, it's ES6 standard (as the question is tagged).

Answer (score 0):

You want to define the globalEmail variable as global, not local.

```
(function() {
    window.globalEmail = []; // this goes here

    var testClear = function() {
        var arr = [1, 2, 3];

        if (window.globalEmail.length > 1) {
            window.globalEmail = [];
        }
        else {
            window.globalEmail = arr;
        }
    };

    //window.globalEmail = globalEmail; <-- not here
    window.testClear = testClear;
})();
```

The `window.` is not absolutely required, but the `var globalEmail;` within a function defines a local variable, which is not what you wanted in the first place.

Although, if the point of `testClear()` is to clear any array, then it is not properly implemented. Instead it should take a parameter and you work on that parameter.

```
function testClear(a)
{
    var arr = [1, 2, 3];

    if(a.length > 1) {
        a.splice(0);
    }
    else {
        a.splice(0);
        a.push.apply(a, arr);
    }
}

testClear(window.globalEmail);
```

Then the `testClear()` function makes more sense, I think.

Note that there are drawbacks with `a.push.apply()` which breaks on large arrays. See here [How to extend an existing JavaScript array with another array, without creating a new array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374126/how-to-extend-an-existing-javascript-array-with-another-array-without-creating) for details.