# When push a data into array is pushing in just one index

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Hi there guys I am new in this but I have a array in my localstorage I get that array I save in old empty array, and I make a petition to the ajax and I try push the new data into my old array

```
$.getJSON(setUrl(pagination, page), function (response) {
            var old = []; 
            old = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('msg'));
            old.push(response.DATA);
            console.log(old);
});
```

but the result I getting is some like this

[image]

I put all my new array inside a index of my old array what am I doing wrong ? can some one help me

Comment: This happens when response.DATA is an array. This is behaving as expected. If you want to add each item individually, iterate over them.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374126/how-to-extend-an-existing-javascript-array-with-another-array-without-creating

Answer (score 1):

Use [Array.ptototype.concat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) instead to merge the arrays.
`Array.prototype.concat()`:

> The concat() method is used to merge two or more arrays. This method
>   does not change the existing arrays, but instead returns a new array.

```
$.getJSON(setUrl(pagination, page), function (response) {
  var old = []; 
  old = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('msg'));
  old = old.concat(response.DATA);
  console.log(old);
});
```

```js
var old = [
  { id: 1 },
  { id: 2 }
];

console.log('old: ', old);

var json = [
  { id: 3 },
  { id: 4 }
];

old = old.concat(json);

console.log('merged: ', old);
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: I use concat before but the element return is the same array

Comment: I try save each element as a new element in the old array

Comment: You are right, I missed a key portion in my answer. `concat()` returns a new array so it would need to be saved to a variable. Updated the answer.

Comment: @AlfredoIzquierdo You can reassign the value of `old` if the goal is to specifically use `old` again in the method or elsewhere. I've updated the answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `concat` but remember....

> The concat() method is used to merge two or more arrays. This method does not change the existing arrays, but instead returns a new array. <sub>[source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)</sub>

```
$.getJSON(setUrl(pagination, page), function (response) {
        var old = []; 
        old = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('msg'));
        var combined = old.concat(response.DATA);
        console.log(combined);
});
```