# How to push a value of an array (arr1) into a new empty array (arr2) in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

### How can I push the values of arr1 into the arr2 ?

#### P.S. I know could simply accomplish this with:

`arr2 = arr1`  or `var arr2 =[...arr1]`

or by using similar solutions instead I want to push the `arr1` values into the empty `arr2` as seen below and without touching the `arr2` at all.

This `var arr2 = [];` MUST be left as it is.

```
var arr1 = [33, 45, -10, 15, 5, 7, -5, 1, -30];

var arr2 =[];


console.log(arr2); 
// This should output: (9) [33, 45, -10, 15, 5, 7, -5, 1, -30]
// and NOT [Array(9)]
```

Comment: I've found a solution guys:

`arr1.forEach(el =>arr2.push(el))`

Comment: @p.s.w.g This question isn't a duplicate of the one linked, as the edit shows. Better dupe here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374126/how-to-extend-an-existing-javascript-array-with-another-array-without-creating

Comment: @HansBrende I agree that given the updated requirements, that's a better duplicate. I've voted to reopen the question, but I'm not able to close the question again because I had previously voted to close it. For future reference, you almost never need to notify a specific user for issues like this. If you feel a question or answer needs some attention, you can post on [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) or an appropriate [char room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/javascript), or even flag the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to extend an existing JavaScript array with another array, without creating a new array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374126/how-to-extend-an-existing-javascript-array-with-another-array-without-creating)

Comment: @p.s.w.g Thanks. I had already tried flagging the question but my flag was declined with the following message: `declined - Moderator flags must not be used to resolve wrong dupe closures. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/291977. @ping the gold badge user who closed the question in the comments and inform them the same.`

Comment: @HansBrende Fair enough. I think the last time I read a meta post about conduct surrounding duplicate questions, the recommendation was to use chat or meta--with flags mostly for abuse of some sort--but not the reply system IIRC. That of was before [Mjölnir](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dupehammer), so recommendations may be a bit different now.

Answer (score 3):

```
var arr1 = [33, 45, -10, 15, 5, 7, -5, 1, -30];
var arr2 =[...arr1];
```

Comment: [IE11 support of the spread operator](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#ie11) (Spoiler: lots of red)

Answer (score 0):

[Try using the spread Operator.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Comment: Link-only answers are not considered valuable on Stack Exchange. They die and your answer dies with them.

Answer (score 0):

Would concat work?  Something like this?

```
var a = [1, 2, 3];
var b = [4, 5, 6];
var c = a.concat(b);
```

Comment: He is not asking about concatenation. He wants to push the values of the first array inside the second array.

Comment: Exactly. I could simply do: `arr2 = arr1` or `var arr2 =[...arr1]` but I'm asking to push the values into the empty array instead.