# I want function to return this list

Tags: function

I want to create a function to return a list of columns which is from a list of list of strings,the output should talk  char of the first row and add it to char of the second row to out a strings from all chars which in row1 and other rows,to understand what I want,please see the code:
board = [['A','B','T','T'],['F','D','Y','E']]
output should be as this:
['AF','BD','TY','TE']
Thanks for any help!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Which language?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374126/how-to-extend-an-existing-javascript-array-with-another-array-without-creating

Comment: It's a program in python for word game search,I want to create a function which return a list from another list of lists of strings

Comment: It's not Java script ,but python