# Why my code with switch(true) and Array.concat() doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, arrays, concatenation

```js
//JavaScript:

    function concatArrays() {
      var recentlyCompleted = ["rc1", "rc2"];
      var upcomingActivities = [];
      var decisionsRequired = [];
      var records = [];
        switch(true) {
          case (recentlyCompleted.length >0):
            records.concat(recentlyCompleted);
            console.log("recentlyCompleted.length >0");
            console.log(records);
          case (upcomingActivities.length >0):
            records.concat(upcomingActivities);
            console.log("upcomingActivities.length >0");
            console.log(records);
          case (decisionsRequired.length >0):
            records.concat(decisionsRequired);
            console.log("decisionsRequired.length >0");
            console.log(records);
            break;
        }
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(records);
      
      var records2 = recentlyCompleted.concat(upcomingActivities).concat(decisionsRequired);
      document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(records2);
    }
```

```html
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>switch(true)</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <p>Click the button to join arrays.</p>
      <button onclick="concatArrays()">Try it</button>
      <p id="demo"></p>
      <p id="demo2"></p>
    </body>
```

Sorry please I have read that the main advantage over the obvious if else if sequence is the ability to omit the break statement and execute more than one block. I wanted to execute more than one block in my case(true) code. But I see something wrong with this simple code.

I am very sorry but could you explain what's wrong with part of this code with switch(true)
Thanks!

Execution more than one block:
[image: Execution more than one block]

Screenshot of the execution of the correct answer:
[image]

```
function concatArrays() {
  var recentlyCompleted = ["rc1", "rc2"];
  var upcomingActivities = [];
  var decisionsRequired = [];
  var records = [];
  switch (true) {
    case (recentlyCompleted.length > 0):
      records = records.concat(recentlyCompleted);
      console.log("recentlyCompleted.length >0");
      console.log(records);
    case (upcomingActivities.length > 0):
      records = records.concat(upcomingActivities);
      console.log("upcomingActivities.length >0");
      console.log(records);
    case (decisionsRequired.length > 0):
      records = records.concat(decisionsRequired);
      console.log("decisionsRequired.length >0");
      console.log(records);
      break;
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
    JSON.stringify(records);

  var records2 = recentlyCompleted
    .concat(upcomingActivities)
    .concat(decisionsRequired);
  document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML =
    JSON.stringify(records2);
}
```

Comment: [`switch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch): _"A switch statement first evaluates its expression. It then looks for the first case clause whose expression evaluates to the same value as the result of the input expression (using the strict comparison, ===) and transfers control to that clause, executing the associated statements. (**If multiple cases match the provided value, the first case that matches is selected, even if the cases are not equal to each other**.)"_

Comment: In Switch is only equal conditions are allowed. Otherwise use IF statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `case` without a `break` doesn't re-evaluate the next `case` for equality, but just runs the block unconditionally - called [*fallthrough*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switch_statement#Fallthrough). I doubt this is what you wanted. Use multiple successive `if` statements instead (not an `if-else` chain) - or just go for the `records2` approach if you don't care about the log statements.

Second, `concat` creates a new array, it doesn't mutate the target by appending to it. See [How to append something to an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/351409/1048572) or [How to extend an existing JavaScript array with another array, without creating a new array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1374126/1048572) for various solutions.

Comment: Thank you @Bergi!
concat creates a new array, it doesn't mutate the target by appending to it
Correct!

Comment: A case without a break doesn't re-evaluate the next case for equality, but just runs the block unconditionally... Many thanks to you, Bergi!

Answer (score -1):

You should take a look at the spread operator:

```
var records = [...recentlyCompleted, ...upcomingActivities, ..decisionsRequired]
```

Also your `records` and `records2` are always going to be the same.