# Array push creates a new Array which I am instead just looking to add a record to my original data

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I want to add an element to my array, but push just adds a new array

https://jsfiddle.net/jna79gs5/

```
var original = [{"Member_Name":"MORGAN, KATHY","Member_ID":"308484402","Member_DOB":"03/05/1998","ProgramType":"Supportive","RateCode":"000603"},{"Member_Name":"BUDZYNSKI, ALDA","Member_ID":"C436418737","Member_DOB":"11/30/1998","ProgramType":"Supportive","RateCode":"000603"},{"Member_Name":"MALLARI, SCOTT","Member_ID":"705681684","Member_DOB":"08/20/2002","ProgramType":"Supportive","RateCode":""}]

let newData = {name:"John", address:"432 main st"}; 
//let newData = [{"name":"John", "address":"432 main st"}]; 

const arr = [];
arr.push(original)
arr.push(newData)

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to extend an existing JavaScript array with another array, without creating a new array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374126/how-to-extend-an-existing-javascript-array-with-another-array-without-creating)

Comment: Well, working with just numbers ends being different to me as I end up being distracted from looking at my actual objects and strings of data that I was getting a nested nightmare .   I'm sure that answer if helpful to some, just not to me   thx though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand correctly, you are trying to merge `arr` and `original` ?
In that case, you can use [`concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat).

```js
var original = [{test: 'value'}]

let newData = {name:"John", address:"432 main st"}; 
//let newData = [{"name":"John", "address":"432 main st"}]; 

let arr = [];
arr = arr.concat(original)
arr.push(newData)

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't push an array to another array using push - JavaScript will just assume you meant to add the array as an element, rather than concatenating the array.

You'll want to use forEach:

```
const arr = [];
original.forEach(el => arr.push(el));
arr.push(newData);
```

Alternatively, you can use the array-spread operator:

```
const arr = [...original, newData];
```

Finally, you could use concat.

```
const arr = original.concat([newData]);
```

Comment: note that `array.push` can also take a variable number of arguments, so you could do `arr.push(...original, newData);`

Comment: Huh! TIL. Every day is a school day

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are creating 2 separate Arrays. `const arr = []` and `var original = [...]` . And then you push `original` into `arr`, which creates the behaviour you don't want.

You dont need the `const arr` - you can just push `newData` into `original`

```
original.push(newData)
```

If you want to create another one then you can just use the spread operator.

```
const arr = [...original, newData];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use array-Spread Operator

const arr =[...original,newData];