# Append Row outputting "[Ljava.lang.Object;@536f3e11" instead of range values

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am currently trying to create a Scrabble Game word scorer. So far, it has been going well, but I've run into an issue. I have one main row (A2:AP2) that contains formulas and calculates the word score. I want to get the values from that entire row each time someone submits a word, and create a record of all the words someone has submitted.

The code below starts that process, but whenever i run the script, it appends "[Ljava.lang.Object;@536f3e11" instead of the actual array values.

```
var p1ScoreCalc = p1Sheet.getRange('A2:AP2').getValues();

//---Array for score records---\\
var array = []

//---Checks if submit is checked--\\
if(submitCheck == 1){

//---Checks for what player is submitting---\\
if(playerCheck === "P1"){

array.push(p1ScoreCalc);

testSheet.appendRow(array);

}
}
```

[image: Append Row result]

I cannot figure out why this is happening. This is not my first time using `appendRow()`, and i cannot seem to find what I am doing wrong. I could be missing something very simple.

Here is the spreadsheet link for reference:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pgsE_OtO8MEqoVcGH5csQ43BOm9kx5XbagwhNTpfSk4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Use [flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(submitCheck==1 && playerCheck=="P1"){
  testSheet.appendRow(p1Sheet.getRange('A2:AP2').getValues()[0]);//append a flattened array
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`appendRow` requires an Array of numbers, strings, booleans and/or Date objects but your code is sending an Array of Arrays. The inner Array is also an Array of Arrays.

Instead of `push` you might need to use `concat`. See [How to extend an existing JavaScript array with another array, without creating a new array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1374126/1595451).

Reference

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendrowrowcontents
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat

Comment: So how would I fix this?

Comment: @kaitlynmm569 I added a link to a question about that.