# App Script create array from email string

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

Using app scripts I'm trying to extract all the email addresses from email messages and put them in an array. From my console.log messages,  I'm getting stuck because it looks like instead of an array I just get a string. i'm not too familiar with javascript. Any help would be great. I'm looking for an array of email address. The methods of  message.get() return a string. I want to split out the email address and create a single, unified array.

```
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
function onOpen(e){
  
  ui.createMenu("Gmail Manager").addItem("Get Emails by Label", "getGmailEmails").addToUi();
  
}

function getGmailEmails(){
  
  var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("MyLabel");
  var threads = label.getThreads();
  var fullArray = [];

  for(var i = threads.length - 1; i >=0; i--){
    var messages = threads[i].getMessages();
    
    for (var j = 0; j <messages.length; j++){
      var message = messages[j];
      if (message.isUnread()){

        fullArray.push(extractDetails(message));
      }
    }

  }
  console.log("FullArray:"+fullArray);
  for(var i=0; i<fullArray.length; i++){
    console.log("printing array " + i + ": "+fullArray[i])
  }

}


function extractDetails(message){
  var dateTime = message.getDate();
  var subjectText = message.getSubject();

  var senderDetails = message.getFrom();
  var ccEmails = message.getCc();
  var replyEmail = message.getReplyTo();
  var toEmail = message.getTo();

  var emailArray = []
  
  var senderArray = senderDetails.split(',');
  var ccArray = ccEmails.split(',');
  var replyArray = replyEmail.split(',');
  var toArray = toEmail.split(',');

  for (var i =0 ; i<toArray.length; i++){
    console.log("toArray Loop"+ i + " : "+ toArray[i]);
    emailArray.push([toArray[i]]);
  }
  for (var i =0 ; i<ccArray.length; i++){
    console.log("ccArray Loop"+ i + " : "+ ccArray[i]);
    emailArray.push([ccArray[i]]);
  }

  console.log("Email Array: "+ emailArray);
 
  var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  activeSheet.appendRow([dateTime, senderDetails, subjectText, ccEmails,replyEmail,toEmail,emailArray]);

  return emailArray;
}
```

Comment: Just for clarification, are you specifically referring to your variable named `emailArray` when you say you're only getting a string value instead of an array? I can see that you're splitting it with `(',')` but when it gets appended on the actual sheet, it shows as something like this `[Ljava.lang.Object;@70de2a83` (this is due to `appendRow` method can't handle array within an array, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63175846/19491139) but there are other ways available to do it). Is this your main concern? If not, please edit your question for it to be more clear & specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is just the console output. If you change `console.log("Email Array: "+ emailArray);` to `console.log("Email Array: ", emailArray);`, then it shows an array of arrays. You could simplify your extract method as follows:

```
function extractDetails(message) {
  /* ...  */

  var senderDetails = message.getFrom();
  var ccEmails = message.getCc();
  var replyEmails = message.getReplyTo();
  var toEmails = message.getTo();
 
  let emailArray = [senderDetails, ccEmails, replyEmails, toEmails].reduce(
    (array, string) => {
      //remove names (like "Name <name@company.com>") and filter empty values
      let emails = string
          .split(/\s*,\s*/)
          .map(e => e.replace(/.*?([^@<\s]+@[^@\s>]+).*?/g, "$1"))
          .filter(Boolean);
      if(emails.length > 0)
        return array.concat(emails)
      return array
    }, []);

  
  /* ... */
}
```