# push list of Date insite another list of Date angular

Tags: angular, typescript

Can you help me please,

i have a problem i have two date type list : listDate: Date[] = []; and listTotalDateProcEnCours: Date[] = [];

I want to insert listDate in the ather list: listTotalDateProcEnCours.

This is my code :

```
    this.dossiers.forEach((element: any) => {
      const listselected: any[] = [];
      const listProcEnCours: any[] = [];
      const listCommentaire: any[] = [];

      **const listDate: Date[] = [];**

      element.porteuseProcedureEnCours.forEach((e: any) => {
        listProcEnCours.push(e.procedureEnCours)
        if (e.reponse === true) {
          // console.log('true', e.procedureEnCours)
          listselected.push(e.procedureEnCours)
          if (e.commentaire != null) {
            listCommentaire.push(e.commentaire)
          }
          if (e.date != null) {
            listDate.push(e.date);
          }
        }
      });
      **this.listTotalDateProcEnCours.push(listDate);**
```

When i tried to do that the compiler gives me this error:

> Argument of type 'Date[]' is not assignable to parameter of type
> 'Date'.   Type 'Date[]' is missing the following properties from type
> 'Date': toDateString, toTimeString, toLocaleDateString,
> toLocaleTimeString, and 37 more.

Can you help me solve this problem, i want to insert date list into another date type list ?

Answer (score 2):

**[EDITED]:**

Your exception:

> Argument of type 'Date[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Date'

tells that elements of this.listTotalDateProcEnCours should be of type 'Date'. And when you try to push list with dates into it - compiler shows an error.

If pushing list into another list (*two-dimensional array*) is your desired behaviour - you should change the type of total list to:

```
this.listTotalDateProcEnCours: Date[][] or Array<Date[]>
```

*ELSE*:

If you want to flatten, You should use spread operator if you want to "extend" one array with another:

```
this.listTotalDateProcEnCours.push(...listDate)
```

OR

```
this.listTotalDateProcEnCours = this.listTotalDateProcEnCours.concat(listDate);
```

OR

```
Array.prototype.push.apply(this.listTotalDateProcEnCours,listDate)
```

Decide which way is cleaner for you.

Useful link: [How to extend an existing JavaScript array with another array, without creating a new array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374126/how-to-extend-an-existing-javascript-array-with-another-array-without-creating)

Comment: thank you for your answer sir,

i want to have a list set in the total list,

that way, I just concatenate the 2 lists that's all.

this is not my goal, my goal is to have several list of dates in a total list
i.e. the total list will have several other lists =>  two-dimensional array

Comment: @Dhia, Okay. Now I got what you want. This means that you have to change the type of your total list to  `this.listTotalDateProcEnCours: Date[][]` or `Array<Date[]>`. The second one seems to me more obvious.