# Difference between array and arrayvalue

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you check if a variable is an array in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767486/how-do-you-check-if-a-variable-is-an-array-in-javascript)

How can I check if a variable is an array (so I can handle each arrayvalue) or a single arrayvalue?

Comment: also [JavaScript: Check if object is array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775722/javascript-check-if-object-is-array)

Comment: Yes, but none of the suggested duplicates were answered with this elegant solution very useful for my specific problem... Anyway thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray) for isArray which is part of the ECMAScript 5 standard:

```
if(!Array.isArray) {
  Array.isArray = function (arg) {
    return Object.prototype.toString.call(arg) == '[object Array]';
  };
}
```

In many cases, you can also just check to see if there is a .length property (this is often what jQuery does) because this will also accept any array-like object that isn't actually an array, but can be iterated like one.  Obviously, if you have things that do have a .length property that you don't want treated like an array, this will get fooled by that situation so you have to know which you want:

```
function isArrayLike(item) {
    return(typeof item.length != "undefined");
}
```